# Photos of the new office

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-hq

I just listened to [podcast 47](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/05/podcast-47-do-you-even-twitter-bro/) and heard about your new hexagonal offices, team spaces, ping-pong tables, arcade machines, and walk-in refrigerator.

I just wondered if you can post some photos up, for the curious?

[image]

Comment: You can see some photos on the Stack Exchange company profile page on the Careers 2.0 site: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange (scroll to the bottom for the photo gallery)

Comment: @Oded I'm jealous!

Comment: @AndrewBarber - So am I. I work remotely...

Comment: [Overripe bananas](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cOg32.jpg) ewww!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Oded pointed out, there's a photo gallery at the bottom of http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange

I've just learned there's [indoor Street View](http://s.tk/NYCTour) too; pretty cool!

[image]

Comment: Hey, it's BoltClock!

Answer (score 13):

Not technically an answer - but as one cannot post images in comments:

[image]

**Where to obtain such a beautiful creature?** Though it would be great that there's the StackExchange logo printed on the t-shirt, I would even take one without that!

Comment: Isn't that a question? *Adding a ME-TOO* comment: I want this.

Comment: Searched amazon.com: No success. Searched Toys'R'Us: No success. Even tried the google image search. You guess it: No success. Dear Team: Where can I buy this unicorn?

Comment: "...without (the Stack Exchange logo)"... what the? What would be the point of *that*? ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Unicorns *always* are beautiful creatures - they don't need any logo to have a point! ;)

Comment: I.Need.This.  Too much cuteness.