# Where can I get a unicorn?

Tags: discussion, unicorns, shop

**Why I asked this question here?**
So I saw this image on careers.stackoverflow.com, but they don't have a META page, and since careers is by stackoverflow, I thought this would be the most appropriate place to this question ask.

### Where can I order/buy the unicorn below? I have to have it!

[image: Unicorn]

Comment: I posted the [same question as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180618/photos-of-the-new-office/180621#180621) to another thread quite a while ago. Thank you for bringing this up again! ;)

Comment: Unicorns don't have cloven hooves.  I don't know what this nonsense is, but someone should be made to pay for it.

Comment: @Won't Actually, [they do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicorn).

Comment: @J.Steen: Oh.  My.  God.

Comment: @Won't I know, right!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We made a limited run of these for an employee summit back in the spring of 2012.

Unfortunately, we don't have any left. :(

I can check where we got them from, but that'll have to be tomorrow.

Comment: Anna Lear, Community Unicorn-Supply Manager. If you haven't gotten business cards with that written on it, you should look in to it.

Comment: @adamlear Yes, please check!!

Comment: @Arian We had them custom-made through our swag printer, so that unfortunately won't be of much help to you either. Sorry.

Comment: @AdamLear would it be possible for you to disclose the name of the company, so one could order there creatures there - even without a Stack Exchange logo on them?

Comment: @Spontifixus http://www.stassoc.com/. Pretty sure you can't just ask them to make one unicorn, though.

Comment: @AdamLear Thank you - I will try though. At the moment this is a bit difficult, because the website listing their products produces an error... But nonetheless I eventually will contact them.

Comment: @AdamLear You used a company that has a landing page?  YOU MONSTERS!

Comment: I have looked at the situation objectively and have concluded that I need this unicorn. Where/how may I purchase/obtain/steal it?

Answer (score 18):

Thanks to Adam's hint I found a web shop [**selling these beautiful creatures**](http://promomart.espwebsite.com/ProductDetails/?productId=7006450&tab=Tile&referrerPage=ProductResults&refPgId=504580171&referrerModule=PRDREB)!

They don't just sell one of them, you will need to buy a whole bunch. Price starts at $6 if 50 of them get ordered.

I'm quite sure that there will be 50 of us wanting such a "Super Soft Stuffed Animal- Unicorn". Even if there is no logo printed on their t-shirts. (Because as I pointed out in [a comment on my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180621/195761), unicorns don't need a logo to have a point.)

But I don't know how this could be organized. Of course one of us could buy the lot and then re-sell them, but that means a lot of work, given that many of us live anywhere but in the US. Any ideas?

Comment: Unicorns always have a [point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicorn_horn).  Its part of the definition of a unicorn.

Comment: Payment is made easy with Paypal. Those who want a unicorn can send a stamped envelope to the one who bought and he'll just have to stuff the unicorn inside the envelope and send it on its merry way. Doesn't sound impossible, just need someone to do that. Who said Tim? ;) Oh, and needless to say, count me in!

Comment: @ShadowWizard I thought of that possibility, too. But investing about 350$ (Our unicorns should wear a t-shirt, right?) could also be a bit risky if some of those saying "I want one!" later on don't buy - and the nice guy organizing is left alone with a box of 45 unicorns. Well on second thought: He has 45 unicorns then...

Comment: @Spontifixus that's a risk, true... but I want to believe some people here have enough money not to care too much and take that risk. :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard I thought about doing it myself. But for once I live in Germany making shipment for most people unnecessarily expensive - and I recently bought a house... ;)

Comment: @Spontifixus yeah, we need someone from the inside aka USA. :)

Comment: Any one of a number of crowdsourcing websites have a solution for the risk angle - if not enough people pledge, then it doesn't happen.  If someone pledges and it's successful, they can't change their mind after pledging.

Comment: But I want a logo on the t-shirt!

Comment: It's only an additional $35 per run, and $1 per unicorn for a logo.  However we'd have to get permission from Stack Exchange to use one of their logos, and they'd probably want to be in the final artwork approval loop if they got on board with the idea at all.  We could avoid that issue if we just used a meta meme that isn't trademarked though.

Comment: Can you post a good Crowd sourcing website so we can get this started. Also, I emailed the sales person of the company that Anna Lear mentioned. and we could get them min order 50, for $4.50 each, with a setup charge of $35.

Comment: That price also includes the shirt, so we should definitely use http://www.stassoc.com/.

Comment: The only one I've used is [kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/profile/2070729777). I've heard of and browsed [Tindie](https://www.tindie.com/) and [Indiegogo](http://www.indiegogo.com/) but have not purchased or sold a project through them.

Comment: It seems that making a crowdfunding offer that was $10 per plush, including shipping in the US would probably break even. Adding another $5 - $10 for international shipping would take care of that. If more than 50 were sold, then the cost would go down, but the effort for distribution would go up, so I'd say don't offer stretch goals, just pocket any "profit" because chances are whoever does it will still make less than minimum wage if they get a profit at all.

Comment: Sorry, y'all. You are welcome to order unicorns or whatever else you want, but we can't authorize the use of our logos, names, etc. for it.

Comment: @AdamLear - that's fine. As has been written before: Unicorns don't need any logo to have a point ;)

Comment: Has been over a month since the last comment. Is there anyone out there in the US willing to open a small unicorn shop?

Comment: Site is down, hopefully only temporary

Comment: @ShadowWizard If you are talking about Stassoc, it is online again.

Comment: If we got them with blank t-shirts, then anybody who wants to could use stickers, patches, or his own artistic talents to customize from there... but with or without a t-shirt, I'd like one of these!