# Who cut the cheese?

Tags: discussion, fun, swag, 10th-anniversary

> **UPDATE:** [JNat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/jnat) will be sending out emails to collect addresses from the lucky users getting a cheese board — be on the lookout for those! :)

We've moved *quite* a bit of stuff around this year, and you've been *mostly* patient with us while we overhauled our information architecture. This was no trivial *needs more pop and a lens flare* type of undertaking, we [moved a *significant* amount of cheese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Moved_My_Cheese%3F).

To kick off our [fall anniversary series of celebrations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374617/happy-10th-anniversary-stack-overflow-commence-au-festival), we'd like to offer our thanks to everyone that put up with us. We'd especially like to thank those of you who went out of your way to try and be constructive, even when you weren't happy about the changes we had to make.

We were going to do this sooner, but we had to find a *really* cheesy way to go about it, and not much is cheesier than a cheese board except the cheese one might carve while using it.

If you want one of these engraved with "Cheese Overflow 2018":

[image: Cheese board picture]

... then you need to regale us with tales of cheese. Or, tails of cheese, if you make mice out of Maasdam. Cheese, Louise, you could even write a song. ***You must submit creative artifacts where the primary theme is cheese, where puns are strongly encouraged.***

You could:

- Make a sculpture out of cheese.
- Write a cheesy story.
- Write a song about cheese, perhaps a *Munster* mash for upcoming holidays?
- Design a completely edible replacement for your favorite review queue.
- Make a ***brie***-f case to hold your important papers.

... you get the drift. The top 25 entries, as calculated by net upvotes received (not aggregate score, down-voting won't help you win!) will receive this cheesy package. Whatever it is, you have to be able to submit it as an answer to this question. **Links to videos *are* accepted**, however they must be of your own creation and the video must remain available. If either stops being true, your submission will be removed.

That's right. Text, images, crayons on newspaper, LEGO, popsicle sticks - it only has to be *cheesy* as a major component. If we have to explain that more technically, it's not going to be fun anymore :P

#### The Rules

1. You can post as many entries as you want *in good faith* as long as they are in line with our [terms of service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service), [acceptable use policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy) and [code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct). This is also a reminder that all user-contributed content falls under our [CC-BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).
2. Contest is open from 2018-10-09 to 2018-11-09, final entry must be received at or prior to 23:59:59 UTC on the last day. Contest will then be locked for historical reference.
3. Employees are eligible. [Jay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles?tab=profile), this means that you've gotta get cheesy in order to get a cheese board.
4. You must be a user in good standing on Meta Stack Exchange during the entirety of the contest, or your entry may be disqualified. Let's have some good, clean fun.
5. Winners will be notified via email within 10 days of the contest closing. As we will be ordering these based on demand (they're not cheap!), you'll need to allow approximately 30 days for delivery. You'll need to provide us your shipping information privately, in accordance with our [privacy policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy).
6. If you win but don't care for cheese, we'll give you a selection of other items of approximate value. We want you to enjoy the prize.
7. Void where contests or cheese is prohibited.

***Now let's get cheesy!***

Comment: Who *doesn't* love cheese?  Heathens, that's who!

Comment: "Employees are eligible." With all the cheese, I first read *edible*. Thankfully not.

Comment: Why do you think we're on to Shog number 9 @AnneDaunted? Gosh those first 8 were tasty.

Comment: @Bart Sweet like Shogolate?

Comment: Good cheese needs a bit longer to mature ...

Comment: Notify Wallace & Grommitt

Comment: _Me doesn't understand the rules. Waits for an answer to be posted._ `:P`

Comment: Ok, raining tacos where every taco is replaced with cheese. Here goes...

Comment: Incoming onslaught of cheese related puns; brace yourselves!

Comment: Can you please give more details about "user in good standing"? e.g. if a user is chat banned or was chat banned for non-trivial amount of time during the last year, can this user take part in the contest? (Talking only about chat ban, guess full suspension on the site means not a good standing)

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Creative things take some time, I know I need to wait until I get home to do something of this magnitude, but as far as I can tell, it's any thing that requires creativity, and themed cheesy. I expect a majority of the winners are going to tie their theme back to Stack Exchange in some way, instead of just taking a picture of a mountain of cheese, or anything of the like.

Comment: We only ate shog(s) 1 - 8 because they weren't doing a gouda nuff job.

Comment: Whoever came up with this idea is crackers.

Comment: This makes so much sense.

Comment: too much equipments are provided to cut the cheese!

Comment: Is this the swag we get for 10th anniversary? 

Comment: Could you please add more context for international visitors? Why cheese etc?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov I linked to a wikipedia article about what inspired the phrase. Commonly, it's a metaphor for disrupting the way people work by changing the location and behavior of the things they need to accomplish something (e.g. changing the design of something)

Comment: Blessed are the cheesemakers!

Comment: Just a thought: I think accepting entries immediately after announcing the contest would tend to advantage lower-effort entries, due to the FGITW effects.

Comment: Just in case you're French and don't quite understand, [here you go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGqxb3vLL1A)

Comment: @TimPost - "Who cut the cheese" is also a phrase related to flatulent behavior. I hope you didn't stink things up around here :o)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara There's certainly some truth to that... but truly stellar answers can (and have) been voted up the ranks even when posted later in the process in past events. Case in point, my cookie hat from Winter Bash, which was posted 3 days after the start of the contest and still managed to finish third. So, if you have a great idea but it will take some time to age - like a good Cheddar - there's still hope.

Comment: I object to the discrimination against the lactose intolerant. We like cheese too, yaknow.

Comment: It's only half an hour until my lunch break. It's only half an hour until I can eat some cheese.

Comment: @TimPost - Is the next context going to be a *Who Stepped On The Duck* contest? Just asking ;-)

Comment: I worry this might give me a [*Cheeses Complex*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Jesus%20Complex).

Comment: Finally, Stack Exchange is starting to think about the future: http://www.poorlydrawnlines.com/comic/your-future/

Comment: Enough!  Can I have the cake trolley instead, or even just coffee?

Comment: Weird, very weird.

Comment: "Void where contests or cheese is prohibited." - In what places is cheese prohibited?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Head on over to Mi Yoda and ask.  Be prepared for some *lengthy* replies.  Also "vegan restaurants".

Comment: Did someone say _coffee_? Yeah, something surrounding that may or may not be coming up soon.

Comment: @MartinBonner Why quotes around "vegan restaurant"?

Comment: @AzorAhai To indicate that it is an answer to the question Robert Columbia asked.  They were *not* intended as scare quotes (I like vegan restaurants), but I can see how they might be read as such

Comment: @martin It just reminded me of r/suspiciousquotes

Comment: [<obligatory xkcd post>](https://xkcd.com/140/)

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd good point: we should chip in (these things ain't cheap) and have one sent to Randall Munroe, too. By implied comment-vote he's probably one of our highest-rep contributors....

Comment: I hear Trump has prohibited shredded cheese. He wants to make America grate again.

Comment: @TimPost: Why is stuff like this allowed on Meta?

Comment: Why is this question protected? Is it only open to programmers?

Comment: @dfeuer check the lowest-scoring answers for one from an association-only score account....

Comment: @dfeuer because two or three answers from very low rep users were deleted. In those cases system assumes spammers activity so auto protects the question. I will unprotect it now.

Comment: I think somebody just went through and downvoted everyone, since all the answers towards the end just went down in net score. Is there any way to check /fix this?

Comment: @IsaacBrowne - Other than visual, what would be the effect? It's based on total upvotes, not net score.

Comment: @JohnP There is a slight effect on reputation, and I feel this is just a "wrong" thing to do.

Comment: @IsaacBrowne - I think it's wrong too, but other than boot someone, they will just go through and do it again. I've got 10 DV on mine so far. I don't see how anyone can DV any cheese story post. "I don't agree with your cheese"?

Comment: @IsaacBrowne The votes not counting towards the resultant prizes doesn't mean we're disabling them entirely. Users are free to vote as they please with the same effects. If it helps, remember that each of those downvotes came with a penalty for the person voting.

Comment: This concept is the equivalent of someone jangling a bunch of shiny keys to distract a whiny weeping baby. It didn't stop me from appreciating the ingenuity of six "answers" and upvoting them though.

Comment: This deserves [a chesy cartoon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2nN4Yh63OY)

Comment: Resisting the urge to make a 5 character change to this post to edit/remove the invalid `s` on "legos" (sic) to be `LEGO` ;-)

Comment: Did you know that cheese is the best food to give you nightmares? It's true. I'm going to have nightmares all week from the cheese overload!!

Comment: @MartinBonner: By the way, I don't know if vegan restaurants discriminate against cheese; I once saw a whole vegan chicken in a supermarket!

Comment: @scunliffe I can read Americans; talk about "getting oil on their pants from the hood of that truck, and it really shows with this color" and it doesn't worry me at all - but treating lego as a count noun drives me up the wall.

Comment: I don't want to rain on anyone's parade but in my neck of the woods "Who cut the cheese?" is a euphemism for "Who farted?". Maybe it's not the best title for this discussion....

Comment: @fbueckert Vegan here xD

Comment: It does so annoy me that none of you people seem able to pronounce "Gouda" correctly. The "ou" part is actually "ow", as in "now". Not even mentioning Anglophones' utter inability to pronounce the soft Dutch 'g'...

Comment: @Henry: that's kind of the point of the title.

Comment: @Henry Don't you know how *edgy* we are?

Comment: 60+ answers so far and not a single song in sight. Even though Tim specifically said "write a song". I am disappoint.

Comment: Make sure you don't take your shoes off when using Cheese Overflow, or at least keep them handy.

Comment: This has officially been my most work-distracting SE post of all time.  How did I just spend two hours reading cheesy posts about cheese???

Comment: Is this cheese still fresh?

Comment: Will there be an annual Big Block of Cheese day in commemoration of this event? Where questions and bugs will be handled that otherwise wouldn't be taken into consideration?

Comment: It's a real shame that you can't lock votes, and have a proper voting phase. Questions more highly upvoted are extremely likely to be those that were posted first, and have more page impressions.

Comment: Can this get unprotected again? I would love to enter an answer, but never did anything on Meta.. ;-(

Comment: @TimPost "Contest will then be locked for historical reference". Well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Just wait for 6-8 Hours more. :)

Comment: @coder-croc lol, no worry I'm past being affected by this, I'm just teasing Tim.

Comment: @TimPost : I added two posts, but none of them were able to make it into top 25 posts. But combined together (in terms of votes) I am in the list. Would I be eligible for the Swag? *(keeping my fingers crossed, please tell the good news :) )*

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have also flagged this post for being ‘overdue’...

Comment: Since this "question" was marked as *off-topic*, does that cancel the contest or...?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd contests are always closed after they're over to prevent more submissions (see example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304500/232439)).

Comment: @scohe001 That was meant as more of a joke, but okay

Comment: My board arrived today and I already have cheese, so... cheese overflow commencing soon! :-)

Comment: @TimPost : Thank you it had been arrived to Israel:https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQRm9.jpg

Comment: Got my cheesy swag, earlier then I expected. Maybe DHL is better then  FedEx then :D

Answer (score 357):

Well, I am generally researching X-ray tomography. I went to the lab to ask them if I could put a cheese in one of the machines, but they are not cool with it....

[image]

So I simulated an X-ray machine on the cheese and reconstructed the result for better analysis. I used MATLAB and the [TIGRE](https://kt.cern/success-stories/tigre-new-open-source-software-medical-imaging) toolbox*.

Cheese generation:

```
%% Create cheese

% First we create a filled cheese
imageSize= 512;
[columnsInImage rowsInImage] = meshgrid(1:imageSize, 1:imageSize);
% Next create the circle in the image.
centerX = 50;
centerY = 50;
radius = 400;
maincheese = (rowsInImage - centerY).^2 ...
    + (columnsInImage - centerX).^2 <= radius.^2;

maincheese(1:100,:)=0;
maincheese(:,1:100)=0;

fullcheese=zeros(imageSize,imageSize,imageSize,'single');

fullcheese(:,:,50:430)=repmat(maincheese,1,1,430-50+1);

clear columnsInImage rowsInImage
```

Now let's make it Swiss. We like manchego, but do we like it more than Swiss? No.

```
nholes=100;
[x,y,z]=meshgrid(1:imageSize, 1:imageSize,1:imageSize);
holecenters=randi(imageSize,3,nholes);
holesizes=rand(1,nholes)*50;
holes=false(size(x));
for ii=1:nholes
holes=holes|((x - holecenters(1,ii)).^2 ...
    + (y -  holecenters(2,ii)).^2 ...
    + (z -  holecenters(3,ii)).^2 <= holesizes(ii).^2);
end
fullcheese(holes)=0;
```

[image]

Then I generated X-ray projections from a circular trajectory

```
%% Define Geometry
%
% VARIABLE                                   DESCRIPTION                    UNITS
geo.DSD = 1536;                             % Distance Source Detector      (mm)
geo.DSO = 1000;                             % Distance Source Origin        (mm)
% Detector parameters

% Image parameters
geo.nVoxel=[128;128;128]*2;                   % number of voxels              (vx)
geo.sVoxel=[256;256;256]/2;                   % total size of the image       (mm)
geo.dVoxel=geo.sVoxel./geo.nVoxel;          % size of each voxel            (mm)



geo.nDetector=[192;  128];                    % number of pixels              (px)
geo.dDetector=[3; 3];                     % size of each pixel            (mm)
geo.sDetector=geo.nDetector.*geo.dDetector; % total size of the detector    (mm)


% Auxiliary
geo.accuracy=0.5;                           % Accuracy of FWD proj          (vx/sample)
geo.mode='cone';                         % Accuracy of FWD proj          (vx/sample)

nangles=180;
angles=linspace(0,2*pi-2*pi/nangles,nangles)-pi;
projections=Ax(fullcheese,geo,angles,'interpolated');
```

[image]

And finally I reconstructed it using two different mathematical methods, just for better cheese-analysis.

```
fdkcheese=FDK(projections, geo, angles);
ossartcheese=OS_SART(projections, geo, angles, 50);
```

Resulting in this deep insight on how cheese is, with non-destructive testing. (The image shows slices of cheese.)

```
plotImg([sartcheese, fdktest], 'dim', 3, 'savegif', 'cheeses.gif')
```

[image]

Now you can know how to cut the cheese so everyone gets equal amount of holes, before even cutting!

---

*Disclaimer: I programmed the TIGRE toolbox and am not trying to promote it. I just know how to make cheese fast with it.

Comment: Have you discovered any broken bones or tumors?

Comment: @flawr nah, apparently its mostly cheese. 

Comment: Boo, your lab's boring! See "The Laser Cheese Raclette", *Annals of Improbable Research* 1(**3**) May/June 1995. (The authors basically used a high powered laser to make [raclette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raclette)!). That said, kudos for a great cheese!

Comment: @terdon I even brought some crackers to convince them, but no. "not scientific enough" "blablablabla". I should change jobs.

Comment: Quick, add a note about affiliation before some kind people spam flag your answer away :P

Comment: You might be able to convince someone to put some cheese on the [DiamondRPI](https://twitter.com/DiamondRPi) visible light RaspberryPi and Arduino 'beamline' at Diamond. *8') Sadly it is undergoing maintenance at the moment, but it was a very cool summer student project where I work, combining the GDA, the [savu tomography reconstruction pipeline](https://github.com/DiamondLightSource/Savu) with a twitter API.

Comment: @MarkBooth I am not far from there and the code here can be included in Savu (well, the python version), so lets write a 10M£ STFC/EPRSC grant and make cheese happen.

Comment: you guys are nerds

have an upvote

Comment: This was absolutely awesome to read

Comment: "I went to the lab to ask them if I could put a cheese in one of the machines" That's your problem right there. You should not have asked. It is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.

Comment: I mean, good effort, but man you have farr tooo much time on your hands.

Comment: @CrisLuengo "Oh. I didn't know I wasn't supposed to do that."

Comment: That last one is the perfect animation to go with [this video](https://youtu.be/_4ruHJFsb4g) on intersecting 3D balls in 2D space and 4D balls in 3D space.

Comment: Mechatronics Engineering Stack Exchange!

Comment: Love it! But I noticed you're using Bandicam have you discovered Screen2Gif?

Comment: @Persistence thanks! Yeah I quickly uninstalled that software after doing the gif, it was pretty crappy.

Comment: Here's a link in case you can't find it, apparently using 2 instead of to has gone out of fashion... https://www.screentogif.com/

Comment: NQ? Maybe think about the red things in the background before you slap on a red NO.

Comment: This is a cheesy project.  Kudos!

Comment: Amazing! i love the x-ray projections

Answer (score 192):

Well, it's gouda you guys to do this, but I'm sure that it will grate on quite a few people. I would proceed very caerphilly with this proposal. Or, on the other hand you could just sit back and have morbier and watch the curds fly.

I would like to offer this advice, because if this really blows up, all that will be left is de brie, and nobody wants that. Just sit back, put on some nice rhythm and bleu's, pick a snack that you are fondue of, except for that one because that one is nacho cheese. On the other hand, eat it because wotsit matter anyway?

Consider the feta of most posts in this salvo, and vote appropriately. Appreciate the sharp wit, be mild with the newbies, and get yourself out of the daily rind for a while. If you must completely retreat, I recommend creating a moatsarella around your house, then stand on your roof shouting "How dairy you?!?".

Once everything is ova, stop throwing stones because the roquefort's back on occasion. Get the beavers out of the moat and break apart their edam. Think about what you've done that might curdle others' toes, and stop being so curd in your speech. Try to be a bit more cultured, but not necessarily Stiltoned, follow the roules, and try to avoid a meltdown.

A few final thoughts - If you want to be clever, use mascapone and go as a horse for Halloween (Make sure you get a tunworth of candy). Avoid angering the Hallouminati, and always act mature.

Comment: The...pronunciation is weird over there. :-P

Comment: Well, yeah. Could be worse, we could be in Philadelphia.

Comment: Fortunately, I'm in good Old Amsterdam!

Comment: @MrLister - Wheel, that's nice. :)

Comment: Far out, you've put me whey over my pun limit for today :|

Comment: Upvote for the **Kraft**y **s**p**licing** in of [Venezuelan Beaver Cheese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AVenezuelan_Beaver_cheese)!

Comment: CH33ZE N STUFF!1117. I await my award.

Comment: After about half the text it felt like a prayer...

Comment: Meh, havarti thought of that one

Comment: Edam that's cheesy.

Comment: that was oaxaca've a pun run there

Comment: someone feel free to add the appropriate Wikipedia links to the cheeses. otherwise its motsoreal for all of us

Comment: Nothing beats Greek Feta! ;)

Answer (score 178):

How about some *StackExcheese*? Modeled in [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com) rendered with [Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycles) with fully procedural textures (no images harmed during the rendering of this 3D model).

[image]

In the [Portuguese](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com) language there is a common traditional saying that [eating a lot of cheese makes you forgetful](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/andar-a-comer-muito-queijo/21251), so stick around and restore some knowledge from the [vast sea of Q&A sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

I do love me some cheese though; my favorites are Halloumi, Ricotta, Edam, Mozzarella and Feta.

Comment: Wow! Nice! @Daurte

Comment: I thought this was a real photo! Wow

Comment: Molded in Blender? Sounds great! Let's eat!

Comment: Portucheese? What? ;)

Comment: The icon has 3 stripes, not four...But a great image!

Comment: @ArtemisFowl That is the sites icon on the top right, I did not use that as reference, I based it on the actual Stack Exchange logo that sits on the top left of the header.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Ah yes, I see. I take it back.

Answer (score 169):

Here's me talking about ***cheese*** AND ***cheese boards*** over a year ago to a user *named* ***[@CHEESE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51142/cheese)***. Destiny much?

-drops mic-

[image]

Comment: just add a link to the original comment. I like the time-travel effort involved in this entry :)

Comment: @NH. [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7371/the-many-usernames-of-sff-se/7378#comment34733_9290)

Comment: It was the first comment where I had to condense because I reached the max number of characters. Took about an hour to research, but I see it as time well spent.

Comment: +1 for the freehand circle

Comment: Just in time for halloween!

Answer (score 112):

## I've moved some cheese!

[image]

Comment: +1 this is easily the most appetizing entry and now I'm hungry.

Comment: Is that *whole grain* bread?! Yuck!

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd No, it's whole grain cheese silly.

Answer (score 108):

#### Stop Moving My Cheese

Run this stack snippet and try to get the cheese with your cursor.

```js
var showAlert = true;
$('#cheese').on('mouseenter',function(e){
    $(this).animate({
        'left': getRandomInt(0, $(window).width() - $(this).width()),
        'top': getRandomInt(0, $(window).height() - $(this).height())
    }, 500);
    showAlert = true;
});

$('#cheese').on('click', function(e) {
  if (showAlert) {
    alert("Got the cheese!");
    showAlert = false;
  }
  
});
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}
```

```css
html {
  cursor: grab;
}
#cheese {
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:88px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="cheese" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nsAx.png"/>
```

Comment: nice, but you should have it do something if we actually click on the cheese successfully (which I did a couple of times when it moved to a new location that was still under my cursor)

Comment: Yay! I got the cheese! Is there a way to limit the amount of notifications though? I didn't notice the first one and kept clicking on the cheese, then had to close all the pop-up windows.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd I updated it so that it doesn't alert a second time unless the cheese moves. Also added animation.

Comment: Nice animation. :) Found another bug though. If the cheese moves to under your cursor and you click more than once without moving your mouse, two pop-ups pop up.

Comment: +1 for `cursor:grab;` , never heard about it before .

Comment: I think we might try doing this with the Ask Question button.

Answer (score 106):

### tl;dr - just [watch the video](https://youtu.be/xxuHuE_hafE) - I'm a big fan of the ending! Cheese Overflow (not at all deliberate...)

I once entertained* my girlfriend in a park in Denmark with a reasonably accurate rendition of all of the collected works of Monty Python's Flying Circus (we did have to wait many hours for the next ferry back from Esbjerg to the UK)

The only one she really enjoyed was the Cheese Shop Sketch. We both agreed it was a masterpiece of British comedy. And my devotion to a life of cheese was born. We split up soon after (unconnected fact, obviously) but I still believe cheese is the food of the gods.

But my cheeseboard is old and frail...

My lowly offering to cheese overflow is below, made from a rather nice [Barber's Vintage Reserve Cheddar](https://www.barbers.co.uk/products/barber-s-1833-vintage-reserve-cheddar) (If you want to see the **limited edition**, **director's cut** video, and understand why I am currently in a bit of a cholesterol haze, [**click here**](https://youtu.be/xxuHuE_hafE)):

[image]

*Bored senseless, apparently. Sorry Kirsty...

Comment: I think you mean "*board senseless*"...

Comment: I managed to put you to sleep before you reached the end of the video didn't I :-)

Comment: You did, actually. I never quite managed to get past two minutes :P

Comment: music doesn't fit at all...

Comment: @mith - you know you can play YouTube videos at 2x speed or more?

Comment: Not Venezuelan beaver cheese? I'm disappointed.

Comment: I love John Cheese!

Comment: @DougGlancy That's so bad but I like John Cleese enough that I like it.

Comment: @Clonkex But you're not enough of a John Cleese fan to have watched the interview where he reveals that his family name was originally Cheese? :-) ([ref](http://www.bubblegun.com/features/cleese.html) - I couldn't find the interview itself just now)

Comment: Anyone watch to the end yet? I'm a big fan of the ending...

Comment: You had me at "I once entertained my girlfriend in a park"

Comment: The music seriously reminds me of [the Riven soundtrack.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMOSTOSyNz8)

Comment: Damn! You don't have any respect for cheese.. my heart is broken after seeing such cruelty with lovely cheese. You could have cut it properly.. disappointed! Sigh...

Comment: @coder-croc this one is quite crystalline, frangible and crumbly. For pure smoothness I would have possibly gone down the Double Gloucester route and caved using a fine paring knife. But I quite like the rough and ready effect.

Comment: Seems like you have a lot of cheese...

Comment: @Arihan - currently 7 different cheddars in the fridge, along with a Stilton, 3 soft cheeses, a Red Leicester and a Bavarian smoked cheese. It is the food of the gods.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Agreed. It is the food of the gods. Ode to cheese!

Comment: Thy cheese overfloweth.

Comment: I recommend watching the video at full speed for the first but, then incrementally speeding it up and watching the construction get more and more frenetic.

Answer (score 88):

*Sniff, sniff*.

Shog's nose wrinkled. The unthinkable had happened. Someone - and he knew exactly who it was - had just cut the cheese<sup>1</sup>.

He had been calmly sitting in his office, working - the folks over at Cooking.SE were having a bit of a salty<sup>2</sup> discussion on meta - when *someone* in the office had released a foul, lingering odor.

And since he worked from home, it was of course him.

With the smell grating<sup>3</sup> on his nerves, Shog decided to take the prudent course of action and exit the room, at least until the pungent smell had dissipated. *I'll just go get a snack*, he decided.
He opened the door of his office and walked down to his kitchen.

"Pickles..." he said, scanning the shelves. "No. Appear to be out."
He glanced over at where he usually kept his baking experiments. Unfortunately, mold appeared to be well on its way towards gaining sentience there.
His tomato patch was still unripe.

Opening the fridge was a slight improvement. Here there was half a watermelon rind<sup>4</sup>, a few slices of pizza, and... a rotten orange, emitting malodorous fumes. In his fridge. It seemed like Shog's nose was in for a rough day.

He sigh and decided to just grab the pizza. He pulled it out, walked over to the microwave, and was about to pop a slice in when he heard a sound behind him. His back stiffened.
Slowly, he wheel<sup>5</sup>ed around.

A heavy weight struck his head, and Shog knew no more.

---

Catija<sup>6</sup> watched as her toddler, screaming, lay on the floor, beating his fists on the rug. Having a temper tantrum. Naturally. She couldn't wait until he matured<sup>7</sup> a little.

"It's okay, Ben!" she said, trying to calm him down. "I'll only be out for a few hours. Your father will be here soon."
She turned to the babysitter, who was eyeing the kid on the floor warily. "I'm sorry... he's not usually like this," she told her, frowning. "I don't know why he's having a melt<sup>8</sup>down now."

The teenager gave a nervous grin, flashing braces.
"It's okay, ma'am, hopefully I can handle it."

"You have my phone number?" Catija asked.
"Yes, I do," the sitter confirmed.
"Good. I shouldn't be back later than 11, and Andy should be here by 5. His bedtime is 7:30."
"Got it," the girl said, making a note on her large purple phone.

Catija took one last look at the screaming child on the floor, picked up her bag, and walked out, closing the door behind her.

It was a warm day for the fall... but then again, it was Texas.

As Catija walked down the street, a taxi pulled up next to her. The window rolled down.
"Need a ride, ma'am?" the driver asked, his face obscured by a large pair of sunglasses.

"No, thanks," she started to decline. But before she could finish, a chemical-doused rag was thrust out the window, and her sight faded to black.

---

The man in black paced around the room. The Swiss<sup>9</sup> gentleman had just been informed that the capture of the man known as Shog9 and the woman known as Catija had been smoothly executed, and that the pair was now being held. The team he had sent had done a gouda<sup>10</sup> job.

Now he could finally execute the next stage of the plan. He smiled as he dialed the phone.

---

Pizza. Everything was black. Microwave. Headache.

Shog groggily opened his eyes. He was lying on the floor in a dark room.
He sat up, rubbing his eyes. There was a large lump on the back of his head, probably because the head in question had recently had a slight disagreement with a heavy object.

As his eyes adjusted to the gloom, he could start to make out several things about his surroundings.

- he was not alone

On the other side of the room, still out cold, was his new colleague, Catija. Apart from her, though, there was nobody in the room that he could see.

- he was apparently in a cheese factory

All around him were refrigerators, filled with cheese wheels, still aging. There was also a table stacked with what appeared to be containers of shredded cheese.

*Odd*, he thought. *Why would cheese be left out like that?*
Not in a fridge it would spoil. Unless...

He crossed the room, heading over to the table to look more closely at these containers. As he passed by her, Catija started to stir. "Wh- what..." she mumbled. Her eyes shot open.

She took a minute to look around her. She was in a small room that was reminiscent of a storage facility. There was large refrigerators around her. And her co-worker Shog - with a rather large lump on his head - standing next to a table, holding a container of shredded cheese.

"I'm thinking this might not actually be cheese."

Caught off guard, Catija turned her head to look at Shog. "What?"

"This might not be cheese," he repeated. "Look. It's not in the fridge, and it doesn't really look like cheese."

She walked over to look. He was right. The "cheese" was too white, thin, and long to be cheese. It looked more like strips of paper.

"You're right," she said. "It looks like... shredded<sup>11</sup> paper."

Before he could respond, she popped open the container and grabbed what was in there. Paper.

She upended the container onto the table. Pieces of paper fluttered down to land in a messy pile.

"It looks like... a puzzle," Shog realized. And without needing further discussion, they set to reconstructing the puzzle.

When they had finished, things weren't exactly clearer.

> THE NAME OF THIS SEMI-HARD, PALE YELLOW CHEESE IS FORMED OF TWO PARTS. ONE IS THE STAGE OF A CELESTIAL OBJECT. THE OTHER IS A GEOGRAPHIC OBJECT NEAR A BODY OF WATER.
>
> **_** _ _ _-_ _ _ _ | _ _ _
>
> THIS AUSTRIAN, SEMI-HARD CHEESE HAS A TWO-WORD NAME. THE FIRST IS A RELATED TO AN IMMENSE GEOGRAPHICAL PHENOMENON. THE SECOND IS RELATED TO LUKE SKYWALKER.
>
> **_** _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _
>
> DETESTED BY MANY, THIS CHEESE IS AMONG THE OLDEST ON THE PLANET, AND, IN THE UNITED STATES, WAS OFTEN ILLEGALLY REPLACED BY WOOD.
>
> **_** _ _ _ _ _ _ _
>
> THE INFAMOUS CHEESE CASU MARZU - MADE USING MAGGOTS - COMES FROM THIS MEH ITALIAN CHEESE.
>
> **_** _ _ _ _ _ _ _
>
> THIS CHEESE'S FIRST NAME MAY BE SIMILAR TO A NEW STATE IN THE US AND THE HOME OF BILBO BAGGINS, BUT IT'S ALSO THE NAME OF A DOG (AND THE NAME OF AN ENGLISH PLACE). THE SECOND MAY BE SAD, BUT IT'S ALSO FUNKY AND SKY-HIGH.
>
> **_** _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _
>
> WHERE NO MAN HAS GONE BEFORE.
>
> THIS IVORY-COLORED CHEESE MAY NOT REQUIRE TWO, BUT THE DANCE IT SHARES A NAME WITH CERTAINLY DOES.
>
> **_** _ _ _ _
>
> THIS MOLDY CHEESE MAY BE DELICIOUS, BUT YOU MAY BE TEMPTED TO, INSTEAD, SAY "EW". AFTER ALL, THAT'S ITS NAME.
>
> **_** _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _
>
> THIS SEMI-HARD CHEESE IS ALSO A CELESTIAL STAGE, BUT YOU CAN'T SEE IT.
>
> **_** _ _ | _ _ _ _
>
> THIS NUTTY CHEESE'S NAME IS TWO WORDS. ONE IS PROBABLY IN YOUR DINING ROOM. IT MAY HAVE A CLOTH ON IT. THE OTHER IS NOT QUITE METAL, BUT NOT BLUE EITHER. IT'S NEXT TO A HARD PLACE, THOUGH.
>
> **_** _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _
>
> THIS YELLOW CHEESE IS WARM ALL ROUND - IT'S SMOKEY, SPICY, AND *HOT*. YOU CAN PROBABLY FIND IT IN THE HEARTH, TOO, WHERE IT'S ALSO FAIRLY WARM.
>
> **_** _ _ _

**Can you help Shog and Catija by solving the puzzle and finding out what the answer is?**

I warn you: The answer is cheesy.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>An idiom for passing gas.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>Salty cheese, yum.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup>A pun on grating cheese.</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup>Ever heard of [cheese rinds](https://cheeseunderground.com/2011/01/11/cheese-rinds-to-eat-or-not-to-eat/)?</sub>

<sub><sup>5</sup>Cheese wheels!</sub>

<sub><sup>6</sup>Apparently, there's a cheese called [Cotija](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotija_cheese).</sub>

<sub><sup>7</sup>On the other hand, most cheeses are rather mature...</sub>

<sub><sup>8</sup>Cheese melts. I admit this one was rather poor.</sub>

<sub><sup>9</sup>Holey puns!</sub>

<sub><sup>10</sup>I'm sorry. This one was obligatory.</sub>

<sub><sup>11</sup>Shredded cheese. Works well on pizza.</sub>

Comment: Holy wowzers this is so well written! I was grinning ear to ear as I read the thing. If I could upvote twice I would! :D

Comment: Prize for solving?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog - People who solve this puzzle and ping me in [my chat office](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58064/miths-desk) *might* receive another puzzle to solve, until *someone* might get a bounty here, or Scifi.SE, or Literature.SE, or Puzzling.SE. No promises, though, because making cheese puzzles is hard work :P

Comment: Wow... nice story. This must have taken some time to write.

Comment: Ah, so this is where the newest Mith puzzle resides... :P Hidden from puzzling xD

Comment: @Quintec - https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47106431#47106431

Answer (score 76):

## A mouse dreaming of the cheese-filled moon

[image: If you are using a screen reader, this was an image!]

Made from [heavily modifying](https://pixnio.com/nature-landscapes/sunrise/sunrise-sky-backlit-dawn-water-sun-dusk-sea-ocean-beach-sunrise) and combining elements of several royalty free images, this mouse is longing for a taste of the cheese that the moon is *obviously* made of.

As a disclaimer, I am allergic to cheese...  but I like Photoshop and SE so all is good :)

Comment: Does SE stand for the chemical element Selenium?

Comment: @SamyBencherif Nope - it stands for "I was too lazy to type out Stack Exchange"

Answer (score 72):

A cheezy freehand circle for you :)

[image: A cheezy freehand circle]

Comment: -1 for not using the jQuery cheese plugin

Comment: This is genius.

Comment: @Machavity I wanted to, but it turns out it isn't compatible with MS Paint yet

Answer (score 63):

### Have some easy-to-code cheese!

> With some work and toil, I've found some plain cheese,
>   It'd bring me delight, if you'd use some of these.
>   Should you want with strength, a password or three,
>   I'd strongly suggest, using cheese ASCII!

```
        ___ _____
       /\ (_)    \
      /  \      (_,
     _)  _\   _    \
    /   (_)\_( )____\
    \_     /    _  _/
      ) /\/  _ (o)(
      \ \_) (o)   /
       \/________/     


         _--"-.
      .-"      "-.
     |""--..      '-.
     |      ""--..   '-.
     |.-. .-".    ""--..".
     |'./  -_'  .-.      |
     |      .-. '.-'   .-'
     '--..  '.'    .-  -.
          ""--..   '_'   :
                ""--..   |
                      ""-' 

         _________ /-'._________
        /         /     \       .
       / ______  /       .       -
      / /      //         |        --------.
     / /      /|----------|                .
    / /      //|          |          _____.'|
   / /______// |          |     _ .       |.
  /  -------'   ----------   ,-   | ------
  --------------------------   _ "
 |_________________________|,-
```

(Just make sure you keep this guy away from it!)

```
(o)(o)--.
 \../ (  )
 m\/m--m'`--.
```

<sup>Credit [here](http://ascii.co.uk/art/cheese) and [here](https://www.asciiart.eu/animals/rodents/mice)</sup>

Comment: scohe001 is asciing for a cheese board.

Comment: Why does the first piece of cheese have a pair of eyes?

Comment: @MrLister your cheese doesn't??

Comment: Now you just need to [write a cheese-formed brainfuck script that will produce that output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21857/17452).

Answer (score 59):

An overflow of cheese?! You gotta brie kidding!

This is gonna be grate.

I tried to make it as gouda as possible, and it ended up being made swiss love. A holy rendition of our most sacred symbol.

Say cheese! ;)

[image: cheese overflow]

And, if you were thinking, "ricotta try this!", here is a platter straight from the block.

[image: cheese overflowing]

Comment: Just threw this together. I'm not sure if I should expand it to have replacements for the other language Cheese Overflow sites and/or the rest of the Cheese Exchange network, but I figured I should post it somewhere just in case I don't get back to it. [https://0bin.net/paste/-t4o+mdYc2HRVSrg#6pTioPv+kV6owg+Fh+0hwwKwElXNNZH2RoMH4AQoRaO](https://0bin.net/paste/-t4o+mdYc2HRVSrg#6pTioPv+kV6owg+Fh+0hwwKwElXNNZH2RoMH4AQoRaO)

Comment: @3D1T0R - To note, it may be difficult to simply expand this with a user script, as the icon I created is in the same font and kerning as the original Stack Overflow icon. It would require a manual process per exchange, or the creation of the entire alphabet in a svg image.

Comment: I did the first two (Cheese Overflow & Meta Cheese Overflow) manually. I kind of figured I'd have to do the rest the same way, though come to think of it there might be some ways I can cheat on sites that display the logo/name via an SVG image. Even then I'd have to manually verify that they're all working as intended.

Answer (score 54):

Oh Dair-y and [Holey Cow!](https://www.cheese.com/holey-cow/). What did y'all think? Let's start with the hardest task? Oh well. I started my cheesy queste [here](http://www.newcrochetpatterns.com/crochet-patterns-manfred-crochet-the-mouse-with-cheese/) and from there it all went [rolling down hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper%27s_Hill_Cheese-Rolling_and_Wake).

I'm personally most fond of soft cheeses, but I make an exception for [hooks](https://www.cheese.com/hooks-5-year-cheddar/). I'm also very fond of crochet hooks. But what's a better entry for a digital cheese competition than a perfect piece of [Dutch E-dam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edam_cheese)? So, I went to get some... But...

## [EEEEK!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83625/369802) A Mouse!.

[image: crochet cheese with mouse]

Answer (score 53):

**STOP! Look and listen!**

This was a quadruple cheeseburger with extra bacon, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You didn't pass.** This food has severe culinary issues. It is fattening nonsense, oversized, Spam-packed, blatantly unhealthy or otherwise irredeemable - connoisseurs will find it disgusting or repulsive rather than tasty. Please **throw away** or **recommend license revocation** when reviewing such food.

Don't worry, we've already handled this food appropriately (we *did* take the food handler's course) - but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

<kbd>I've had enough of these cheesy audits</kbd>

Answer (score 51):

Ready for a Stackoverflow cheesy riddle? (Hint: Feta pH usually ranges from [4.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feta#Description) to 4.6):

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~gsamaras/soCheese.html)</kbd>

Or, view it below:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#slide').click(function() {
        if($("#answer").val() != 4.4) {
     $('#slide').text("Try again..");
            return;
        }
        $('#slide').hide();
        setTimeout(hide_puzzle, 500);
        setTimeout(decode, 1500);
    });
});

function hide_puzzle() {
     $('#puzzle').hide();
}

function decode() {
     var delay = 0;
     var reels = $('#reels').children().each(function() {
         var reel = this;
         setTimeout(function() {
             $(reel).toggleClass("reel-change");
         }, delay);
         setTimeout(function() {
             changeLetter(reel);
         }, delay + 500);
         setTimeout(function() {
             $(reel).toggleClass("reel-change");
         }, delay + 1000);
         delay += 200;
     });
}

function changeLetter(el) {
    el.innerHTML = incrementChar(el.innerHTML);
}

var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('')
function incrementChar(c) {
    var index = alphabet.indexOf(c);
    return alphabet[index + -4] || alphabet[index + -4 + 26] || alphabet[0];
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Delius+Unicase');

#reels {  
  font-family: 'Delius Unicase', sans-serif;
}

#reels > div {
  width: 12px;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:3px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#reels > div.end-of-word {
  padding-right:14px;
}

#reels > div.reel-change {
  animation: slideReel 1s 1;
}

@keyframes slideReel {
  0% {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity:1;
  }
  49% {
  transform: translateY(-30px);
  opacity:0;
  }
  50% {
  transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  100 % {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity:1;
  }
}

#reels {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}


.myButton {
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #1c1b18;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #1c1b18;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #1c1b18;
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #eae0c2), color-stop(1, #ccc2a6));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #eae0c2 5%, #ccc2a6 100%);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eae0c2 5%, #ccc2a6 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #eae0c2 5%, #ccc2a6 100%);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #eae0c2 5%, #ccc2a6 100%);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #eae0c2 5%, #ccc2a6 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eae0c2', endColorstr='#ccc2a6',GradientType=0);
background-color:#eae0c2;
-moz-border-radius:15px;
-webkit-border-radius:15px;
border-radius:15px;
border:2px solid #333029;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#505739;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:12px 16px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
.myButton:hover {
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ccc2a6), color-stop(1, #eae0c2));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ccc2a6 5%, #eae0c2 100%);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ccc2a6 5%, #eae0c2 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ccc2a6 5%, #eae0c2 100%);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ccc2a6 5%, #eae0c2 100%);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc2a6 5%, #eae0c2 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ccc2a6', endColorstr='#eae0c2',GradientType=0);
background-color:#ccc2a6;
}
.myButton:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;
}


body{
background: #D1913C;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #D1913C, #FFD194);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #D1913C, #FFD194);
/*background: #FFAFBD;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #FFAFBD , #ffc3a0);
background: linear-gradient(to left, #FFAFBD , #ffc3a0);*/
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://thefavicongallery.com/g/o/gotcancer.org.ico"/>
<div id="reels">
  <div>X</div>
  <div>I</div>
  <div class="end-of-word">R</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>I</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>V</div>
  <div class="end-of-word">W</div>
  <div>W</div>
  <div>X</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>G</div>
  <div>O</div>
  <div>S</div>
  <div>Z</div>
  <div>I</div>
  <div>V</div>
  <div>J</div>
  <div>P</div>
  <div>S</div>
  <div class="end-of-word">A</div>
</div>
<p id="puzzle">Minimum pH of feta cheese = ?   <input style="width: 60px;" step="0.1" type="number" id="answer" placeholder="Answer" maxlength="3"><br></p>
<a href="#" id="slide" class="myButton">OK, check!</a>
```

Comment: @Mari-LouA I know! the min number is 4.4! The hint says: "Feta pH usually ranges from 4.4 to 4.6". When you answer correctly, the message will show itself. Let me know if you were able to solve it... Oh, you found it, I will try to fix it ASAP!

Comment: I didn't explain myself well. Yes, I got the answer. But I was expecting the letters to do something more... clever. Anyway, I sure as hell wouldn't be able to create anything similar, so bravo!

Comment: I fixed the counter scrolling! Well, the letters hop as many times as the integer part of the answer, back to the alphabet.. So for D, you would get A. Maybe you hadn't notice that @Mari-LouA :D Grazie!

Comment: GoGo ( *!Golang* ) for the Greek FETA cheese!!

Comment: Probably the best cheese of all @ChristosLytras

Comment: I see feta... I upvote

Comment: I just found out that neither jQuery, nor the lack of ES6, nor inline styles are bad enough to stop my hand from upvoting feta. If Frodo had feta along with the lembas bread, he would've reached and left Mordor quickly and intact. Up the cheese-horns!

Comment: @DimitrisDamilos, feta is unstoppable! dixromos98, you are a simple person, you see feta, you upvote!

Comment: Προχώρα Γιώργο!

Comment: Με τη φέτα για οδηγό @NikDrosakis!

Comment: Excellent Γιώργο, keep the good work up. Χαιρετισμούς!

Comment: I thought you would attract a few views from [your "how to get attention" meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317564/how-to-give-a-chance-to-my-cheesy-riddle), but not this much, let alone so many upvotes. I am flabbergasted by your success. Did you end up doing anything else to advertise, like tweeting the share link, or was this all meta?

Comment: I posted it on **Facebook** @SOLO, as eventually suggested, and the branching of the graph there is really helpful! I got connected with people who were a hop away!

Comment: Oh okay. That's less-flabbergasting. Thanks for the follow-up!

Comment: You are welcome and good luck @Solo. On second thought, I had also tried Instagram and a little of WhatsApp. Maybe I am not good at stories, but I saw the difference when I posted in Facebook. I think the fact that undergraduate, masters and SO group are full of programmers did the trick! I had tried YouTube also, but still, I think FB was the key.

Comment: SomethingBadHappened if you didn't feel good with my post, then you should downvote as well. Feta might be the [most ancient cheese](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-6138345/Scientists-discover-worlds-mature-cheese-7-200-year-old-traces-feta-found.html), and even nowadays in my village feta is produced without harming the animals. What went wrong then? Humans of industrial age, I guess, but sure a good topic for philosophical discussion...

Answer (score 45):

Ok, you moved our cheese. Let's get it back.

I start with a simple SQL query:

```
SELECT Id AS [Post Link], Body, PostTypeId, 'Body' AS RelField
  FROM Posts
  WHERE Body LIKE '%[Cc]heese%'

UNION

SELECT Id AS [Post Link], Title, PostTypeId, 'Title' AS RelField
  FROM Posts
  WHERE Title LIKE '%[Cc]heese%'
```

This gives all posts containing cheese. (currently 89 on MSE)

Let's continue by adding some fluff:

```
SELECT Id AS [Post Link], Body, PostTypeId, 'Body' AS RelField
  FROM Posts
  WHERE Body LIKE '%[Cc]heese%' AND 1=1 AND 2=2 AND 'Cheese'='Cheese' AND 3=3 AND 'cheese'='cheese' AND 'fhc'='fhc' AND 'Jon Skeet'='Jon Skeet' AND 42=42 AND 0<1 AND 1>0 AND 'StackOverflow'!='Evil'

UNION

SELECT Id AS [Post Link], Title, PostTypeId, 'Title' AS RelField
  FROM Posts
  WHERE Title LIKE '%[Cc]heese%' AND 1=1 AND 2=2 AND 'Cheese'='Cheese' AND 3=3 AND 'cheese'='cheese' AND 'fhc'='fhc' AND 'Jon Skeet'='Jon Skeet' AND 42=42 AND 0<1 AND 1>0 AND 'StackOverflow'!='Evil'
```

If we format this then appropriate:

```
                          SELECT
                 Id AS [Post Link], Body,
      PostTypeId, 'Body' AS RelField FROM Posts
WHERE Body LIKE '%[Cc]heese%' AND 1=1 AND 2=2 AND
-- ------------------------------------------------
'Cheese'='Cheese' AND 3=3 AND 'cheese'='cheese' AND
 'fhc'='fhc' AND 'Jon Skeet'='Jon Skeet' AND 42=42
AND 0<1 AND 1>0 AND 'StackOverflow'!='Evil'  UNION
SELECT Id AS [Post Link], Title, PostTypeId, 'Title'
AS RelField FROM Posts WHERE Title LIKE '%[Cc]hee'+
'se%' AND 1=1 AND 2=2 AND 'Cheese'='Cheese' AND 3=3
AND 'cheese'='cheese' AND 'fhc'='fhc' AND 'Jon Skeet'
='Jon Skeet' AND 42=42 AND 0<1 AND 1>0 AND'Stack'+
'Overflow'!='Evil' AND 2=2 AND 1=1 AND 3=3 AND 1=1
```

You recognize this?:

> 

---

<sub>On SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/edit/909117</sub>

Comment: so nerdy I had to upvote it!

Answer (score 45):

### The unicorn did it.

The question title asked "Who cut the cheese?" and, well, it looks like the unicorn did.

[image: Unicorn holding knife from cheese overflow 2018 set next to a piece of cheese]

Attribution:

- Unicorn image from [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180618)  by [Spontifixus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/195761/spontifixus)
- Knife image from [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515) by [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post)
- Cheese image by [Coyau](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Coyau) / [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:WikiCheese_-_Tomme_de_Savoie_-_20150619_-_005.jpg) / [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Comment: An upvote in memory of Lady Stackicorn. Lost on her travels :-(

Answer (score 45):

I thought I'd let the image speak for itself, but I have to add ... this was imagined, designed, and printed by me on my Anet A8 3D printer using PLA filament.

Which begs the question ... *Who **did** cut the cheese?*

If you consider you have to use a slicer to get the g-code (cura in this case),
well I guess you could say ***I did***.

[image]

Comment: This is 3D printed cheese? Wow... nice one :-)

Comment: Upvote for superb 3D printing dude!

Comment: Cheesy dilemma: how can anyone have cut it if it's made with additive manufacturing?

Comment: @Zaid - Sliced or cut ... does it really matter ;-)

Comment: I used to have that same slicer! Small world.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Ours still has the "spare" cutting blade underneath, lol ... good times.

Answer (score 43):

## [**404 Cheese Not Found**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7nZb.png)

[image]

Comment: If you feel something is missing that should be here, *[don't dare to contact us.](https://stackoverflow.com/contact)*

Answer (score 37):

I came home as usual, ready to make a nice dinner -- but no!  My kitchen was undergoing a **food emergency**!  That essential ingredient to accompany my nice bottle of Pinot Grigio was gone!

[image: near-empty cheese drawer]

Two slices of Provolone -- not nearly enough for a meal!  **Somebody moved my cheese!**  The [cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkSuV.jpg) wasn't talking, so I was going to have to hunt it down myself.

I found a single slice taunting me, daring me to find its compatriots.  Game on.

[image: slice hiding behind book]

(This is low-end actual cheese but *not* "cheese product".  This caused some discussion in the comments.)

Another slice had fled to the office, only to be caught by my attack-stapler.  Nobody messes with my stapler!

[image: red stapler]

Or my hat.  Sheesh.

[image: mod hat]

I'm not sure what the cottage cheese was thinking.  And no, it wasn't a very satisfying game of Bananagrams.  Cheese can't spell.

[image: games]

The Romano gets points for trying, but burrowing isn't its strong suit.

[image: cheese in stack of SE shirts]

But oh, the cream cheese -- kraftiest of all, it seems!  I haven't touched that box since spring!

[image: matzah box]

The search continued, until finally I'd found all my cheese again.

[image: cheese drawer, occupied]

Wait.  Where's the Jarlsberg?

Never mind.  I'm gonna have dinner.  And wine.  At some point you just have to let cheese go free, y'know?

Comment: I think cheese and "Matzos" is not tasty :).... you remind me the Passover holiday:)

Comment: I suppose you mean Pinot.

Comment: @לבנימלכה - actually, it's not bad. But there are more crumbs than when Aunt Sophie sat on it.

Comment: @Mithrandir Lol... who is  `Aunt Sophie`(or maybe I too young to know who is she...)

Comment: @לבנימלכה - https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Deborah-Katchko-Gray/Don-t-Sit-On-the-Afikomen

Comment: @Mithrandir awosome... Yes this song from my adolescence(from 2012)... I have no `Aunt Sophie` ...:)

Comment: @Mithrandir see my answer here

Comment: @לבנימלכה it's one of my lunch staples for that week because it's easy to do at work.

Comment: @Nemo I guess I should have found all the cheese and finished this writeup before opening the bottle.  *ashamed*

Comment: I'm not sure I should upvote this: that thing hiding on your bookshelf and the item caught by the stapler are not actually cheese.

Comment: @Marti its purpose is to populate grilled cheese sandwiches.  (That's actual cheese, not Velveeta or some such nonsense.  It's not *good* cheese, but it has its uses.)  Some of the individual Swiss cheese slices escaped too, but the cat was playing with them and they were all covered in lint and stuff, so I counted those as casualties.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I really happy to see image of "Matzos"  in this site :) and Ireally want T-shirt of SO :(

Comment: I think it's arguable whether that is "actual cheese". If the outer packaging calls it a "processed cheese food" or a "prepared cheese product" I'm pretty sure it doesn't count as "actual cheese". There's an impostor lurking in your fridge! (seriously, try some cheddar or gouda on a grilled cheese instead)

Comment: @DoktorJ the packaging calls it sliced cheese; I don't buy "cheese product".  (Swiss works nicely on a grilled cheese sandwich too.)

Comment: That's good to know! The cheese in those shots looked suspiciously like "cheese product".

Comment: Waaaaaaait a minute... workplace mods get workplace-themed staplers? Where's my RPG-themed dice-bag!?

Comment: @nitsua60 that was graduation swag, back when sites got graduation swag.  (It still hurts that Worldbuilding *just* missed on that.  Lots of us *really* wanted to see our robot on a notebook or t-shirt!)

Comment: sorry, indeed i had affected your cheese

Comment: Those are some serious e-merch-and-cheese!

Answer (score 33):

### **STACK EXCHANGE EXPLAINED: with CHEESE!**

(Or maybe it is "Cheese explained with Stack Exchange", I don't know...)

---

**Stack Overflow:**

```
Cheese
   Wensleydale (Swiss Happy Anniversary, Stack Exchange!Swiss) Brie
NoCheese
```

(As [one of the other answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316544/232439) mentioned, Cheese ++ is an esoteric language.)

---

**Life Hacks:**

[image]

---

**Arqade:**

[image]
*IT FILLS YOU WITH DETERMINATION*

---

**Skeptics:**

[image]

*And men never reached it...*

---

**Mathematics:**

[image]

---

**Arts & Craft:**

[image]

---

**SharePoint:**

[image]

(Yes, [SharePoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casu_marzu) is moldy, filled with bugs, unsafe to eat and probably illegal in most countries.)

Want more? Check [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1255/stack-exchange-explained-with-cheese)!!

Comment: Ok. Had to stop this for a while since I was ill, but I am happy to say that I restarted my "association game" in the linked chat room. Still waiting for guests if anyone wants to join.

Comment: ...dangit I should have refreshed the answer list and seen this before I posted my answer. Oh well. Have a +1!

Answer (score 29):

If we got some cheese every time we received an upvote, **[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)**:

[image]

Sorry for bad photo editing.

Comment: *the great pyramid of cheese-a (giza)

Answer (score 29):

Ever seen one of those "which breed of dog/Harry Potter character/programming language would you be" personality quizzes?

I decided to give a cheese-focused quiz to the Stack Exchange sites. (Well, not *all* the sites. Just the 15 at the top of [the list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), and a handful of others.) Here are the results:

**Stack Overflow**
*Feta*
It is, after all, the oldest cheese (or, at least, [the closest modern equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese#Origins)).

**Mathematics**
*Mozzarella*
One of the world's most popular, yet not talked about much. Also, [often associated with pizza.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=pizza)

**Stack Overflow in Russian**
[*Коралл*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korall)
'cause it's Russian, see?

**Ubuntu**
*Pepper Jack*
A popular, friendly introduction to something out of the mainstream.

**Stack Overflow in Spanish**
*Manchego*
And this one's Spanish.

**Super User**
*Cottage cheese*
Like Stack Overf—um, I mean, feta—it's one of [the earliest cheese types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese#Origins).

**Stack Overflow in Portuguese**
[*Requeijão*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requeij%C3%A3o)
Brazilian and Portuguese. C'mon, keep up.

**Stats**
*Gouda*
Nice enough, if kinda mild.

**Physics**
*Edam*
Pretty cool, for those who know enough to get past the outer shell.

**Unix & Linux**
*Five-cheese blend*
Kind of a mixture of multiple similar topics.

**Server Fault**
*Domiati*
An [early variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese#Origins) again... and a bit of a salty one.

**Electrical Engineering**
*Cheddar*
Often feels extra sharp.

**Geographic Information Systems**
*Blue cheese*
What really makes this special and distinctive from other cheeses/sites? An emphasis on [sticking pins in things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_cheese#Creation).

**Magento**
*Pecorino Romano*
Useful for making other things better, but not exactly a cheese people are enjoying mouthfuls of on its own. (See also Worldbuilding, below.)

**TeX and LaTeX**
*Provel*
Kind of a [specialty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provel_cheese). People who like it tend to be **really** into it.

**English Language & Usage**
*Neufchâtel*
A relatively old style; it's got a reputation for elitism in some circles.

**Apple**
*Gorgonzola*
Great with apples. If you don't have apples, maybe don't bother with this one.

**English Language Learners**
*Cream cheese*
Covers territory originally owned by Neufchâtel/EL&U, but has evolved into its own distinct entity.

**MathOverflow**
*American*
Cue semantics argument over whether this entry is technically [qualified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_cheese#Modern_varieties)/[eligible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277072) to be on the list.

**Blender**
*Queijo Computadorizado de Duarte*
Take a moment to be amazed at what is [clearly the best answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316621/). It's so awesome I don't even care that I'm giving free advertising to a competitor.

**SharePoint**
[*Government cheese*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_cheese)
Whether deservedly or not, [it's got some negative connotations](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-platforms).

**Code Review**
*Muenster*
Very pleasant, and can be applied in a wide variety of situations. Adding even just a little bit of this will greatly improve pretty much anything.

**Travel**
*Paneer*
Somehow, it seems foreign and accessible at the same time.

**Home Improvement**
*Parmigiano-Reggiano*
A bit rough around the edges, but overall, it's solid.

**Science Fiction and Fantasy**
*Pimiento cheese*
A fun cheese, if a little too spicy at times.

**Software Engineering**
*Emmentaler*
Better known to many by [another name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_cheese). (Never forget Programmers SE! (Or, for the true OGs, Not Programming Related.))

**Role-Playing Games**
*Colby Jack*
A blend of two different groups (sorry, couldn't figure out how to work in a literal [RAW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/rules-as-written/info) vs. unpasteurized joke), but they work together well.

**Stack Overflow in Japanese**
[*Sakura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakura_cheese)
A cheese from Japan. Seriously, you haven't figured out how this works yet?

**Worldbuilding**
*Nacho cheese*
This is just for fun for most people, but for a few, it's a livelihood. (Kinda the opposite of Magento.)

**Arqade**
*Skyrim goat cheese wheel*
Started out as an unremarkable component of a larger, established franchise, and quickly turned into an Internet phenomenon ([for example](https://knowyourmeme.com/photos/1005124-pac-man)).

**Puzzling**
[*Bergkäse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergk%C3%A4se)
Hard and nutty.

**Mi Yodeya**
*[Non-animal-rennet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75942/why-are-some-cheeses-not-kosher) cheese*
Are you kosher, but still want to have your <strike>cake</strike> cheese and eat it too? This is for you.

**Seasoned Advice**
*Époisses de Bourgogne*
Has the quality demanded by epicures, yet is accessible enough for all.

**Photography**
*Blue Stilton*
Meets all the usual criteria, and looks real good doing it, too.

**Interpersonal Skills**
*Milbenkäse*
It's debatable how many people are legitimately interested in this and how many just want to gawk at [a pile of excrement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milbenkase). Nevertheless, if the stories are to be believed, [it could solve some real problems](https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/strange-cheeses/index.html).

**Arts & Crafts**
*Cotija*
Okay, this doesn't really have anything to do with A&C, I just wanted to make the easy Catija joke.

**Community Building**
*Lymeswold*
[It sounded like a great idea on paper, but it's pretty much died off.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lymeswold_cheese)

**Veganism & Vegetarianism**
*Non-dairy cheese*
Not yet mature, and rarely used.

**Meta Stack Exchange**
*Vieux Boulogne*
[Really off-putting](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/1477473/Worlds-smelliest-cheese-named.html) at first, but it does have a small, devoted—one might say "cult-like"—following.

Comment: These are on-point, especially the SF&F one. We do tend to burn things on occasion.

Comment: "Hard and nutty" - ROFL.

Comment: B-b-but Requeijão is amazing :O

Answer (score 27):

Over at [RPGSE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions) we maintain a [cheese hall of fame](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7222/23970). This is a curated list of the cheesiest answers seen on site, including:

- [catnapping for an arbitrary number of spell slots](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78918/23970)
- [maximum attainable beard thickness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/127975/23970), and
- [Chuck E. Cheese, D&D3.5's fastest character.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14505/23970) (Superluminal, at that.)

**This community has created some of the finest internet-transmissible cheese out there.**

I propose that RPGSE as a whole be awarded a cheese board which we will time-share monthly among the top twelve cheese-posters on site, as ranked in our cheese hall of fame.

Comment: Okay, confession-time: the whole time-sharing thing didn't work out at all, and I've still got the cheese board. If any RPGSE cheesters want a cheese board still in its box, ping me.

Answer (score 26):

Little did I know how appropriate [this stack of cheddar slices I made a few days ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374676/6768037) would be now!

Enjoy! <3

[image: Origami]

Answer (score 26):

Needless to say: marmots **love** cheese. (This is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446516/121799) and done with a typesetting system that is often said to be only good for equations. The spurious black lines in the holes come from the conversion to an animated gif, and are not there on the pdf file that gets created when the following code gets compiled with `pdflatex`.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\DrawVerticalPart}[3][]{%
\draw[fill=yellow!30!orange,#1]
plot[variable=\x,domain=#2:#3,samples=30,smooth] 
({4*cos(\x)},{4*sin(\x)},0) -- ++(0,0,2)  --
plot[variable=\x,domain=#3:#2,samples=30,smooth] 
({4*cos(\x)},{4*sin(\x)},2) --cycle;
}
\newcommand{\CheesePiece}[1]{\ifcase#1
\or% 1: xz face
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,transform shape]
\filldraw[fill=yellow!80!orange] (4,2) -- (4,0) --(0,0) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
\foreach \x/\y/\r in {0.4/0.6/0.3, 
0.5/1.3/0.2,
1.5/0.5/0.4,
1.5/0.5/0.4, 
2.1/1.5/0.3,
2.5/0.8/0.2, 
3.3/1.1/0.3}
{\shade[ball color=yellow!80!orange,opacity=0.2] (\x,\y) circle (\r);}
\end{scope}
\or% 2: yz face 
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0,transform shape]
\filldraw[fill=yellow!80!orange] (-4,2) -- (-4,0) --(0,0) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
\foreach \x/\y/\r in {-0.4/0.6/0.3, 
-0.5/1.3/0.2,
-1.5/0.5/0.4,
-1.5/0.5/0.4, 
-2.1/1.5/0.3,
-2.5/0.8/0.2, 
-3.3/1.1/0.3}
{\shade[ball color=yellow!80!orange,opacity=0.2] (\x,\y) circle (\r);}
\end{scope}
\or% 3: top
\draw[fill=yellow!30!orange] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:270,samples=90,smooth] 
({4*cos(\x)},{4*sin(\x)},2) -- (0,-4,2) -- (0,0,2) -- (4,0,2);
\or% 4: bottom
\draw[fill=yellow!30!orange] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:270,samples=90,smooth] 
({4*cos(\x)},{4*sin(\x)},0) -- (0,-4,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0);
\fi} 
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,5,...,355}%{45,135,225,315} 
{%\tdplotsetmaincoords{120+20*sin(\X)}{-135+45*cos(2*\X)}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{90+30*sin(\X)}{\X}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use as bounding box] (-6,-3) rectangle (6,5);
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xtest}{sign(cos(\tdplotmainphi+90))}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ytest}{sign(-cos(\tdplotmainphi))}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ztest}{sign(cos(\tdplotmaintheta))}
%\node[anchor=north west] at (-6,5) {\X,\xtest,\ytest,\ztest};
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
\ifnum\xtest=1
  \CheesePiece{2}
  \ifnum\ytest=1
    \CheesePiece{1}
    \DrawVerticalPart{0}{\tdplotmainphi-180}
    \DrawVerticalPart{\tdplotmainphi}{270}
  \else
    \DrawVerticalPart{0}{\tdplotmainphi-180}
  \fi
\else
  \ifnum\ytest=1
    \CheesePiece{1}
    \DrawVerticalPart{\tdplotmainphi}{270}
  \else
    \DrawVerticalPart{\tdplotmainphi}{\tdplotmainphi+180}
  \fi
\fi
\ifnum\ztest=1
\CheesePiece{4}
\else
\CheesePiece{3}
\fi
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 25):

2018: [**C**atija **H**ired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313086/278659), [**E**lection **E**xperimenting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314459/278659), **S**tack **E**xchange!

2017: [**C**ake **H**at](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304644/278659), [**E**xact-dupe **E**dits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/278659), **S**tack **E**xchange!

**C**ome now, think of all the years of SE's lif**e**.
**H**elping people here has many benefit**s**:
**E**very time your post is useful, rep you'll hav**e**.
**E**xperts sharing with their peers their facts and knowledg**e**:
**S**o the system works, and so SE can flouris**h**.
**E**xcels in what it does, so each site gets good traffi**c**.

2008: **C**reating **H**istory: **E**xperts **E**xchange -> **S**tack **E**xchange!

---

- What did the cheese say when it saw itself in the mirror?

  > *Hallo, me!*
- What cheese do you use to get a bear out of a tree?

  > *Come on, bear!*
- How do you eat Welsh cheese?

  > *Carefully.*

Comment: It's a cookie hat... which, fortunately, still works.

Comment: @Catija In British English it doesn't :-(

Comment: But... you do use the word "cookie", right? And it's my hat, so my terminology should "win" over your local vernacular. 

Comment: @Catija [Cookies (US, CA) are biscuits (UK, AU, NZ).](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca-nz)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yeah, I know... but my understanding is that y'all do use the term cookie and you're sorta ignoring my main point. It's my hat and I call it a cookie hat.

Comment: This is like the MWAM theory, but better

Comment: @Catija Did you cook it twice? If so, it's a biscuit. But either way, it's a Catija Hat.

Answer (score 23):

Cantal me answer?

[image]

I don't know what ha Bandal websites affected - [Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGoFK.png), [Reddit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1MFG.png), [Youtube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNxb5.png), [Twitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MtMS.png), [Wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1eG0.png).

What Colby problem?

Chz help.

Tommes in advance.

---

Want this amazing experience for yourself?

[Download the font](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=71557672132594695317), install it, create a user script with the below, and enjoy the new Stack Exchange.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Cheese!
// @version      0.1
// @author       Me
// @match         *://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match         *://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match         *://superuser.com/*
// @match         *://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match         *://serverfault.com/*
// @match         *://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match         *://askubuntu.com/*
// @match         *://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match         *://stackapps.com/*
// @match         *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       *://api.*.stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var cheese_url = "https://isitbadforyou.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/article/pictures/798/big_is_swiss_cheese_bad_for_you..jpg";

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    try {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = cheese_url;
        img.width = elements[i].getBBox().width;
        img.height = elements[i].getBBox().height;
        elements[i].remove();
        elements[i].parentNode.appendChild(img);
        i--;
    } catch (Exception) {}
}

var style = document.createElement("style");
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("body *, body{font-family: Cheese !important;}"));
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("div.favicon, div.image, span.badge1, span.badge2, span.badge3, svg {content:url("+cheese_url+");}"));
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("span.-img {content:url("+cheese_url+");}"));
document.head.appendChild(style);

var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
    var sImage = images[j];
    var href = sImage.getAttribute('src');
    sImage.setAttribute("src", cheese_url);
}
```

Comment: Somebody should make an extension for this

Comment: @abc I added a user script. One may be able to get around needing to install a font (especially since there's already a cheese unicode character), but don't ask me how.

Answer (score 21):

#### Do you want to taste this Delicious Cheese Cake?

[image]

This cheese cake is generated via below CSS & HTML. **Run it, try it, & upvote it!** ;)

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khula:400,700,800|Lilita+One|Rammetto+One|Seymour+One");
* {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  text-align: center;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: plum;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.ctnr {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  height: 450px;
  width: 600px;
}

.cake {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ab6eab 60%, #dda0dd 70%);
  height: 165px;
  width: 600px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.plate {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #F2DAF0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 550px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d9c1d7, 0 6px 0 0 #c0a8be;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d9c1d7, 0 6px 0 0 #c0a8be;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d9c1d7, 0 6px 0 0 #c0a8be;
}

.plate:after {
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #F2DAF0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 395px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #e3cbe1, inset -2px 0 0 0 #c0a8be, inset -2px 3px 0 0 #c0a8be, inset 0 3px 0 0 #c0a8be;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #e3cbe1, inset -2px 0 0 0 #c0a8be, inset -2px 3px 0 0 #c0a8be, inset 0 3px 0 0 #c0a8be;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #e3cbe1, inset -2px 0 0 0 #c0a8be, inset -2px 3px 0 0 #c0a8be, inset 0 3px 0 0 #c0a8be;
}

.crust {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 90px;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #E5AC72;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 5px 0 #c78e54, inset 5px -3px #c78e54;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 5px 0 #c78e54, inset 5px -3px #c78e54;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 #c78e54, inset 5px -3px #c78e54;
}

.crust:after {
  top: 2px;
  left: 10px;
  background: #d1985e;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 6px #c78e54, 16px 2px #d69d63, 30px 1px #cc9359, 35px 4px #c78e54, 50px 7px #d1985e, 65px 2px #c2894f, 85px 4px #bd844a, 90px 6px #b37a40, 90px 2px #d1985e, 110px 1px #d69d63, 115px 2px #c2894f, 130px 8px #b87f45, 150px 4px #c78e54, 160px 6px #b37a40, 180px 4px #d1985e, 200px 2px #d69d63, 230px 6px #c78e54, 235px 2px #bd844a, 240px 8px #d1985e, 260px 1px #b37a40, 275px 5px #c78e54;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 6px #c78e54, 16px 2px #d69d63, 30px 1px #cc9359, 35px 4px #c78e54, 50px 7px #d1985e, 65px 2px #c2894f, 85px 4px #bd844a, 90px 6px #b37a40, 90px 2px #d1985e, 110px 1px #d69d63, 115px 2px #c2894f, 130px 8px #b87f45, 150px 4px #c78e54, 160px 6px #b37a40, 180px 4px #d1985e, 200px 2px #d69d63, 230px 6px #c78e54, 235px 2px #bd844a, 240px 8px #d1985e, 260px 1px #b37a40, 275px 5px #c78e54;
  box-shadow: 10px 6px #c78e54, 16px 2px #d69d63, 30px 1px #cc9359, 35px 4px #c78e54, 50px 7px #d1985e, 65px 2px #c2894f, 85px 4px #bd844a, 90px 6px #b37a40, 90px 2px #d1985e, 110px 1px #d69d63, 115px 2px #c2894f, 130px 8px #b87f45, 150px 4px #c78e54, 160px 6px #b37a40, 180px 4px #d1985e, 200px 2px #d69d63, 230px 6px #c78e54, 235px 2px #bd844a, 240px 8px #d1985e, 260px 1px #b37a40, 275px 5px #c78e54;
}


.filling {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 110px;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffffc4;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 5px 0 #ffff74, inset 0 -40px #ffff9c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 5px 0 #ffff74, inset 0 -40px #ffff9c;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 #ffff74, inset 0 -40px #ffff9c;
}

.toping {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 210px;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}

.toping:before {
  left: 30px;
  bottom: -9px;
  background: linear-gradient(5deg, #f8576d 65%, #ff758b 65%);
  height: 50px;
  width: 270px;
  -moz-transform: rotate(4.5deg) skewx(-50deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(4.5deg) skewx(-50deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(4.5deg) skewx(-50deg);
  transform: rotate(4.5deg) skewx(-50deg);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 268px 24px, 270px 26px, 0 50px);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 268px 24px, 270px 26px, 0 50px);
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 5px 0 #e44359;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 5px 0 #e44359;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 #e44359;
}

.toping:after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e44359, #ff758b 50%);
  height: 6px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset -2px 0 #ff758b, inset 5px 0 #d02f45, inset 0 -4px #e44359;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -2px 0 #ff758b, inset 5px 0 #d02f45, inset 0 -4px #e44359;
  box-shadow: inset -2px 0 #ff758b, inset 5px 0 #d02f45, inset 0 -4px #e44359;
}

.coulis {
  left: 185px;
  bottom: 218px;
  height: 26px;
  width: 105px;
  background: #8a0000;
  -moz-transform: skewy(1deg);
  -ms-transform: skewy(1deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewy(1deg);
  transform: skewy(1deg);
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 2px -2px #8a0000, inset 5px -2px #bc1b31, 0 2px #760000, inset -2px 1px #8a0000, inset -3px 3px #d02f45;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px -2px #8a0000, inset 5px -2px #bc1b31, 0 2px #760000, inset -2px 1px #8a0000, inset -3px 3px #d02f45;
  box-shadow: inset 2px -2px #8a0000, inset 5px -2px #bc1b31, 0 2px #760000, inset -2px 1px #8a0000, inset -3px 3px #d02f45;
}

.drips {
  background: #e44359;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 160px;
  bottom: 202px;
  height: 13px;
  width: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px #d02f45, 10px 0 #e44359, 10px 4px #e44359, 10px 8px #e44359, 10px 12px #e44359, 10px 16px #d02f45, 20px 0 #e44359, 20px 4px #e44359, 20px 8px #d02f45, 40px 0 #e44359, 40px 4px #d02f45, 120px 0 #e44359, 120px 4px #d02f45, 180px 0 #e44359, 180px 4px #d02f45, 190px 0 #e44359, 190px 4px #e44359, 190px 8px #e44359, 190px 12px #d02f45, 220px 0 #e44359, 220px 4px #d02f45, 258px 0 #e44359, 258px 4px #d02f45, 268px 0 #e44359, 268px 4px #e44359, 268px 8px #e44359, 268px 12px #e44359, 268px 16px #d02f45, 278px 0 #e44359, 278px 4px #d02f45, 280px 0 #ff758b, 280px 4px #ff758b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px #d02f45, 10px 0 #e44359, 10px 4px #e44359, 10px 8px #e44359, 10px 12px #e44359, 10px 16px #d02f45, 20px 0 #e44359, 20px 4px #e44359, 20px 8px #d02f45, 40px 0 #e44359, 40px 4px #d02f45, 120px 0 #e44359, 120px 4px #d02f45, 180px 0 #e44359, 180px 4px #d02f45, 190px 0 #e44359, 190px 4px #e44359, 190px 8px #e44359, 190px 12px #d02f45, 220px 0 #e44359, 220px 4px #d02f45, 258px 0 #e44359, 258px 4px #d02f45, 268px 0 #e44359, 268px 4px #e44359, 268px 8px #e44359, 268px 12px #e44359, 268px 16px #d02f45, 278px 0 #e44359, 278px 4px #d02f45, 280px 0 #ff758b, 280px 4px #ff758b;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #d02f45, 10px 0 #e44359, 10px 4px #e44359, 10px 8px #e44359, 10px 12px #e44359, 10px 16px #d02f45, 20px 0 #e44359, 20px 4px #e44359, 20px 8px #d02f45, 40px 0 #e44359, 40px 4px #d02f45, 120px 0 #e44359, 120px 4px #d02f45, 180px 0 #e44359, 180px 4px #d02f45, 190px 0 #e44359, 190px 4px #e44359, 190px 8px #e44359, 190px 12px #d02f45, 220px 0 #e44359, 220px 4px #d02f45, 258px 0 #e44359, 258px 4px #d02f45, 268px 0 #e44359, 268px 4px #e44359, 268px 8px #e44359, 268px 12px #e44359, 268px 16px #d02f45, 278px 0 #e44359, 278px 4px #d02f45, 280px 0 #ff758b, 280px 4px #ff758b;
}

.lemon {
  left: 200px;
  bottom: 230px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center bottom, #ffff7e 58%, #ffffb0 58%, #ffffb0 65%, #ffff6a 65%);
  height: 37px;
  width: 75px;
  -moz-transform: skew(-4deg, 4deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-4deg, 4deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-4deg, 4deg);
  transform: skew(-4deg, 4deg);
  -moz-border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 #FFFC4C, 2px -1px #FFFC4C, 3px -2px #FFFC4C, 4px -3px #FFFC4C, 5px -4px #FFFC4C;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 #FFFC4C, 2px -1px #FFFC4C, 3px -2px #FFFC4C, 4px -3px #FFFC4C, 5px -4px #FFFC4C;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 #FFFC4C, 2px -1px #FFFC4C, 3px -2px #FFFC4C, 4px -3px #FFFC4C, 5px -4px #FFFC4C;
}

.lemon:after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  -moz-transform: scalex(0.75) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: scalex(0.75) rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: scalex(0.75) rotate(45deg);
  transform: scalex(0.75) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px #ffffb0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px #ffffb0;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px #ffffb0;
}

raspberry,
.rasberries:before,
.rasberries:after {
  background: #B21127;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 -2px #e44359, 1px -1px #e44359, 6px 0 #B21127, 6px -2px #e44359, 7px -1px #e44359, 12px 0 #B21127, 12px -2px #e44359, 13px -1px #e44359, -6px 0 #B21127, -6px -2px #e44359, -5px -1px #e44359, -12px 0 #B21127, -12px -2px #e44359, -11px -1px #e44359, 0 -8px #B21127, 0 -10px #e44359, 1px -9px #e44359, 7px -8px #B21127, 7px -10px #e44359, 8px -9px #e44359, 0 -8px #B21127, 0 -10px #e44359, 1px -9px #e44359, -7px -8px #B21127, -7px -10px #e44359, -6px -9px #e44359, -12px -8px #B21127, -12px -10px #e44359, -11px -9px #e44359, 12px -8px #B21127, 12px -10px #e44359, 13px -9px #e44359, 3px -15px #B21127, 3px -17px #e44359, 4px -16px #e44359, 9px -15px #B21127, 9px -17px #e44359, 10px -16px #e44359, -3px -15px #B21127, -3px -17px #e44359, -2px -16px #e44359, -9px -15px #B21127, -9px -17px #e44359, -8px -16px #e44359, 4px -22px #B21127, 4px -24px #e44359, 5px -23px #e44359, -3px -21px #B21127, -3px -23px #e44359, -2px -22px #e44359;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -2px #e44359, 1px -1px #e44359, 6px 0 #B21127, 6px -2px #e44359, 7px -1px #e44359, 12px 0 #B21127, 12px -2px #e44359, 13px -1px #e44359, -6px 0 #B21127, -6px -2px #e44359, -5px -1px #e44359, -12px 0 #B21127, -12px -2px #e44359, -11px -1px #e44359, 0 -8px #B21127, 0 -10px #e44359, 1px -9px #e44359, 7px -8px #B21127, 7px -10px #e44359, 8px -9px #e44359, 0 -8px #B21127, 0 -10px #e44359, 1px -9px #e44359, -7px -8px #B21127, -7px -10px #e44359, -6px -9px #e44359, -12px -8px #B21127, -12px -10px #e44359, -11px -9px #e44359, 12px -8px #B21127, 12px -10px #e44359, 13px -9px #e44359, 3px -15px #B21127, 3px -17px #e44359, 4px -16px #e44359, 9px -15px #B21127, 9px -17px #e44359, 10px -16px #e44359, -3px -15px #B21127, -3px -17px #e44359, -2px -16px #e44359, -9px -15px #B21127, -9px -17px #e44359, -8px -16px #e44359, 4px -22px #B21127, 4px -24px #e44359, 5px -23px #e44359, -3px -21px #B21127, -3px -23px #e44359, -2px -22px #e44359;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px #e44359, 1px -1px #e44359, 6px 0 #B21127, 6px -2px #e44359, 7px -1px #e44359, 12px 0 #B21127, 12px -2px #e44359, 13px -1px #e44359, -6px 0 #B21127, -6px -2px #e44359, -5px -1px #e44359, -12px 0 #B21127, -12px -2px #e44359, -11px -1px #e44359, 0 -8px #B21127, 0 -10px #e44359, 1px -9px #e44359, 7px -8px #B21127, 7px -10px #e44359, 8px -9px #e44359, 0 -8px #B21127, 0 -10px #e44359, 1px -9px #e44359, -7px -8px #B21127, -7px -10px #e44359, -6px -9px #e44359, -12px -8px #B21127, -12px -10px #e44359, -11px -9px #e44359, 12px -8px #B21127, 12px -10px #e44359, 13px -9px #e44359, 3px -15px #B21127, 3px -17px #e44359, 4px -16px #e44359, 9px -15px #B21127, 9px -17px #e44359, 10px -16px #e44359, -3px -15px #B21127, -3px -17px #e44359, -2px -16px #e44359, -9px -15px #B21127, -9px -17px #e44359, -8px -16px #e44359, 4px -22px #B21127, 4px -24px #e44359, 5px -23px #e44359, -3px -21px #B21127, -3px -23px #e44359, -2px -22px #e44359;
}

.rasberries {
  left: 220px;
  bottom: 250px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: -42px 27px #c6253b, -24px 34px #df3e54, 66px 34px #da394f, 76px 21px #c6253b, 80px 30px #d5344a, 90px 16px #da394f, 95px 30px #e44359, 100px 19px #df3e54, 110px 24px #cb2a40, 125px 32px #da394f, 135px 26px #d02f45, 145px 30px #c6253b, 155px 28px #e44359, 170px 32px #cb2a40, 185px 33px #da394f;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -42px 27px #c6253b, -24px 34px #df3e54, 66px 34px #da394f, 76px 21px #c6253b, 80px 30px #d5344a, 90px 16px #da394f, 95px 30px #e44359, 100px 19px #df3e54, 110px 24px #cb2a40, 125px 32px #da394f, 135px 26px #d02f45, 145px 30px #c6253b, 155px 28px #e44359, 170px 32px #cb2a40, 185px 33px #da394f;
  box-shadow: -42px 27px #c6253b, -24px 34px #df3e54, 66px 34px #da394f, 76px 21px #c6253b, 80px 30px #d5344a, 90px 16px #da394f, 95px 30px #e44359, 100px 19px #df3e54, 110px 24px #cb2a40, 125px 32px #da394f, 135px 26px #d02f45, 145px 30px #c6253b, 155px 28px #e44359, 170px 32px #cb2a40, 185px 33px #da394f;
}

.rasberries:before {
  left: 2px;
  bottom: -25px;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8) rotate(2deg) skewx(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8) rotate(2deg) skewx(-5deg);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) rotate(2deg) skewx(-5deg);
  transform: scale(0.8) rotate(2deg) skewx(-5deg);
}

.rasberries:after {
  left: 25px;
  bottom: -26px;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.7) rotate(-2deg) skewx(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.7) rotate(-2deg) skewx(-5deg);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.7) rotate(-2deg) skewx(-5deg);
  transform: scale(0.7) rotate(-2deg) skewx(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="ctnr">
  <div class="cake">
    <div class="plate"></div>
    <div class="crust"></div>
    <div class="filling"></div>
    <div class="toping"></div>
    <div class="coulis"></div>
    <div class="drips"></div>
    <div class="lemon"></div>
    <div class="rasberries"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Credit goes to [Mr. Salix Dubois](https://codepen.io/salixdubois/) for sharing this CSS [on CodePen](https://codepen.io/salixdubois/pen/BdOzxb)</sub>.

Comment: wow thats awesome in css

Comment: This is great work! But as you noted in your post, it's not your original work and is basically a direct copy from the CodePen you link to. I assumed work was supposed to be primarily original?

Comment: @James thanks! that's mine :) (only found it cuz I googled myself lol)

Answer (score 20):

Now I'm [not expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AtGF.png) to win one of the top 25 spots, because we all know the fastest gun in the west gets the cheese.
However I've decided to throw my hat in the ring. (Wait did I say [hat](http://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/)?... *cheese*, *cheese* stay focused here.)

I give you a unicorn thinking of cheese. SE has a long history with unicorns.
[image: A unicorn thinking of cheese, wishing for cheese, and dreaming of cheese.]

---

Because my mind is always on the bash <sup><sub><sup>([image: Dec 17th])</sup></sub></sup> here is a history of cheese through the winter bashes.

- **2012** [*Cheddarhead*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKDfv.png) "answer score 10+"
- **2014** [*30 minutes or less*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8NgV.png) (it has cheese on it) "get 5 answers in 30 minutes"
- **2016** A real hat featured in the [promotional](https://youtu.be/CDi_nj1-G6U?t=51) [video](https://youtu.be/CDi_nj1-G6U?t=57), multiple [times](https://youtu.be/CDi_nj1-G6U?t=111).
- **2017** [*Extra toppings*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDMg2.png) (really it's a *cheese* pizza) "answer +3 a question with accepted answer"

Answer (score 19):

A question about cheese magically attracts the TikZmice. They are part of a LaTeX package named "tikzlings" which is currently developed with the help many TeX.Stackexchange users.

In case you want to try it yourself, the package source code is available from https://github.com/samcarter/tikzlings.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikzlings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\mouse[cheese]
\fill[gray!59!white,rotate around={70:(0.385,0.93)}] (0.385,0.93) ellipse (0.24 and 0.13);
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

The name of this mouse is TokZ, which is a mixture of `TikZ` (the LaTeX package used to draw these cute little beings) and the Italian word for mouse (The user who had the idea to draw a mouse is Italian).

---

A few of its friends which share the mouse's passion for cheese:

[image]

---

And to not disappoint the ducks commenting to this post, the cheese is of course also available for the `tikzducks` (at least in the development version at https://github.com/samcarter/tikzducks):

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[cheese]
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the mouse's left paw over the cheese in your top picture but under in the row of animals? I don't know too much about TikZ...is this a setting of the package you've built?

Comment: @scohe001 Very good job in noticing this detail! The code I posted in the question first draws the mouse with chesse (`\mouse[cheese]`) and in the next line (`\fill....`) it draws again the paw on top of the cheese. I was too lazy to do this in the row of animals as well.

Comment: No ducks with cheese?

Comment: @PauloCereda Of course the ducks also have cheese (just a different type, the yellow one was invisible on top of the duck)!

Comment: oooooooooh `:)`

Comment: Like with a lot of the Exiting TikZ packages: I don't know *why* you would do something like this, but it is awesome and I am happy that you do something like this :D

Answer (score 18):

## This incredible web application will tell you your cheese name (the results are just amazing)!

```js
function loadModule(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({url: url, dataType: 'text'}).done(resolve).fail((j, t, e) => reject(e));
    }).then(d => new Function('var exports={},module={exports:exports};' + d + 'return module.exports')());
}
function loadModules(urls) {
    return Promise.all(urls.map(loadModule));
}
loadModules([
    'https://unpkg.com/cheese-name@1.0.0/lib/cheeses.js',
    'https://unpkg.com/seed-random@2.2.0/index.js'
]).then(modules => {
    const [cheeses, seedRandom] = modules;
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const rand = seedRandom($('#form [name="name"]').val());
        const randCheese = function() { return cheeses[Math.floor(rand() * cheeses.length)]; }
        $('#result').text(randCheese());
    });
}).catch(err => $('body').text(err.toString()));
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy';
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #ff5;
    color: #cb8300;
    font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', san-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
input, button {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #ff5;
    background: #cb8300;
    border: 2px solid #a56b00;
}
input {
    width: 10em;
}
button {
    padding: 0 0.25em;
    margin: 0 0.25em;
}
form, h1 {
     font-size: 1.5em;
     font-weight: bold;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form"><label>Name: <input name="name"></label><button name="submit">Find</button></form>
<h1> Name: <span id="result"></span></h1>
```

I heard some calls for JavaScript and jQuery, so how about a super-cheesy what's-my-cheese-name generator using the [cheese-name](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheese-name) NPM library?

Apparently, my name is Feta:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: No, *I'M* Stilton; preemptively he said, in case anyone got the same.

Comment: I am Greek and got "Tamie", while you hot "Feta". :/ +1

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 44,
  "colno": 52
}

Comment: @GeorgeM Odd. What browser are you getting that error in? I'm not even using `localStorage`.

Comment: garden-variety chrome, on win 7.  ???  But I wanted to be mimolette!

Comment: @GeorgeM I'm guessing maybe an error was throw? Perhaps ajax.googleapis.com or unpkg.com are block by your browser or corporate firewall.

Comment: oh, could very well be.  The error happens before I even type anything in the field, just as it comes up.  Sorry!  Let me try with another browser

Comment: Not IE either!  I'm doomed.  I'm just going to for mimolette and leave it at that.  Thanks though, I like the idea :-)

Answer (score 14):

### Here's some cheesy code

For SO's 10th anniversary, this will print "Cheese Overflow!" 10 times!

```
Cheese                                             //Begin program
Glyn(CheeseYears(10))Brie                          //Declare our cheese years to be 10
Cheddar                                            //Begin loop
    Wensleydale(Swiss Cheese Overflow! Swiss)Brie  //Print "Cheese Overflow!"
    Glyn(CheeseYears=CheeseYears-1)Brie            //CheeseYears--
Coleraine(Glyn(CheeseYears = 0))Brie               //Loop until CheeseYears == 0
NoCheese                                           //End program
```

#### Some explanation:

It turns out there's actually a [programming language named Cheese++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Cheese%2B%2B).

The syntax looks like:

```
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        Command         |                                                                                                                         Description                                                                                                                         |
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Cheese                 | Begin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
| NoCheese               | End                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| Wensleydale()          | Print (to console)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| Swiss                  | Quotation mark equivalent, used when creating strings.                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| Glyn(operation)        | The 'variable function'. It must be invoked in every single operation involving a variable, as demonstrated in the examples below. There is only one data type so no data type identifiers are required, saving space. A variable can take any ASCII value. |
| Cheddar...Coleraine    | repeat ... until                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| Stilton...Blue...White | if ... then...else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| Belgian                | Prints out the entire source code of the program to the console. Useful for debugging.                                                                                                                                                                      |
| Brie                   | Ends a line/section of code                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 13):

You wanted cheesy, so here are a whole lot of ______.

[image: Chee]
[image: Chee]
[image: Chee]
[image: Chee Chee]
[image: Chee]
[image: Qi]
[image: 22158 Chee]
[image: Chee]
[image: Chée]
[image: Chee]
[image: Qi]
[image: chi]
[image: Chi]
[image: Chee]

Comment: No idea what it is, but it surely isn't a proper answer to this contest.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: my fear is that if I make it blatantly obvious, it won't be funny when you do get it.

Comment: If this is a puzzle/riddle of some sort, at least say this in the answer somewhere. Many people (most, I believe) are not into puzzles.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: It isn't a puzzle, in the sense of spending an hour and still not being able to work it out. It is a joke, in the sense of it should take all of 10 seconds to work it out. [Sure, some people still might not get it. That's true of every joke. Spelling it out would make it less funny. That's also true of every joke.]

Comment: _You wanted cheesy, so here are a whole lot of **cheese**_?

Comment: @Oddthinking _it should take all of 10 seconds to work it out_ ... for someone who is used to **odd thinking**? ;) - I like it, and since the pics are linked, it's (ch)easy enough, I'd say....

Comment: @Oddthinking you think identifying a Chinese footballer in an icon that small is easy enough? Identifying an obscure indigenous artist who died in 1977 should take less than 10 seconds? Cheeze.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: When the image is a link to a Wikipedia page, and has some alt text, yes, yes, I do.

Comment: Then it has absolutely nothing to do with "working it out", but everything to do with clicking on an image, which is exactly what I did when I saw this post the second time... (the first time, it didn't occur to me).

Comment: @Mari-LouA: *shrug* Some people don't understand it. That doesn't bother me, as long as the people who *do* get it think it is funny. Voting suggests there aren't enough of the latter, so, meh. No cheeseboard for me. At least I
 tried. But dumbing it down would be self-defeating.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Be careful. I've found that, usually, when I don't understand something, I know less about it than I believe I do.

Comment: I enjoyed the joke

Comment: What a weird joke :/

Comment: Does anyone else see this as *mildly* racist? Not saying I'm offended, but this post makes me think of racism.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: It made you "think of racism" is a difficult claim to respond to. That's okay? That's good even. However, I do not think this is even mildly racist. There is a diverse range of cultures, the people included are accomplished in their fields and not being othered or denigrated, any more than making a joke about people called Matt/mat.

Answer (score 11):

I teamed up with Joel Bot* for a whole boatload of Swiss cheese, between the covers of a book from our favorite publisher.

[image]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](https://orly-appstore.herokuapp.com/generate?title=Constructing%20Cheese&top_text=Discuss%20everything%20that%20is%20not%20on%20topic!&author=Joel%20Bot&image_code=4&theme=8&guide_text=How%20to%20Make%20Bad%20Podcasts&guide_text_placement=bottom_right))</sub>

<sub>*Not really, but why not?</sub>

Comment: Wow.. this is epic.. :)

Answer (score 10):

I didn't cut the cheese, so don't blame it on me.

But I did see someone wearing a *chef's unicorn hat* cutting some cheese. You see, it's part of his *culture*; chopping, dicing, slicing, and grilling cheese, every single day of the year yet he never *wines*.

I'm positive he's the guy responsible for cutting your cheese. Maybe you *curd* ask him yourself?

[image: this guy cut the cheese]

<sup><sup>*Made with LDraw / rendered with Photoshop*</sup></sup>

Coincidentally, here's a *Cheese Overflow* logo from me:

[image: Cheese overflow]

<sup><sup>*Made with Photoshop*</sup></sup>

Comment: Can you give me the link to LeoDraw, I'm not familiar with that one.

Comment: @David Here is the link to [**LDraw/LeoDraw/LeoCAD**](https://www.leocad.org/):

Answer (score 10):

Introducing *ReactCheese*, the [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) awesome component for **Cheese Overflow 2018**! You can add your awesome cheese anywhere inside your application. And it’s flexible!

Here's the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ashrafonline/ReactCheese) and the [GitHub pages](https://ashrafonline.github.io/ReactCheese/)

[image: GitHub pages]

Answer (score 10):

When normal human's failing to find who cut the cheese, it's time for a superhero:

> "In cheesiest day, in cheesiest night,
>
> No cheese thief escape my sight.
>
> Let those who worship rotten cheese's might
>
> Beware my power in cheesey light!"

Here comes the cheesiest superhero: **Cheesy lantern**

[image]

> **Story of Origin:** Italian boy Formaggio came to America with big dreams of opening a restaurant chain based on dishes with lots of cheese and to run away from family and old friends who were never able to understand him due to his non romantic and asexuality. They want him to settle with a girl which he had no desire of. One blackest day with no moon in sky, he was going to a mart to buy [Camembert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camembert) but on the way he heard about an underground organization which works on experimental cheese and he went to steal some for his dishes. That was a huge factory where they were experimenting on cheese with many nontraditional ways, one of them was placing gamma rays on a shiny yellow cheese which was even brighter than the Moon. When he tried to steal some, security guys came in. In order to escape, he slipped on melted cheese-X. He managed to run away but was unable to steal any cheese. His elbow got injured in this process. After reaching home, he was trying to check his injury in the bathroom but there was no injury but a shiny yellow patch on his elbow.
>
> He never understood what was happening to him but from that day on wards his injuries healed so quickly while omitting yellow sticky substance. Even his hands omit cheesy sweat which made him able to stick to walls and climb any heights. He was a fan of DC comics and thought about using his new found powers to beat criminals. He bought multiple Halloween costumes and by combination make a superhero costume for himself. His friend Ande (Not Edna) told him not to use capes but he ignored the advice and made an oath like his favorite superhero Hal Jordan. He even figured out that he got many other powers like; cheesy slide which made him slide on superfast speed in any surface, throw sticky cheese balls from hand and cheesy super sense. So by day he was a cheese dealer and by night a Superhero.

Answer (score 9):

Everyone thinks that great Jon Skeet is the user with the highest reputation on Stack Overflow. But no one knows that there exists a secret profile hidden from the world, the profile of Mr. Gouda Cheese!

Stack Overflow keeps this cheesy user hidden, because the secret service agencies of many of the countries is looking for him. Currently he is hiding in one of the safe houses in the Netherlands, and was last seen near Schiphol Airport.

I had to hack into the SO servers to get this information. I know after this post, Stack Overflow staff, and secret agencies are going to come after me. But I want to spread the words of greatness of Mr. Gouda Cheese to the world. Here's the screenshot of his profile:

[image: Gouda Cheese]

Comment: I find it interesting that this secret power user (user 9983618193) has an id that is bigger than the newest user (user 10507549). It is exactly nine billion, nine hundred seventy-three million, one hundred ten thousand, six hundred forty-four bigger. Which means in real rough numbers, it has taken SO ten years to get ten million users. So this user id should be real in about 9,974 years.

Comment: May be that's how StackOverflow hides user profile from rest of the community. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It's interesting how a hidden user has 143,112,902 profile views.

Comment: @David The question is, will that user face peer pressure to change his or her profile to match this image?

Comment: LOL! Has 982,582 score in the [gauda] tag, but only a silver badge. It must suck not being able to single-handedly dupe-close questions about yourself...

Comment: I wonder that StackOverflow has been founded on 400BC look at the number of days visited its almost **2739.67945205 years** .   Wow!

Answer (score 8):

Help the **mouse** eat the cheese (See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fkn7chz/1/)).

How? click wherever position you want to eat it...

```js
var x,y,counter=0;
$('.cheese').mousemove(function(e){
  
  var offs = $(this).offset(),
      p    = {x:offs.left, y:offs.top},
      mPos = {x:e.pageX, y:e.pageY};
      x    = mPos.x - p.x - 50;
      y    = mPos.y - p.y - 50;
      
  $('.gray', this).css({left:x, top:y, backgroundPosition: -x+'px '+-y+'px'});
    
});
 $('.cheese').click(function(e){
   var wrapper = $(this).parent();
   var parentOffset = wrapper.offset(); 
   var relX = x;
   var relY = y;
   if(x>parentOffset.left+5 && y>parentOffset.top+80)
   {
    counter++;
   }
    $(this).append($('<div/>').addClass('placeddiv').css({
        left: relX,
        top: relY
    })); 
    if(counter>10){
    $('.cheese').hide();
    $('.hide').show();
    }

 })
```

```css
.cheese{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSXoO.png);
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.gray{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: white;
  border-radius:50%;
} 
.placeddiv{

    background-color: #fff;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
  color:red;
}
.hide img{
      width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div class="cheese">
  <div class="gray"></div>
</div>
  
<div class="hide">
<h1>
Warning!
</h1>
<p>
This cheese may contain a lot of calories <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.co.il/search?q=calories+yellow+cheese&oq=calories+of+yellow+ch&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.18943j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8">more...</a> 
</p>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is my mouth round but my bite square?

Comment: He probably forgot `border-radius:50%;` for `.placeddiv`

Comment: I was hoping a mouse would appear (or at least something would happen) when all the cheese was gobbled up...

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd It was my decision... :)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos feel free to edit if you want

Comment: @anonymous2 I agree. Disappointing.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @DuarteFarrajotaRamos. Still no mouse at the end.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd I edited my answer

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos see edit:)

Comment: Nice one, looking better

Comment: Thanks ... have a cheesy day :)

Comment: @anonymous2 see my edit... Hope not to disappoint you

Answer (score 8):

Of course, we all know who cut (or at least ate) the cheese.

[image: Panda who ate the cheese]

Answer (score 7):

The [gerbils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerbil) were out too long, they ate it (supporting evidence in screenshot):

[image]

### Situation right now (rodent alert, Not Safe For Search, many more out there)

[image]

Image taken from: [Pexels.com](https://www.pexels.com/photo/cheese-cute-gerbil-517891/).

Answer (score 6):

A lot of these answers are funny and great - but I'm on StackOverflow to be *productive* so I built a **useful utility** that picks a random cheese for you to enjoy. You can even pick which culture you want your cheese to be from!! And if you've never heard of that cheese, well, it even gives you a nice link to that cheese on Wikipedia.

Now, my JavaScript is pretty bad, so I decided, in the spirit of a StackOverflow-inspired post, to build the answer entirely from snippets of JavaScript code from StackOverflow, with only minimal renaming and adjustment. Enjoy the cheese!

```js
var cheeses = ["American", "Argentine", "Australian", "Austrian", "Belgian", "Beninese", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Brazilian", "British", "Bulgarian", "Canadian", "Chilean", "Chinese", "Cornish", "Croatian", "Czech", "Danish", "Dutch", "Egyptian", "Emirati", "English", "Finnish", "French", "German", "Greek", "Hungarian", "Indian", "Irish", "Italian", "Piedmontese", "Sardinian", "Kenyan", "Lithuanian", "Macedonian", "Maltese", "Mauritanian", "Mexican", "New Zealand", "Nicaraguan", "Norwegian", "Pakistani", "Polish", "Portuguese", "Romanian", "Russian", "Scottish", "Serbian", "Slovak", "South African", "Spanish", "Swedish", "Swiss", "Tibetan", "Turkish", "Ukrainian", "Venezuelan", "Welsh"];
/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/17865880/1204143 */
var dropdown = document.getElementById("menu");
/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/1204143 */
var arrayLength = cheeses.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.text = cheeses[i];
    opt.value = cheeses[i];
    dropdown.options.add(opt);
}

/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/36988565/1204143 */
function processResult(apiResult) {
    /* https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915122/1204143 */
    var items = apiResult.query.categorymembers;
    var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];

    $('#display-result').append('<p>Your random ' + cheese + ' cheese is: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + item.title + '">' +item.title+'</a></p>');
}

/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/14004145/1204143 */
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'display-result';
iDiv.className = 'block';

// Create the inner div before appending to the body
var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
innerDiv.className = 'block-2';

// The variable iDiv is still good... Just append to it.
iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

// Then append the whole thing onto the body
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);

/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/40986153/1204143 */
var goBtn = document.getElementById("goBtn");
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

goBtn.onclick = function() {
    cheese = menu.value;
    /* https://stackoverflow.com/a/3586781/1204143 */
    if(menu.value === "RANDOM") {
        /* https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915122/1204143 */
        cheese = cheeses[Math.floor(Math.random()*cheeses.length)];
    }
    /* https://stackoverflow.com/a/36988565/1204143 */
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
        data: { action: 'query', list: 'categorymembers', cmtitle: 'Category:' + cheese + ' cheeses', format: 'json' },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: processResult
    });
}
```

```html
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37016293/1204143 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Get a random cheese by country</h2>
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40986153/1204143 -->
<select id="menu">
  <option selected="selected" value="RANDOM">Random</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="goBtn" value="GO!">
```

Answer (score 6):

I see that several people went for the cheese Stack Overflow logo, and I don't make any claim to originality, like in most parts of my life, in my ability to make cheese sculptures. That said, I was disappointed how two dimensional the other cheese logos were, so at the risk of some gravity assisted theatrics and my sanity, I decided to elevate the logo to the correct viewing orientation (websites are obviously walls, not floors.) I do not recommend cheddar for architectural or engineering challenges, though the toothpicks held up as well as could be expected. Please enjoy the most fleeting form of the SO logo – short lived due to both hungry bystanders and physics.

The one major improvement I would make on this logo would be to display it on an appropriately be-logoed cheese board.

[image: Cheese overflow, now in 3D]

Comment: 7/10 for the photography, 8/10 for the concept, 9/10 for the stylish platter, but 5/10 for the sculpture. You can do better! Photoshop? CGI?

Comment: This is about my artistic authenticity in an analog medium! No hate for digital art, but I want my cheese tangible/edible!

Comment: I'd suggest that you give it another go, the idea is good, the cheese colour is perfect, so it will earn upvotes but the execution looks sloppy. The slices should be the same thickness for example. And IMO a spot of photoshopping to eliminate the toothpicks would make it look fantastic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree with your rating of the platter. That's the only thing I'd upvote for, but that wouldn't be in the spirit of the contest. :) I'd also say to redo the sculpture. I like that it's **not** photoshopped or CGI, but that doesn't mean it can be thrown together and not look **good**. A little effort goes a long way.

Answer (score 5):

Everyone's Rushan to post an Urdă answer Paneer than [JohnP's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316521/308065), but I'd prefer uniqueness to another punny Saga (I'm not trying to Gjizë anyone's Pultost). Imsil working on mine, but here's what I've got so far.

#### Change Log:

- v0.0.0: Initial version.
  Segfaults if you ask for port. I don't know why, but it it seems appropriate.
- v0.0.1: Fixed segfault.
  The segfault was caused by slicing the cheddar too thickly. This caused it to spill out into the NULL page.
- v0.1.0: Added port.
  Well... added port *shelves*. Port's expensive; we'll probably have some in the patch version.
- v0.1.1: Put port into some of the shelves.
  Who knew that the drunken ramblings of a waiter would have so much to do with operator precedence?

### `stdboard.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define charkassiye char *
#define mish main
#define into int
#define cubes []
#define eat printf(
#define some "%s",
#define quickly );
#define consume(o, s) printf("%s: %" #o, #s, (s))
#define strips ;
#define swap do{register char _v=
#define container if (_v==
#define with ;
#define serve }
#define once while(0)
#define before for
```

### `cheese.c`

```
#include "stdboard.h"

/* Associate prepositions with verbs */
#define cut into

/* Associate nouns with verbs */
#define drank drink

/* Define words */
/* Nouns */
#define glass   /**/ container
/* Adverbs */
#define loudly  "\n" quickly
#define calmly  /**/ loudly
/* Verbs */
#define drink   /**/ eat
#define suggest /**/ complain

/* Define units */
#define mm  0
#define g   1
#define lb  2

/* Solve common cheese-related problems */
#define PROBLEM    SOLUTION
#define complain   eat some

/* Serving instructions */
#define of(wine) *#wine){(wine)(\
    slices - 2,2+               \
    small); break;       } //optional

/* Table of contents */
cut mish(into slices, charkassiye /*into*/ small cubes);
port (into glasses, charkassiye optional cubes);

cut mish(into slices, charkassiye /*into*/ small cubes) {
    if (slices < 2) return
        complain "Not enough slices!" loudly

    cut cheddar
      = (into) small [1] [mm] strips

    swap cheddar with
        glass of (port)

    serve once;
}

port (into glasses, charkassiye* optional) {
    if (glasses < 1) return
        complain "I don't have any port!" loudly

                   before (long i = 2;
i   <              drank "some port"
+9)+(**optional    quickly i  = i  -+ -  1ll)
                   if (1+ drink "is"
+2)-(* *                             optional
%i>0)                                          )
    {                  complain "No port!" loudly
                       goto recommend_cheese;
    }                  complain "N0 Port!\n"-0+3 +0**loudly
                   "CYCLOPS CHEESE UNICAT! ^^ ^ ^^^:@jE2v ";

    /* We apologise; the writer of the previous code was...
       somewhat inebriated. We will not be serving such
       drinks in future, even if they do go well with cheese. */

    recommend_cheese:
    suggest "Have you tried some charkassiye with that? "
            "Or perhaps some mish?"                      calmly

    /* We won't ask you to return the glasses. Sorry again. */
    return mish(glasses, optional);
}
```

Comment: At the moment it segfaults if you ask for port; I'm not sure why but it seems appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

I hereby present you with... Free Hand Cheese House, aka FHCH!

[image: cheese house]

- 100% Self Made
- 100% Cheese (on bread)
- 100% Edible

And the bonus feature: you can put the FHCH inside oven or microwave to get a Melting Cheese House! :)

Comment: Yummm.....!! :)

Answer (score 4):

You said links to videos was ok, so I'll hope a game on an external site is ok. The site is mine, the software for the game is [mine](https://wordpress.org/plugins/crosswordsearch/), only the cheese, on the whole, is imaginary.

Since I am neither English- nor Welshman I cannot say whether they all could be found in real groceries. I only know I read about them in a book by [Jasper Fforde](http://www.jasperfforde.com//subindex/tn5subindex.html).

[In this crossword riddle there are ten hidden cheeses.](https://browser-unplugged.net/blog/cheese.en.html)

[image: In this crossword riddle there are ten hidden cheeses.]

Comment: I simply can't find more than 6 cheeses in your word search. Can you at least post a full word list?

Comment: (The ones that I've found are camembert, cheddar, edam, gorgonzola, gouda, and jarlsberg.)

Comment: Check the Cheese Enforcement Agency website. They are all mentioned there. (And take into account that Jasper Fforde, who made them up, is welsh.)

Comment: The Cheese Enforcement Agency has Dolgellau. The puzzle has Dolgelau.

Comment: You are right. I have corrected that error, with sincere appologies to all inhabitants of that historic town.

Answer (score 4):

foods again? I know spammers love this most.

I've listed potential product names for the next wave of upcoming spam:

- Keto Cheese Diet
- Keto Cheese Shark Tank
- Perfect Cheese Diet
- Premium Cheese Diet
- Cheese Forskolin
- Total Cheese Weight Loss
- Beautiful Cheese Serum
- Radiantly Slim Cheese
- Neuro Cheese XT
- Cheese-y Testo Booster
- Rapid Cheese Weight Loss
- Alpha Pro Cheesing Diet
- Slim Cheese Diet
- CheeseFit Keto
- Garcinia Cheese
- Cheese Cambogia
- Ultimate Cheese Diet
- Gigantic Cheese Skin Care
- TestoCheese Weight Reduction
- Cheese-y Muscle Builder
- Alpha Cheesy XT
- Cheese Drive 365
- Cheesey Serum
- Cheesy P**** Enlargement
- Healthy Cheese CBD Oil
- Neuro Cheese Cream

And of course, these potential related domains:

```
cheesesupplement.com
supplement4cheese.com
healthycheesediet.com
cheesesupplementsreviews.com
cheese4forskolin.com
cheeseysharktank.com
supplementcheesediet.com
cheesegarcinia.com
```

Read More @>>> [Buy CheeseOverflow Supplements now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515)

If you're confused, fell free to contact CheeseOverflow Customer Service Numbers at `cheeseoverflowsupportnumbers.com`, `cheeseoverflowcustomerservice.com`, `customerservice.com/cheese-overflow-service-numbers`, `cheeseoverflowtechnicalsupportnumbers.com`, `universalsupportnumbers.com/cheeseoverflow-customer-service` ......

I also know a hacker who can instantly repair your microwaves and ovens <s>and credit cards</s> and return you a nice cooking experience. contact him at cookerrepair@cheeseoverflow.com.

Do you want to find back your lost love? Have a talk with this cheesey spell caster and he'll bring your beloved Her back to you. He lives in Hogwarts School of Cooking and Processing Cheese >>> magiclovespellcaster@cheesehouse.com

Want monetary assistance with your personal finance? Let us know if some cheese helps. We offer loans with cheese and butter, and honey and sugar are also in stock. Contact yourkitchen@cheesebuy.com

University diploma forgery: University of CheeseStoke of America, Cheesecraft University of Australia, real certificate from Ministry of Education of People's Republic of Cheese, +QQ/WeChat 1234567890

cheese-cort service on stack overflow, cheese-cort pans, cheese-cort forks, cheese-cort syrup, call +1 234 567 0000

java training, php training, angular training, android courses, css development, c# development in wogharts school of cooking and cheesecraft

cheese overflow customer service number: +1 999 888 0000

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua[.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540) Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat[.](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1181) Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur[.](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/posts) Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum[.](https://charcoal-se.org/about)

Comment: Did you miss link-in-punctuation? I love that one.

Comment: @Chair Added that

Comment: You could make the link point to Fire Department or Charcoal HQ instead. That would be fun.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by the post, I decided to parody “Monster Mash” into the delightful song, “Munster Mash.”

[Link to the music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49xF5YVFQ8U) by Bobby "Boris" Picket so you can sing along!

---

### Munster Mash

```
I was waxing in my kitchen late one night
When my eyes brie-held a dairy sight
My Munster on its slab, orange in rind,
Took the microphone and let the whey unwind

It played the Munster mash
It was a rennet smash
It ripened in a flash
It played the Munster mash

From starter culture of a Parma cheese
To the Vacha Rossa and its curdled treat
The copper vats from night until dawn
Form a compact mass - Italian Parmesan

It did the Munster mash
It was a fermented smash
It curdled in a flash
It did the Munster mash
```

Answer (score 4):

My [Comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62616/scripting-a-boolean-modifier-loop-but-im-doing-something-wrong#comment107845_62642) on [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62642/5334) to my Blender SE question, September 2016, which makes this nicely aged cheese indeed!

> Yippee!! The SwissCheese modifier is born. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDEZP.png

[image: swiss cheese modifier]

Answer (score 3):

#### Foreword:

My idea took some time to mature, and it took much longer for me to get enough time to be able to follow through on it. I know that I am a bit late, but here it is.

I must apologise for my really rather cheesy puns (Oh no, yet another one!). I apologise too for the length of my story. I really didn't intend to write a book. Anyhow:

## The tail of two cheeses:

In the Brieginning<sub>1</sub> of this tail [Carlow](https://cheese.com/carlow/) was sitting, feeling cheesed off with his new job. He said aloud “I’ve been through too much strain<sub>2</sub> already. This is whey too limiting for me; I’ve gouda<sub>3</sub> see some of the big [wiede wield](https://cheese.com/wilde-weide/).” With that, he slipped out of his bag, off the shelf, and headed out in to the [blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_cheese).

After setting out, he found the sun very hot and unpleasant. It was nearly midday, and after some time his limbs where starting to feel wobbly. It wasn’t long, however, before he came upon a [pleasant creek](https://cheese.com/pleasant-creek/) among a grove of old, thickly-leafed trees. He stretched himself out, relaxing in the cool stillness near the bank. “This is the life” he murmured happily to himself. Just then he caught a slight movement above, and looked up. A large [grey owl](https://cheese.com/grey-owl/) was staring down on him from her perch. This was dangerous. He slowly backed through the grass, keeping his eyes fixed on the danger at hand. Suddenly she swooped. His nerve broke, and he turned and ran for his life. With a jerk he left he ground and was quickly carried over the treetops. Carlow could see no way of escaping, so he resigned himself to his fate. He could only wait while he was carried, moving on and on over the landscape.

A small, beady eye was watching him, though. A [red hawk](https://cheese.com/red-hawk/) had seen the prize which the owl carried, and decided that he had a good chance of stealing from her. She was probably sleepy, as it was the middle of the day. He trailed her, just out of sight. Suddenly he swooped in and made a grab for Carlow. The owl wheeled, furious at being attacked. He came in again, and as she struck out at him with her talons, Carlow felt suddenly weightless. Luckily for him, the owl had lost a lot of height in the brief fighting, so he only had the wind knocked out of him by the semi-hard ground. Getting up, he saw a [white stone farmhouse](https://cheese.com/whitestone-farmhouse/) just a few metres away, and made a dash for it, hoping to reach it before he could be caught again.

Carlow squeezed in through the door, which was ajar, over the [doorstone](https://cheese.com/dorstone/) and found himself in a large kitchen. The floor was of large flagstones, and the walls where plastered and white-washed. On the counter a cheese board stood. It was a difficult climb, but eventually he scrambled onto the countertop, breathless. On the board near him there was a lovely piece of cheese, who seemed to be crying. “Why are you crying?” Carlow asked. She started at the sound of his voice. “Hello,” she said politely while drying her eyes, “I’m [Victoria](https://cheese.com/victoria/). Who are you, and what are you doing here?”

“I’m Carlow,” he said simply, “and I came here to escape being eaten by two big birds. Why are you crying? Would you like to tell me what is wrong?”

“The mice have stolen the cat’s tail,” she replied, tears welling up again, “the cat has always kept the evil mice hordes at bay, but without his tail he is terrified of them. It was cut off a long time ago, and it was tied back on with string. The mice stole it while he was asleep. Now they are coming tonight to eat me, they told the cat so, and he is too afraid to do anything about it.”

“Isn’t there anywhere safe that you can go to?”

“No, there is no other place in walking distance, and there are mice everywhere after dark. I will be eaten, and you too, now that you are here. It is too terrible, what shall we do?” And with that she fell to weeping pitifully.

It [Greved](https://cheese.com/greve/)<sub>4</sub> him, but Carlow had no words to comfort her. He looked around the kitchen, then made his way back down to the floor. He might as well look around while he thought. He looked at the oven, the cupboards, the table and everything else in the kitchen. He saw the cat in the next room, pacing up and down and moaning “What shall I do, what shall I do?”.  Slowly a plan started to form in Carlow’s mind. The cat couldn’t fight off the mice, but he could help them get to a more defensible position, and also gather things which might help them keep the mice at bay. He went to talk to the cat.

Once he had got the cat (who’s name was Cheddar) to pay attention to him, the plan was quickly arranged. Cheddar helped Victoria and Carlow onto a high shelf in the tall, free-standing crockery cupboard. They then stockpiled potential weapons. The knives and forks in the cutlery drawer where too heavy for either of the two cheeses to lift, but they could be pushed off onto mice climbing up from below. Toothpicks they could use to hold to hold off mice who had made the climb up to the shelf, while the dishes themselves would scare mice on the floor as they smashed. When they were finally done, the sun was already low. “Where will you go, Cheddar?” Victoria asked.

“If you don’t mind, I’ll stay behind you two. It seems safest.” was the reply.

They didn’t have to wait long. As dusk set in, squeaks were heard from outside. Soon a crowd of mice strutted into the kitchen. More followed, cheering and waving Cheddar’s tail. For a while they ran around the kitchen sniffing, until some stopped at the bottom of the cupboard. Cheering again, the mice swarmed toward it. Victoria and Carlow [caerphilly](https://cheese.com/caerphilly/)<sub>5</sub> rolled a bowl over the edge of the shelf. It shattered on the hard stone floor, hurling knives and daggers in every direction. It was followed by a second, then a third. The mice where not going to give up however. Some were already two-fifths of the way up. A fork knocked one mouse to the floor and a knife took care of two others. Another knife and fork missed their mark.

---

---

Some time later the situation was much more desperate, and completely hopeless. The pile of cutlery was gone, as well as all of the smaller crockery. Mice crowded the edge of the shelf, and the two brave heroes where slowly being forced back. They could not hold out any longer.  “Goodbye my brave warrior” Victoria said gently, as she and Carlow where forced apart.  With a rush and some quick stabs with his toothpick Carlow pushed his way through his opponents, to the edge of the shelf. “Follow me, Cheddar!” he cried, and leaped.

All of the mice who were not in the attack were gathered together at the base of the cupboard. Carlow was completely surrounded. “We’ve [gotcha gouda](https://cheese.com/gotcha-gouda/)<sub>6</sub> now!” a large grey mouse  sneered, “did you think you could beat us?” Carlow did not answer, he only set himself and fought resolutely toward the middle of the mice. He felt teeth stab into his back, claws all over him, but he knew what he wanted.

---

“Cheddar, *please*” Victoria was pleaded, while backing away as she held off the oncoming wave, “you can do this; I know you can. Carlow knows you can. Please go to him as he asked, *please*.”

“I can’t” Cheddar quavered, “I can’t even move”.

“Just take one step” she begged again, “Cheddar, if you don’t we are done for. Please do ask he asked.”

---

Carlow had fought his way to Cheddar’s tail, and was holding onto it for all he was worth with one hand, while the mice piled onto him from every side. Suddenly Cheddar fell from above, scattering the mice, but they where on the attack again immediately. “Cheddar, your tail!” Carlow yelled above the squeaks and howls of the triumphant mice.  With his eyes shut Cheddar bounded to the tail. He felt a surge of courage. With a tremendous caterwaul he turned on the mice, striking right and left. They scattered like the shards of a broken window. Tail in hand, Carlow jumped on his back, and together they leaped from shelf to shelf, back to the top.

It was all over soon. The mice were routed, and fled as far and as fast as they could. Carlow and Victoria were safe, and Cheddar was re-united with his tail.

---

---

#### Author's notes:

- Cheddar had his tail sewn on soon after, so that it was always there to back him up.
- I held all of the humans back while writing this. Whether Victoria and Carlow matured to green, and eventually black cheese or where eaten by humans (a distinguished end for a cheese) I don't know.

  1. I apologise.
  2. curds are *strained*. Yeah, sorry.
  3. I can't apologise every time!
  4. Yes I know, but it is just too poor to leave out!
  5. What can I say but sorry?
  6. When I saw Gotcha Gouda I couldn't resist.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: No cats, or cheese, were harmed in the making of this story.

---

Allow me to regal you with a cheesy tale of a cheesy tail:

I am a fan of cats. <sub>(Dogs too, but it's funnier when things happen to cats. Dogs roll with it, cats... well, they just get Feta up with things fast.)</sub>

I am also a fan of cheese. <sub>(And puns, we'll see how many terrible ones I can fit in here!)</sub>

As a fan of cheese and cats, eating cheese around cats is risky. Sometimes, the cats decide to try to steal the cheese. If hooman likes it, kitty must likes too, right?

For the most part, the cats do appear to like small bits of cheese! However, cheese seems quiet fondue of cats as well!

One day, as I enjoyed a Gouda bowl of mac and cheese, heavy on the cheese and light on the mac of course, one of the cats decided to lure me away. He made an awful racket in another room, clearly into something.

"Grate, right in the middle of dinner! What is Swiss you tonight? Can't you brie-have for just a bit?" I asked, standing and walking to go intervene.

As I went to see where the trouble was, the other cat came for my cheese.

Unfortunately for the cat, the cheese was there for it! As I returned, I found a cat covered in cheese, as if the cheese had decided it enjoyed the taste of fur!

"You have cat to be curlding me right meow!" I sighed, taking in the site. "I'm gonna need Morbier to handle all of this stress..."

Needless to say, my cat was having a Munster of a time trying to clean up.

"Not very sharp of you, is it, getting into my food?" I scolded, moving to help clean up the hole mess very Caerphilly. "And I'll have to use my 'in queso emergency' cheese replacement, if I want to have the right balance of mac and cheese!"

Lucky for the cat, the cheese didn't have quiet a big enough stomach for a whole cat. Once the mess was clean, I looked the cats over.

"I hope you know never to dairy get into my cheese again. The cheese has a mind of its own! You Cantel what it will do when angered."

---

I'd like to take this time to dedicate this fun story to the team member that I feel this story makes me think of most: [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija).

After all, that's a username marriage of Cat and [Cotija](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotija_cheese)- Cat and Cheese!

Comment: Ooh,,,I can't believe I missed muenster in my Halloween reference. +1.

Comment: Just wait until I flesh this story out a bit more. It won't brie as simple then. ;) Just need more time, probably over my lunch break!

Answer (score 3):

Cheesus! What's going on here?

As a swiss guy I'm an expert in destroying lots of cheese....*mmmmmmmhhh...cheese*. I need some cheese, NOW!

**Quits the room and goes looking for some cheese.**

...

...

... after a considerable amount of time ...

...

...

OK, here I am again. Now where have I stopped? Oooohhh...cheese. Emmentaler, Greyerzer, NEED MORE!

**Can't concentrate....neeed moooooooooree!!!**

...

...

... stuck in an endless cheese hole

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There have been enough puns edam here already,  and I don’t want to just do permutations on what we’ve already done… Actually, let’s let feta decide.

Hello! Here from Math Stack Exchange, where we have too much cheese to go around.
Now here are some theorems to add to your cheesy repertoire.
But before I start with the math, I should say that I am a mere ricotta.

1. First an important question, [How to Slice the Cheese](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6868/how-to-slice-the-cheese), from our very own Math Stack Exchange! How many cheese slices can the [lazy caterer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer's_sequence) make with n slices? Turns out, this doesn't depend on the shape of the cheese, and is a  nice problem (in my books at least).
2. The [Ham Sandwich Theorem](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20001.7.shtml). The 2D version, sometimes called the "Cheese on Toast Theorem", is quite useful for splitting that cheesy goodness such that everyone gets the same amount of toast and cheese.
3. The [Cheese Pizza Theorem](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2009.11920956) is very important when trying to split a pizza evenly int N>3 slices by picking every other slice when making cuts from a point which is not the origin!
4. [Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor) has his own cheese, aptly named [Cantor's Cheese](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009784939090046Z). It's created by starting with a circle, and continuing to put two circles inside of each circle.
5. Now we're getting into Math Overflow territory, but I'll continue. A [Swiss Cheese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_cheese_(mathematics)) an actual mathematical object which apparently has some significance. Here's an article for those interested: [Swiss Cheeses and Their Applications](https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/plp/pmzjff/Papers/pdf/Swiss-cheeses-and-applications.pdf).
6. Quite related to 5 is the [Swiss Cheese Operad](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9807037). Algebras are weird.
7. Then there's this thing called [Sierskma's Dutch Cheese Problem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9703208.pdf).

There's probably more cheese to be had, but for now I think I'll retire to a little cottage and look for a comte in the starry night sky.

Answer (score 3):

> ***Who cut the cheese?***

Ans: **[Tom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Cat)**.

**Proof:** See below.

1. Tom laying traps (not very thought of a trap..)

[image]

2. Jerry was suspicious and did not show interest.

[image]

3. Tom added more traps...

[image]

4. Jerry hunting for cheese and tom chasing.

[image]

5. Finally, Jerry evaded and enjoying the cheeseeeeeeeee.. (see, it is one of the pieces cut by Tom!!)

[image]

**Conclusion:** In order to lay traps, Tom cut the cheese.

<sup>Disclaimer: Image source: Google, modifications mine</sup>

Just to add, some real life images, too:

- Cats guarding the Cheese:
  [image]
- Mice eating the cheese:
  [image]

Answer (score 3):

Who can think of cheese without wanting nibbles?  I didn't put much thyme into this nor did I caerphilly reverie-fy my code.  Also, due to colby-ning vw/vh with px, it's not Polished (bundz, anyone?) and Cheesy's not really stretchy, but I think we'll find the cheese cutter if you don't get board first.  :)

This is best viewed in full paglierino.

To try the code out, click the "run code snippet" button below the code and click "Full page" (full paglierino), or use this jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/k5q1p0fs/1/

```js
window.speed = 100;
window.direction = 0; // 0 = left, 1 = up, 2 = right, 3 = down
window.current_cheese = 1;
window.new_game = true;
window.max_lives = 5;
window.max_points = 9;

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(obj) {
  switch (obj.keyCode) {
    case 37: // left
      if (window.direction == 1 || window.direction == 3) {
        window.direction = 0;
      }
      break;
    case 38: // up
      if (window.direction == 0 || window.direction == 2) {
        window.direction = 1;
      }
      break;
    case 39: // right
      if (window.direction == 1 || window.direction == 3) {
        window.direction = 2;
      }
      break;
    case 40: // down
      if (window.direction == 0 || window.direction == 2) {
        window.direction = 3;
      }
      break;
    case 32: // space
      if (typeof(window.gameplay) == "undefined" || window.gameplay == null) {
        // Start game
        if (parseInt(document.querySelector(".lives").innerText) == 0) {
          window.new_game = true;
        }
        hide_mouseage();
        start_game(window.speed);
      } else {
        // Pause game
        window.clearInterval(window.gameplay);
        window.gameplay = null;
        show_mouseage("Press space to comtomme...");
      }
      break;
  }
});

function show_mouseage(msg, error) {
  clearInterval(window.gameplay);
  document.querySelector(".cheese-message").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector(".cheese-message").innerText = msg;
  if (error === true) {
    window.clearInterval(window.gameplay);
    window.gameplay = null;

    switch (window.direction) {
      case 0: // left
        window.direction = 2;
        break;
      case 1: // up
        window.direction = 3;
        break;
      case 2: // right
        window.direction = 0;
        break;
      case 3: // down
        window.direction = 1;
        break;
    }

    var lives = parseInt(document.querySelector(".lives").innerText);
    lives--;
    document.querySelector(".lives").innerText = lives;
    if (lives <= 0) {
      show_mouseage("Cat-astrophe! You're out of livarots.");
    }
  }
}

function hide_mouseage() {
  document.querySelector(".cheese-message").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector(".cheese-message").innerText = "";
}

function place_cheese() {
  var slice = document.querySelector(".cheese-slice");
  slice.innerText = current_cheese;
  slice.style.left = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 97) + 1 + "vw";
  slice.style.top = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 96) + 2 + "vh";
  slice.style.display = "block";
}

function start_game(speed) {
  // Setup new game
  if (window.new_game == true) {
    document.querySelector(".cheese-eater").style.top = "50vh";
    document.querySelector(".cheese-eater").style.left = "50vw";
    document.querySelector(".lives").innerText = window.max_lives;
    document.querySelector(".cheese-success").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".cheese-message").classList.remove("final");
    window.direction = 0;
    window.current_cheese = 1;
    window.new_game = false;

    place_cheese();
  }

  window.gameplay = window.setInterval(function() {
    var eater_top = document.querySelector(".cheese-eater").style.top;
    var eater_left = document.querySelector(".cheese-eater").style.left;
    var slice_top = document.querySelector(".cheese-slice").style.top;
    var slice_left = document.querySelector(".cheese-slice").style.left;
    var vertical = parseInt(eater_top);
    var horizontal = parseInt(eater_left);

    if (eater_top == slice_top && eater_left == slice_left) {
      var total = parseInt(document.querySelector(".total").innerText);
      if (typeof(document.querySelector(".total").innerText) == "undefined") {
        total = 0;
      }
      total = total + window.current_cheese * 100;
      document.querySelector(".total").innerText = total;
      window.current_cheese++;
      if (window.current_cheese > window.max_points) {
        document.querySelector(".cheese-slice").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".cheese-message").classList.add("final");
        show_mouseage("Coolea!");
        document.querySelector(".cheese-success").style.display = "block";
        window.new_game = true;
      } else {
        place_cheese();
      }
    }

    var eater = document.querySelector(".cheese-eater");
    switch (window.direction) {
      case 0: // left
        if (horizontal - 1 <= 0) {
          show_mouseage("You diet!  Too much cheese?", true);
        } else {
          eater.style.left = horizontal - 1 + "vw";
        }
        break;
      case 1: // up
        if (vertical - 2 <= 0) {
          show_mouseage("You diet!  Too much cheese?", true);
        } else {
          eater.style.top = vertical - 1 + "vh";
        }
        break;
      case 2: // right
        if (horizontal + 1 >= 100) {
          show_mouseage("You diet!  Too much cheese?", true);
        } else {
          eater.style.left = horizontal + 1 + "vw";
        }
        break;
      case 3: // down
        if (vertical + 1 >= 100) {
          show_mouseage("You diet!  Too much cheese?", true);
        } else {
          eater.style.top = vertical + 1 + "vh";
        }
        break;
    }
  }, speed)
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  width: calc(100vw - 20px);
  border: 10px solid #f55;
  background: #00a;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#cheese_bar {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 320px;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.name {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.total {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
.cheese-eater {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ff0;
  position: absolute;
}
.cheese-slice {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.cheese-message {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  background: #a00;
  padding: 1vw;
  text-align: center;
}
.cheese-message.final {
  top: 15%;
}
.cheese-success {
  display: none;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
.cheese-success span {
  margin-top: -40px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=VT323" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="cheese_bar">
  <span class="name">CHEESY--></span>
  <span>Livarots: <span class="lives">5</span></span>
  <span class="total">0</span>
</div>
<div id="playground">
  <div class="cheese-eater" style="left:50vw;top:50vh;"></div>
  <div class="cheese-slice">1</div>
  <div class="cheese-message">Press space to dig in</div>
  <div class="cheese-success">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 580 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_1" height="14.28564" width="453.14062" y="334.78187" x="71.14393" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_3" height="139.99932" width="17.14277" y="193.42861" x="71.14393" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_4" height="139.99932" width="17.14277" y="193.42861" x="507.71323" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_5" height="15.99992" width="417.14078" y="177.05489" x="90.00098" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect id="svg_6" height="139.99932" width="418.28367" y="194.57062" x="88.85727" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#ffc13c"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_7" height="15.4285" width="33.1427" y="229.42843" x="90.00098" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_8" height="14.85707" width="33.1427" y="281.9996" x="89.42955" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect id="svg_9" height="34.85697" width="16.57135" y="245.99978" x="123.7151" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect id="svg_10" height="16.57135" width="16.57135" y="245.99978" x="88.85812" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#0000aa" id="svg_11" height="16.57135" width="17.14277" y="245.99978" x="71.71535" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#0000aa"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_12" height="16.57135" width="34.28555" y="159.14306" x="124.28652" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#ffc13c" id="svg_25" height="34.85697" width="330.85555" y="140.85744" x="159.7149" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#ffc13c"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_13" height="16.57135" width="34.28555" y="140.85744" x="159.71492" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_14" height="15.99992" width="85.14245" y="123.71466" x="194.57189" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#ffc13c" id="svg_26" height="33.1427" width="191.99907" y="106.57189" x="280.85719" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#ffc13c"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_15" height="16.57135" width="68.57109" y="106.57189" x="246.00022" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_16" height="16.57135" width="50.85689" y="89.42912" x="299.1428" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_17" height="16.57135" width="34.28555" y="106.57189" x="350.57114" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000000" id="svg_18" height="16.57135" width="33.71412" y="53.42929" x="404.28516" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect id="svg_19" height="34.85697" width="16.57135" y="70.57206" x="386.57095" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect id="svg_20" height="34.85697" width="16.57135" y="123.14324" x="474.57054" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_21" height="16.57135" width="15.99992" y="158.57163" x="491.14186" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_22" height="16.57135" width="15.99992" y="106.57189" x="457.42774" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_23" height="16.57135" width="15.99992" y="88.5182" x="438.80262" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#ffc13c" id="svg_42" height="34.85715" width="33.71429" y="70.57143" x="403.7143" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#ffc13c"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_24" height="16.57135" width="15.99992" y="70.80399" x="421.65985" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000000" id="svg_27" height="15.99993" width="51.42833" y="229.99986" x="228.85744" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000000" id="svg_28" height="15.4285" width="51.42833" y="299.25798" x="228.85744" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_29" height="50.8569" width="17.14278" y="246.5712" x="210.66387" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_30" height="50.8569" width="16.57135" y="246.5712" x="280.94924" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_31" height="15.4285" width="33.1427" y="264.85683" x="228.85744" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect id="svg_32" height="16.57135" width="16.57135" y="282.57104" x="263.14299" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#0000aa" id="svg_33" height="17.7142" width="17.14277" y="263.71398" x="262.57157" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#0000aa"/>
  <rect stroke="#0000aa" id="svg_34" height="16.57135" width="50.85689" y="247.14263" x="228.85746" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#0000aa"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_35" height="50.8569" width="16.57135" y="228.85692" x="474.09211" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_36" height="50.8569" width="16.57135" y="228.85692" x="386.66354" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#0000aa" id="svg_37" height="51.4285" width="33.71421" y="228.28541" x="439.143" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#0000aa"/>
  <rect stroke="#000000" id="svg_38" height="16.57136" width="69.14262" y="211.14271" x="404.28604" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000000" id="svg_39" height="16.57136" width="68.57119" y="280.85701" x="404.28604" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect id="svg_40" height="34.85697" width="16.57135" y="228.85692" x="421.42942" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect id="svg_41" height="16.57135" width="16.57135" y="263.71389" x="439.71444" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect id="svg_43" height="34.85697" width="16.57135" y="123.71492" x="316.28523" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_44" height="16.57135" width="50.85689" y="141.42912" x="245.99994" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_45" height="16.57135" width="51.99975" y="159.14341" x="263.71423" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000000"/>
  <rect stroke="#0000aa" id="svg_46" height="16.57135" width="17.14277" y="159.14263" x="282.00109" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#0000aa"/>
  <rect stroke="#0000aa" id="svg_47" height="16.57135" width="17.14277" y="141.42835" x="263.71537" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#0000aa"/>
 </g>
</svg>
  <span>OVERFLOW!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you also post a working demo,  ot just the cose, since it’s very hard to follow

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I added a jsfiddle link and explanation how to run it in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

As a member of the Puzzling.SE site, I have to write a short and simple riddle!

---

> Colorado is known as my cat.
>
> He's not fond of pepper in fact.
>
> Excitement takes over,
>
> Each time you come over.
>
> So stop by the cottage with Jack.
>
> ---
>
> Easy now Colby, you'll eat here for free, just
>
> String up the nachos for me!

Comment: Nice, +1. I made a [cheesy riddle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese/316605#316605) as well, hope you like it!

Answer (score 3):

**This is a story of a Josh who loved Cheese a lot**

Once a upon a time, there was a little boy named Josh. He was born and raised in a small town in Colorado. His parents owned a farm with many cows. He loved eating different kinds of dairy products especially cheese. Whenever a calf was born, his mother made *Molozyvo*, a colostrum milk cheese. No matter what he is eating, he used to add cheese in it. Cheese burger, Cheddar Cheese ice cream what not....many. All of them homemade. Josh loved company of his friends. Every year, he attended the annual Cheese festival, Colorado Cheese Festival with friends and family. His mother was an exceptional cook. He acquired that trait from her. He learned many dishes from his mother. Not only that, he also learnt not to leave passion in the hardest of times. She believed that these passions would help a lot in our life in some way. Josh started invented new dishes since his teens by experimenting by the blend of ingredients with his favorite dish "Cheese".

Days were passing by and everything was going fine. Josh decided to move to city and live on his own till he is settled. He started attending college and learn programming. He became a great programmer. Even though he became busy with his college, he never left his passion i.e., cooking remembering his mother's words. He used to spending time in kitchen for a long time experimenting with Cheese, Chocolate, Chicken. Drinking coffee, cooking, eating, college, reading, typing, running Vinegar through his sink hole.... this was his routine. During weekends, He invited his friends, class mates to lunch and dinner. They enjoyed Josh's company a lot. They enjoyed with Josh's mouth watering *Cheesy Zucchini Casserole* was everyone's favorite dish. They partied hard with 'Prosecco And [Parmesan](https://www.cheese.com/parmesan/)',  'Riesling And [Ricotta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricotta)' in the weekends. Cooking and Cheese helped him earn a lot of friends. He is kind and funny at the same time, he would [Cheese Off](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cheese+off) quicker than any body.

During his years of university, Josh and his friends started a small food court with the dishes Josh had cooked as a part time business. The sales were okay-ish. All they need was a big mouth and publicity to be successful. So, Josh tried some ads on the internet. He knew a website named *Cheese Overflow*, a network  where people who love cheese write questions and answers. He had already posted some answers there. He posted an ad advertising his dish *Cheesy Zucchini Casserole* on a website which deals Cooking on Cheese Overflow network to try his luck. As we already know, Josh is a great programmer and funny towards people. His interactions and way of talking while submitting his ad impressed the Staff of *Cheese Overflow*. Looking at his programming skills (by questions and answers), they put a keen look on Josh. After continued interactions with him regarding his ads on his cheesy dishes, they grew fond of his style of talking, way of handling situations. They included him in one of their early projects. He proved himself a great contributor, associate and colleague. After a few years, he became a [Big Cheese](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/big%20cheese) in the company.

One evening, he was sitting alone in the hall leaning in the couch. He remembered his life from his childhood. A thought struck his mind how Cheese has [*moved the Cheese*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Moved_My_Cheese%3F) in his life by giving friends, taking part in celebrations having a role indirectly in securing a job etc., He felt fascinated. He remembered his mother's words :

> Do not leave your passion in your hardest of times. It will help in some or the other way.

He headed towards the refrigerator searching for old cheese to restart experiments in the kitchen.

Do you know who this Josh is?

> He is my good friend ;-)

<sup>Note: Events in this story are fictitious and any resemblance to real persons, living or dead, is coincidental. ;-)</sup>

Comment: Looks like people didn't got the joke :D

Comment: Yeah. I should have added link to profile for better understanding. :/

Answer (score 3):

**Lil Win: the story of the mouse that never gave up on his dream**

Lil Win was a small mouse, leaving in its own house, in Miice, a small, yet beautiful land. While being a kid, Win had heard a great story about a process called "Cheeselopment": that you could get a tiny part of cheese called Goode, sratch it, and put it into the CheesePiler, a big machine that was taking the scratched cheese, and if the scratches were orchestrated in the right way, the cheese would be multiplied into more and more cheese, being able to feed other mice. Win loved it right away!

But there were some problems with that: only one CheesePiler existed for the whole land, once created by an older mouse, named "The Wise", that had left Miice a long time ago. And only a few, older mice knew how to do Cheeselopment. But they were not talking too much. And Win wanted to learn do this. Oh, he loved it from the first time he heard about it. And he said "This is it! I am going to do this!".

The other mice in Miice were not that brave though. They kept telling him: "eat that little piece of cheese you have boy now, and stop dreaming. You don't even have nails to scratch! Let it to others do it!". But Win said "No. one day I will do it. And even more, I will create my own CheesePiler!" And he kept having faith. Then Win heard about a school that he could learn scratching that small pieces of cheece, called "Cheeseversity". But this school was in another land, called "AwayLand". And again, other mice were telling him "It is far away! Stay here, do not move". He said "No, I will do what I love".

After greeting his family in tears, started the way to "AwayLand". The journey was not easy. It was through a cold and difficult road, that Win would have to walk it by himself alone, far away from his loved ones. But Win did it. and he reached Cheeseversity. But even there, learning scratching the cheese was not easy. "You have very small and weak nails now" older mice said. "How are you goind to scratch the cheese?". And they yelled at him. But he said "NO. I am going to do this. Because I love it. And my nails will grow".

And Win scratched Goodes everyday. And was learning from his teachers how to become better. And formed Goode as better as he could to put them into the CheesePiler one day. But this was not easy, and Win was thinking of letting it go. And then, he remembered why he started. And he said "I am doing this because I love it! No stop man!". And days passed. And he kept sratching the cheese. And he kept becoming better.

But it came one day, that he realized that his nails had not only grown up, but had gotten stronger. And that his scratches were more delicate and well-formed. Older mice saw this, and finally got it. He was ready. Win headed back to his land. Back to his loved ones. Back to his older friends. Back, in front of the mighty CheesePiler. Win stood in front of the machine in awe, and spelled: "now, is the time".

He took that Goodes that he had worked on lately. They had tiny little scratches on. But only a few, and clean ones. You see, Win had understood that those scratches were enough, and no deep or strange ones were needed. He put those pieces in the CheesePiler. And the CheesePiler started working, making some strange sounds, and then responded "No cheese dude - scratches are bad on Goode!".

The other mice were then yelling at him saying: "What a shame, what a waste of your years in life, to go somewhere far away and fail". He bent his head, and started thinking that all this might have been useless indeed. But then he thought "It can't be! I will not fail!".

He looked again on his Goodes. And all of a sudden, he saw it! They missed one, one little scratch on the top. He did it immediately, and put the parts into the CheesePiler. The machine started doing some sounds and then....silence. All of a sudden, little pieces of cheese started pouring out of the machine, little ones, but hey, it was cheese, new cheese! This gave strength to Win. And he went to his house, and kept scratching cheese parts, even better and even better and put it to CheesePiler. And the new pieces of cheese becoming bigger and bigger. And he was happy, for he was doing what he loved. And he did it well. And he created cheese for himself and for other mice. And he taught other mice do it as well, in joy.

But Win had learned in his journey, that all this would had not become a reality if he had given up along the way, while he was small and weak. And now Win knew he could make his own CheesePiler. He was ready. And the journey was only at its very beginning. He would not say he was neither "The Wise", nor would he try to create such a great CheesePiler as "The Wise" had. He knew comparison was useless. But he knew more CheesePilers neede to be done, for a better world. And now It is time. Win is about to start that journey. He is neither old nor wise. But one thing is for sure: He does what he loves. And, who knows?

**He might eventually make it!**

Answer (score 2):

**Here's a cheesy algorithm for turning a potential problem into a tasty treat:**

1. Dig the leftover semi-hard cheese out of your refrigerator. Cheddar is good, Colby, Monterey Jack, Swiss, etc. are all fine. You'll want 8-12 ounces, total.
2. Shred your cheese with a box grater or other cheese-shredding tool.
3. Add the cheese to your mixer bowl along with 8 ounces of softened cream cheese, about 2 ounces of mayonnaise, some onion powder, cayenne pepper, and a couple of pimentos, diced.
4. Mix to combine well and season with salt and black pepper.
5. Behold! You now have pimento cheese, a delicious staple in any Southern (US) household. Serve on crackers or between slices of bread.

Maybe *I'm* being cheesy here, but I curd you not when I say that the whey the different ingredients in this recipe combine into a not-quite-homogenized whole that's better than any of the individual parts is a nice metaphor for the best aspects of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

What can I say? this is not mine but for self-sufficiency, and in the name of fun, I'll add it here:

[Original post](http://www.amiright.com/parody/80s/eurythmics21.shtml)

(Parody of "Sweet Dreams Are Made Of This" by the Eurythmics)

```
Sweet dreams are made of cheese
Who am I to dis a Brie
I cheddar the world and a Feta cheese
Everybody's looking for Stilton

Some cheese wants to be Bleu, too
Some cheese wants to be Buchette d'Anjou
Some cheese wants to be cubed
Some cheese will be braided by you

Sweet dreams are made of cheese
Colby or Chevre, if you please
I ferment the milk and then I squeeze
Everybody needs penicillium 

Mold is better, on the rind
Mold is better, leaves taste behind
Mold is better, cheese is confined
Mold is better, use my enzymes

Some cheese ought to be grated
No cheese should be ammoniated
Some cheese will always be hated
No cheese wants to be called rancid

Sweet dreams are made of cheese
Casein and rennet curdle it with ease
Whey from the curds it eventually frees
The best cheese comes from Wisconsin
```

Comment: *applause* this deserves more votes

Comment: @KorvinStarmast thank you - sadly, I do not deserve the credit - it's someone else's work :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm member of a German improv group called "Bricolage", which is the French word for DIY (MacGyver is featured on its Wikipedia article). One of our members likes sending voice messages to the others, often lengthy ones. I don't like listening to lengthy voice messages, so I put them through a speech recognition system and just read them.

The (German language) speech recognition system made out of his pronunciation of the word "Bricolage" three words: Brie, Cola, Arsch. The first one is obviously a name of a cheese (which makes this story qualify for this), the second is a drink and the last one is a German word for the body part you usually sit on.

Joking about this, we made an alternative logo for our group, let's see if you can find the cheese in it (and the other two components):

[image: BCA]

Comment: Δημοσθένη +1 for not enjoying the lengthy message voices, and the way you used technology to the rescue! Hope you also like my [cheesy riddle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese/316605#316605), and not just your new logo! PS: Brie << Feta.

Answer (score 2):

## CheeseBob SquarePants

Do you remember this guy? No, You are wrong!

He is ***CheeseBob SquarePants***, twin brother of Mr. [*SpongeBob SquarePants*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpongeBob_SquarePants), born in year 1989.

[image]

**"CheeseBob" Song** : Here comes the famous "CheeseBob" Song:

> Are you ready kids? Aye-aye captain.
>
> I can't hear you... Aye-aye captain!
>
> ...
>
> Ohhhhhh! Who is so yummy and tasty, and is derived from milk?
>
> ***CheeseBob SquarePants!***
>
> Valued for portability, long life, and high content of fat, protein, calcium is he!
>
> ***CheeseBob SquarePants!***

<sub>*(modified lyrics from original SpongeBob SquarePants title song)*</sub>

---

And now, below is the *magical* HTML + CSS code to generate "Mr. CheeseBob Square Pants". Check it out ;)

***PS: Above image of Mr. CheeseBob is generated via this code :D***

```css
.body {
  background: #f5ee31;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.ojos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 210px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.ojo {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: -17px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ojo_externo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  background: #00aeef;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

.ojo_interno {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.pestanas {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 28px;
  left: 12px;
}

.pestana {
  width: 15px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.pestana.primera {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.pestana.tercera {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nariz {
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #f5ee31;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  left: 130px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 42.5%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.boca {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  z-index: 10;
}
.dientes {
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  left: 65px;
}
.diente {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mejilla {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid #f1592a;
  border-bottom: 5px transparent;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 20% 20%;
}

.mejilla.primera {
  left: -15px;
}

.mejilla.segunda {
  left: 175px;
}

.poro {
  background: #c0a402;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.poro.primero {
  top: 230px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.poro.segundo {
  top: 200px;
  left: 280px;
}

.poro.tercero {
  top: 50px;
  left: 260px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}

.poro.cuarto {
  top: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  left: 50px;
}

.poro.quinto {
  top: 250px;
  left: 200px;
}

.poro.sexto {
  top: ;
  left: ;
}

.poro.septimo {
  top: ;
  left: ;
}

.poro.octavo {
  top: ;
  left: ;
}

.copy {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #00abf0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="ojos">
    <div class="ojo">
      <div class="pestanas">
        <div class="pestana primera"></div>
        <div class="pestana segunda"></div>
        <div class="pestana tercera"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ojo_externo">
        <div class="ojo_interno"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ojo">
      <div class="pestanas">
        <div class="pestana primera"></div>
        <div class="pestana segunda"></div>
        <div class="pestana tercera"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ojo_externo">
        <div class="ojo_interno"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nariz"></div>
  <div class="boca">
    <div class="mejilla primera"></div>
    <div class="dientes">
      <div class="diente"></div>
      <div class="diente"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mejilla segunda"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="poro primero"></div>
  <div class="poro segundo"></div>
  <div class="poro tercero"></div>
  <div class="poro cuarto"></div>
  <div class="poro quinto"></div>
  <div class="poro sexto"></div>
  <div class="poro septimo"></div>
  <div class="poro octavo"></div>
</div>
```

<sub>Generated via modified code from [this](https://codepen.io/falconmasters/pen/sBmcx) css snippet</sub>

Comment: +1 for making it purely out of HTML and CSS

Answer (score 2):

I think this can best be answered with a data structure, the little-used binary prefix tree.  Unlike a binary search tree, no node in the tree stores the key associated with that node; instead, its position in the tree defines the key with which it is associated. All the descendants of a node have a common prefix of the string associated with that node.

To represent the sequences 01100010, 011110010, 01101001, and 01100101 for instance, the following tree would be used:

```
        0
        1
        1
     0-----1
   0---1   0
  0-1  0   0
  1 0  0   1
  0 1  1   0
```

The advantages of this structure should be obvious to anyone schooled in Big-O notation.  The storage savings alone are significant - 20 bits instead of 24 for our example.  Because of the analogies with the [trie data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), the binary prefix tree is more commonly known as the "brie" data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Bill gets quite sad everytime someone eats his cheese, so I created a song to express all his feelings: Here's the famous [Ode to the Cheese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIdIqbv7SPo%22Bill%20Withers%22):

> Ain't no sunshine when cheese's gone
>   It's not warm when cheese's away 
>   Ain't no sunshine when cheese's gone
>   And cheese's always gone too long
>
> Anytime cheese goes away
>
> Wonder this time where cheese's gone
>   Wonder if cheese's gone to stay 
>   Ain't no sunshine when cheese's gone
>   And this house just ain't no home
>
> Anytime cheese goes away
>
> And I know, I know, I know, I know, I know, I know, I know, I know, I know I know, I know, I know, I know, I know I know, I know, I know, I know, I know I know, I know, I know, I know, I know I know, I know,
>
> HEY, I oughtta leave young thing alone
>   But ain't no sunshine when cheese's gone
>   Ain't no sunshine when cheese's gone
>   Only darkness every day
>
> Ain't no sunshine when cheese's gone
>   And this house just ain't no home 
>   Anytime cheese goes away
>   Anytime cheese goes away
>   Anytime cheese goes away
>   Anytime cheese goes away

---

What was noticed can not go unnoticed, and I bet you will be singing it everytime cheese is gone. You're welcome!

[image: Damm RatDog]

Comment: This is a good one, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Let every mortal shudder at the power of Gorgonzola!

[image]

For those wondering where this is from, look up [The Mask](http://the-mask.wikia.com/wiki/Gorgonzola) cartoons :)

Comment: I thought only I remember this cartoon

Answer (score 2):

## A Crappy Cheese Pun Finder

Uses a list of cheeses extracted from [Cheese.com](https://www.cheese.com/alphabetical/?per_page=20) and calculates the Levenshtein distance between every cheese and every word. If it's less than `maxDist` (3), the word will be replaced with the cheese.

```js
var maxDist = 3;

var cheeseNames = JSON.parse(`[\"cheese\",\"Abbaye de Belloc\",\"Abbaye de Belval\",\"Abbaye de Citeaux\",\"Abbaye de Timadeuc\",\"Abbaye du Mont des Cats\",\"Abbot's Gold\",\"Abertam\",\"Abondance\",\"Acapella\",\"Accasciato\",\"Ackawi\",\"Acorn\",\"Adelost\",\"ADL Brick Cheese\",\"ADL Mild Cheddar\",\"Affidelice au Chablis\",\"Affineur Walo Le Gruyere AOC Extra Mature\",\"Affineur Walo Rotwein Sennechas\",\"Afuega'l Pitu\",\"Aged British Cheddar\",\"Aged Cashew & Blue Green Algae Cheese\",\"Aged Cashew & Brazil Nut Cheese\",\"Aged Cashew & Dulse Cheese\",\"Aged Cashew & Hemp Seed Cheese\",\"Aged Cashew Nut Cheese\",\"Aged Cashew Nut & Kale Cheese\",\"Aged Chelsea\",\"Aged Gouda\",\"Aggiano\",\"Ailsa Craig\",\"Airag\",\"Airedale\",\"Aisy Cendre\",\"Allgauer Emmentaler\",\"Allium Piper\",\"Alma Vorarlberger Alpkase\",\"Alma Vorarlberger Alpkase\",\"Alma Vorarlberger Bergkase\",\"Alma Vorarlberger Bergkase\",\"Alma Vorarlberger Bergkase\",\"Almnas Tegel\",\"Alpe di Frabosa\",\"Alpha Tolman\",\"Alpicreme\",\"Alpine Gold\",\"Alpine-Style\",\"Alps Rebel\",\"Alta Badia\",\"Alverca\",\"Amablu Blue cheese\",\"Amalthee\",\"Amarelo de Beira Baixa\",\"Ambert\",\"Ameribella\",\"American Cheese\",\"Ami du Chambertin\",\"Amish Frolic\",\"Amou\",\"Amsterdammer\",\"Amul Cheese Spread\",\"Amul Emmental\",\"Amul Gouda\",\"Amul Pizza Mozzarella Cheese\",\"Amul Processed Cheese\",\"Anari\",\"Anejo Enchilado\",\"Anneau du Vic-Bilh\",\"Anniversary Ale Cheddar\",\"Anster\",\"Anthotyro\",\"Anthotyro Fresco\",\"Aphrodite Haloumi\",\"Appalachian\",\"Appenzeller\",\"Appleby's Double Gloucester\",\"Apple Walnut Smoked\",\"Applewood\",\"Applewood Smoked Chevre\",\"Aradalen\",\"Aragon\",\"Ardi Gasna\",\"Ardrahan\",\"Ardsallagh Hard Goat's Cheese\",\"Ardsallagh Smoked Cheese\",\"Ardsallagh Soft Goat's Cheese\",\"Armenian String Cheese\",\"Aromes au Gene de Marc\",\"Ascutney Mountain\",\"Asher Blue\",\"Ashley\",\"Asiago\",\"Asiago d'Allevo\",\"Asiago Pressato\",\"Aspen Ash\",\"Assa\",\"Aubisque Pyrenees\",\"Aura\",\"Austrian Alps cheese\",\"Autun\",\"Avaxtskyr\",\"Avonlea Clothbound Cheddar\",\"Azeitao\",

\"Babybel\",\"Baby Brie\",\"Baby Swiss\",\"Bad Axe\",\"Baguette Laonnaise\",\"Baita Friuli\",\"Baladi\",\"Balaton\",\"Balfour\",\"Baluchon\",\"Bandal\",\"Banon\",\"Barambah Organics Marinated Feta\",\"Barberey\",\"Barber's 1833\",\"Barden Blue\",\"Barely Buzzed\",\"Barilotto\",\"Baron Bigod\",\"Baronerosso di Capra\",\"Barrel Aged Feta\",\"Barricato al Pepe\",\"Barry's Bay Cheddar\",\"Bartlett\",\"Basajo\",\"Baserri\",\"Basils Original Rauchkase\",\"Basing\",\"Baskeriu\",\"Basket Cheese\",\"Basket Molded Ricotta\",\"Bassigny au porto\",\"Bath Blue\",\"Bath Cheese\",\"Batzos\",\"Bavaria blu\",\"Bavarian Bergkase\",\"Bayley Hazen Blue\",\"Baylough\",\"Beach Box Brie\",\"Bear Hill\",\"Beaufort\",\"Beaumont\",\"Beauvoorde\",\"Beecher's Flagship\",\"Beehive Fresh\",\"Beemster 2% Milk\",\"Beemster Aged\",\"Beemster Classic\",\"Beemster Extra Aged\",\"Beemster Graskaas\",\"Beenleigh Blue\",\"Bega Processed Cheddar\",\"Bel Ceillo\",\"Bella Lodi\",\"Belle Creme\",\"Belletoile\",\"Bellwether Farms Crescenza\",\"Bel Paese\",\"Benedictine\",\"Bent River\",\"Bergader\",\"Bergere Bleue\",\"Bergues\",\"Berkswell\",\"Bermondsey Hard Pressed\",\"Bermuda Triangle\",\"Bethmale des Pyrenees\",\"Bettine Bleu\",\"Bettine Grand Cru\",\"Beyaz Peynir\",\"Bianca\",\"Bianco\",\"Bica de Queijo\",\"Bierkase\",\"Big John's Cajun\",\"Big Rock Blue\",\"Big Woods Blue\",\"Bijou\",\"Binnorie Marinated Fetta\",\"Bishop Kennedy\",\"Bismark\",\"Black Betty\",\"Black Pearl\",\"Blacksticks Blue\",\"Blarney Castle\",\"Blenda\",\"Bleu Benedictin\",\"Bleubry\",\"Bleu d'Auvergne\",\"Bleu de Laqueuille\",\"Bleu Des Causses\",\"Bleu L'Ermite\",\"Bleu Mont Dairy Bandaged Cheddar\",\"Blissful Blocks\",\"Blissful Toppings\",\"Bloomsdale\",\"Blu '61\",\"Blu Della Casera\",\"Blu di Bufala\",

\"Bluebell Falls Cygnus\",\"Blue Benedictine\",\"Blue Castello\",\"Blue Earth\",\"Blue Ledge La Luna\",\"Blue Lupine\",\"Blue Rathgore\",\"Blue Vein\",\"Blue Vein Cheese\",\"Blue Wensleydale\",\"Blue Yonder\",\"Blythedale Camembert\",\"Bocconcini\",\"Boeren-Leidse met sleutels\",\"Bohemian Blue\",\"Boivin Extra Aged Cheddar\",\"Boivin Marbled Cheddar\",\"Boivin Medium Cheddar\",\"Bonchester\",\"Bonifaz\",\"Bonne Bouche\",\"Boo Boo Baby Swiss\",\"Bootlegger\",\"Bossa\",\"Bosworth\",\"Bothwell Black Truffle Cheddar\",\"Bougon\",\"Boulder Chevre\",\"Boule Du Roves\",\"Boulette d'Avesnes\",\"Bourdin Goat Log\",\"Boursault\",\"Boursin\",\"Bouyssou\",\"Bra\",\"Branza de Burduf\",\"Braudostur\",\"Breakfast Cheese\",\"Brebirousse d'Argental\",\"Brebis d'Azure\",\"Brebis du Lavort\",\"Brebis du Puyfaucon\",\"Bresse Bleu\",\"Brewer's Gold\",\"Brick\",\"Bridgewater\",\"Brie\",\"Brie au poivre\",\"Brie Coco\",\"Brie d'Alexis\",\"Brie de Meaux\",\"Brie de Melun\",\"Brie de Portneuf\",\"Brie de Portneuf Double Cream\",\"Brillat-Savarin\",\"Brillo di Treviso\",\"Brimstone\",\"Brin\",\"Brin d'Amour\",\"Brinza - Feta style\",\"Briquette de Brebis\",\"Briquette du Forez\",\"Briscola\",\"Brise du Matin\",\"Brocciu\",\"Broncha\",\"Brousse du Rove\",\"Brown's Gulch\",\"Bruder Basil\",\"Brunost\",\"Brusselae Kaas\",\"Brutal Blue\",\"Bryndza\",\"Buche de Chevre\",\"Bucheret\",\"Buchette a la Sarriette\",\"Buchette d'Anjou\",\"Bufala Soldier\",\"Bufalino\",\"Bufarolo\",\"Buffalo\",\"Buff Blue\",\"Burgos\",\"Burrata\",\"Burwash Rose\",\"Burwood Bole\",\"Butte\",\"Buttercup\",\"Butterkase\",\"Buttermilk Blue\",\"Buttermilk Blue Affinee\",\"Buttermilk Gorgonzola\",\"Butternut\",\"Buxton Blue\",\"Byaslag\",

\"Cabecou\",\"Cabecou Feuille D'Armagnac\",\"Caboc\",\"Cabot Clothbound\",\"Cabrales\",\"Cachaille\",\"Caciobarricato\",\"Caciobirraio\",\"Caciobufala\",\"Caciocavallo\",\"Caciocavallo di Bufala\",\"Caciocavallo Podolico Vetus\",\"Cacio De Roma\",\"Cacio di Bosco al Tartufo\",\"Cacioradicchio\",\"Caciotta\",\"Caciotta Al Tartufo\",\"Cacow Belle\",\"Caerphilly\",\"Cahill's Irish Porter Cheddar\",\"Cahill's Whiskey Cheese\",\"Cairnsmore\",\"Calcagno\",\"Calenzana\",\"California Crottin\",\"Cambazola\",\"Cambozola Grand Noir\",\"Cambus o'May\",\"Camembert\",\"Camembert de Normandie\",\"Camembert de Portneuf\",\"Camembert des Camarades\",\"Cameo\",\"Campfire\",\"Campi\",\"Cana de Cabra\",\"Cana de Oveja\",\"Canadian Cheddar\",\"Canastra cheese\",\"Cancoillotte\",\"Canestrato\",\"Cantal\",\"Cap Cressy\",\"Cape Vessey\",\"Capra al Fieno\",\"Capra al Pepe\",\"Caprano\",\"Capra Nouveau\",\"Capraricca\",\"Caprese di Bufala\",\"Capriago\",\"Capri Blu\",\"Caprice\",\"Caprice des Dieux\",\"Capricious\",\"Capricorn Somerset Goats Cheese\",\"Capriny\",\"Capriole Banon\",\"Caprotto\",\"Carabiner\",\"Caravane\",\"Cardo\",\"Carlina\",\"Carlow\",\"Carmody\",\"Carnia Altobut\",\"Caronzola\",\"Carre de l'Est\",\"Carrot Rebel\",\"Carrowholly\",\"Carr Valley Glacier Wildfire Blue\",\"Casatica\",\"Casciotta di Urbino\",\"Cashel Blue\",\"Cashew Nut Cream Cheese\",\"Castelmagno\",\"Castelo Branco\",\"Castigliano\",\"Castle Blue\",\"Casu marzu\",\"Cathelain\",\"Catupiry\",\"Cave Aged Marisa\",\"Caveman Blue\",\"Cave Rebel\",\"Cayuga Blue\",\"Cello Thick & Smooth Mascarpone\",\"Celtic Promise\",\"Cendre des Pres\",\"Cendre d'Olivet\",\"Cerney Pyramid\",\"Chabichou du Poitou\",\"Chabis de Gatine\",\"Challerhocker\",\"Champignon de Luxe Garlic\",\"Champignon de Luxe Pepper\",\"Champignon Mushrooom\",\"Chaource\",\"Chapman's Pasture\",\"Charolais\",

\"Chateau de Versailles\",\"Chaumes\",\"Chavroux\",\"Checkerboard Cheddar\",\"Cheddar\",\"Cheddar LaDiDa Lavender\",\"Cheddar with Irish Porter\",\"Cheddar with Red Wine\",\"Cheese Curds\",\"Chelsea Blue\",\"Cherokee Rose\",\"Cheshire\",\"Chevre\",\"Chevre des neiges\",\"Chevre en Marinade\",\"Chevre Log\",\"Chevrotin des Aravis\",\"Chhurpi\",\"Childwickbury\",\"Chile Caciotta\",\"Chile Jack\",\"Chimney Rock\",\"Chiriboga Blue\",\"Chocolate Lab\",\"Chocolate Stout Cheddar\",\"Chontaleno\",\"Chorlton Blue Cheshire\",\"Chura Kampo\",\"Cilentano ai fichi\",\"Cinerino\",\"Cirrus\",\"Civray\",\"Classic Blue Log\",\"Classico Pecorino Senese\",\"Classico Riserva\",\"Classics Fresh Mozzarella\",\"Clonmore\",\"Coalho\",\"Coastal Cheddar\",\"Coeur de Camembert au Calvados\",\"Coeur de Chevre\",\"Colby\",\"Colby-Jack\",\"Cold Pack\",\"Colony cheese\",\"ColoRouge\",\"Colston Bassett Stilton\",\"Comox Brie\",\"Comox Camembert\",\"Comte\",\"Comtomme\",\"Conciato Al Pepe\",\"Condio\",\"Connemara\",\"Consider Bardwell Farm Manchester\",\"Coolattin Cheddar\",\"Coolea\",\"Cooleney\",\"Coquetdale\",\"Corleggy\",\"Cornish Blue\",\"Cornish Brie\",\"Cornish Crumbly\",\"Cornish Kern\",\"Cornish Pepper\",\"Cornish Smuggler\",\"Cornish Wild Garlic Yarg\",\"Cornish Yarg\",\"Cote Hill Blue\",\"Cotherstone\",\"Cotija\",\"Cotswold\",\"Cottage Cheese\",\"Cottage Cheese\",\"Cougar Gold\",\"Coulommiers\",\"Counting Sheepand Goats...\",\"Country Morning\",\"Coupole\",\"Couronne Lochoise\",\"Coverdale\",\"Cow's Milk Gouda\",\"Cracked Pepper Chevre\",\"Cranborne\",\"Cratloe Hills\",\"Cravero Parmigiano Reggiano\",\"Crayeux de Roncq\",\"Cream Cheese\",\"Cream Cheesy Bliss\",\"Cream Havarti\",\"Creamy Lancashire\",\"Crema Agria\",\"Crema de Blue\",\"Crema Mexicana\",\"Cremet\",\"Cremig Extra Wurzig, Bergkase Aus Dem Schweizer Jura\",\"Cremont\",\"CreMonte\",\"CreNoble\",\"Crescenza\",

\"Crescenza di Bufala\",\"Cressy Blu\",\"Criffel\",\"Crocodile Tear\",\"Croghan\",\"Cropwell Bishop Blue Stilton\",\"Crotonese\",\"Crottin\",\"Crottin de Chavignol\",\"Crottin du Chavignol\",\"Crowdie\",\"Crowley\",\"Crozier\",\"Crumbly Lancashire\",\"Cuajada\",\"Cubetto\",\"Cuor di burrata\",\"Cup Cheese\",\"Cure Nantais\",\"Curworthy\",\"Cwmtawe Pecorino\",\"Cypress Grove Chevre\",

\"Danablu\",\"Danbo\",\"Danby\",\"Danish Feta\",\"Danish Fontina\",\"Dante\",\"Daphne's Aged Goat Cheese\",\"Daphne's Alpine Classic\",\"Daphne's Goat Gouda\",\"Daralagjazsky\",\"Dark / Snow Canyon Edam\",\"Dauphin\",\"Davidstow 3 Year Reserve Special Vintage\",\"Davidstow Extra Mature Cheddar\",\"Davidstow Mature Cheddar\",\"Dehesa De Los Llanos - Curado\",\"Dehesa De Los Llanos - Gran Reserva\",\"Dehesa De Los Llanos - Media Curacion\",\"Delamere Goats Cheese Logs\",\"Delamere Medium Hard Goats cheese\",\"Delice de Bourgogne\",\"Delice des Fiouves\",\"Denhany Dorset Drum\",\"Derby\",\"Desert Red Feta\",\"Dessertnyj Belyj\",\"Detroit Street Brick\",\"Devil's Gulch\",\"Devon Blue\",\"Devon Garland\",\"Dill & Garlic Chevre\",\"Dilly Girl\",\"Dinarski Iz Mosta\",\"Dinarski Sir\",\"Dinarski Sir Iz Maslinove Komine\",\"Dirt Lover\",\"Di.Vino\",\"Dolcelatte\",\"Dolomitico\",\"Don Bernardo Manchego\",\"Don Carlo\",\"Don Olivo\",\"Doolin\",\"Doppelrhamstufel\",\"Dorblu\",\"Dore-Mi\",\"Dorset\",\"Dorset Blue Vinney\",\"Dorset White\",\"Dorstone\",\"Double Gloucester\",\"Doublet\",\"Double Worcester\",\"Dreux a la Feuille\",\"Driftless\",\"Driftwood\",\"Drommen\",\"Dry Jack\",\"Dubliner\",\"Duck Isles Stone\",\"Duddleswell\",\"Duet\",\"Dumpling\",\"Dunbarra\",\"Dunbarton Blue\",\"Dunlop\",\"Dunsyre Blue\",\"Dura\",\"Duroblando\",\"Durrus\",\"Dutch Mimolette\",
\"Echo Mountain Blue\",\"Edam\",\"Edelpilz\",\"Edith\",\"Elberton Blue\",\"Elk Mountain\",\"Ellington\",\"El Trigal Manchego\",\"Emental Grand Cru\",\"Emlett\",\"Emmental\",\"Epoisses de Bourgogne\",\"Esbareich\",\"Esrom\",\"Essex Comte\",\"Estero Gold Reserve\",\"Etorki\",\"Etzy Ketzy\",\"Evans Creek Greek\",\"Evansdale Farmhouse Brie\",\"Evora De L'Alentejo\",\"Ewelicious Blue\",\"Ewe's Blue\",\"Exmoor Blue\",\"Explorateur\",\"Extra Mature Wensleydale\",

\"Farm Chanco\",\"Farmer\",\"Farm House Clothbound Cheddar\",\"Farmhouse Gouda\",\"Fat Bottom Girl\",\"Fellowship Too\",\"Fermiere\",\"Feta\",\"Ficaccio\",\"Fiery Rebel\",\"Fiesta Cheddar\",\"Figaro\",\"Figue\",\"Filetta\",\"Finca Pascualete Mini Torta\",\"Fin-de-Siecle\",\"Finn\",\"Fior Di Latte\",\"Fiore Sardo\",\"Fiscalini Bandaged Cheddar\",\"FITAKI White Cheese\",\"Fitness Rebel\",\"Five Counties\",\"Flagship Block\",\"Flashback Goat Disks\",\"Fleur du Maquis\",\"Flor de Guia\",\"Flory's Truckle Cheddar\",\"Flower Marie\",\"Foggy Morning\",\"Folded cheese with mint\",\"Fondant de Brebis\",\"Fontainebleau\",\"Fontiago\",\"Fontina\",\"Fontina Val d'Aosta\",\"Forest Rebel\",\"Formagella\",\"Formaggio di capra\",\"Formaggio di Grotta\",\"Forme'\",\"Forsterkase\",\"Fortsonia\",\"Fou du roy\",\"Fougerus\",\"Four Corners\",\"Four Herb Gouda\",\"Fourme de Haute Loire\",\"Fourme de Montbrison\",\"Fox Hill Gouda\",\"Fox Hill Parmesan\",\"Fragolone\",\"Francis\",\"Fresh Chevre\",\"Fresh Crottin\",\"Fresh Fior Di Latte\",\"Fresh Hand-Stretched Mozzarella\",\"Fresh Jack\",\"Fresh Mozzarella\",\"Fresh Ricotta\",\"Fresh Truffles\",\"Freya's Wheel\",\"Friesago\",\"Friesla\",\"Frinault\",\"Fromage a Raclette\",\"Fromage Blanc\",\"Fromage Blanc with Truffle\",\"Fromage Corse\",\"Fromage de Montagne de Savoie\",\"Fromage Frais\",\"Frying Cheese\",\"Funky Bleats\",\"Fuzzy Udder Brie\",\"Fuzzy Udder Creamery's Tomme\",\"Fuzzy Udder Washed Rind\",\"Fuzzy Wheel\",\"Fynbo\",

\"Galbani\",\"Galette du Paludier\",\"Galette Lyonnaise\",\"Galloway Goat's Milk Gems\",\"Gammelost\",\"Gamoneu\",\"Garlic and Fine Herbs Cashew Cheese\",\"Garrotxa\",\"Gastanberra\",\"Geitost\",\"Georgia Gold Clothbound Cheddar\",\"Gippsland Blue\",\"Giuncatella\",\"Glebe Brethan\",\"Gloucester\",\"Gloucester Goat\",\"Goat Cheddar\",\"Goat Curd\",\"Goat Fromage Blanc\",\"Goat Gouda\",\"Goat Milk Cheddars\",\"Goat Milk Feta\",\"Goat on a Hot Tin Roof\",\"Goat ricotta\",\"Goats' Milk Caciotta\",\"Golden Cross\",\"Golden Smoked Rebel\",\"Good Thunder\",\"Gorgonzola\",\"Gorgonzola Cremificato\",\"Gorgonzola Dolce DOP\",\"Gorgonzola Piccante DOP\",\"Gornoaltajski\",\"Gorwydd Caerphilly\",\"Gospel Green\",\"Gotcha Gouda\",\"Gouda\",\"Gourmandise\",\"Goutu\",\"Goya\",\"Grabetto\",\"Gracie Grey\",\"Graddost\",\"Grafton Village Cheddar\",\"Grana\",\"Grana Padano\",\"Granbu\",\"Grand Cru Original\",\"Grand Cru Reserve\",\"Grand Cru Surchoix\",\"Grand Vatel\",\"Gran Levante\",\"GranQueso Original\",\"GranQueso Reserve\",\"Grasso d'alpe Monscera\",\"Grataron d' Areches\",\"Grated Kefir Cheese\",\"Gratte-Paille\",\"Graviera\",\"Grayson\",\"Great Lakes Cheshire\",\"Green Dirt Farm Fresh Garlic & Peppercorn\",\"Green Dirt Farm Fresh Nettle\",\"Green Dirt Farm Fresh Plain\",\"Green Dirt Farm Fresh Rosemary\",\"Green Dirt Farm Fresh Spicy Chilis\",\"Green Hill\",\"Greuilh\",\"Greve\",\"Grey Owl\",\"Gris de Lille\",\"Gruyere\",\"Gubbeen\",\"Guerbigny\",

\"Habanero Cheddar\",\"Hafod\",\"Half-Moon Bay\",\"Halleck Creek\",\"Halloumi\",\"Hand Rolled Chevre Logs\",\"Hannah\",\"Hannah Reserve\",\"Harbison\",\"Harbourne Blue\",\"Harlech Truckle\",\"Harvest\",\"Havilah\",\"Hay Flower Rebel\",\"Hayloft\",\"Haystack Mountain Camembert\",\"Haystack Mountain Feta\",\"Haystack Peak\",\"Heat\",\"Heidi Aged cheese\",\"Heidi cheese\",\"Herbes de Provence Chevre\",\"Herbs de Humboldt\",\"Hereford Hop\",\"Herrgardsost\",\"Herriot Farmhouse\",\"Herve\",\"Hidden Falls\",\"Hidden Springs Farmstead Feta\",\"Highway 1\",\"Hillis Peak\",\"Himmelsraften\",\"Himmelsraften Extra\",\"Hipi Iti\",\"Holey Cow\",\"Holiday Brie\",\"Holzhofer Latte Crudo\",\"Hook's 5-year Cheddar\",\"Hooligan\",\"Hoop Cheese\",\"Hopyard Cheddar\",\"Horizon\",\"Hubbardston Blue Cow\",\"Humble Herdsman\",\"Humboldt Fog\",\"Huntsman\",\"Hushallsost\",

\"I' Blu\",\"Idaho Goatster\",\"Idiazabal\",\"Il Boschetto al Tartufo\",\"Imokilly Regato\",\"Impromptu\",\"Infossato\",\"Innes Brick\",\"Innes Button\",\"Innes Log\",\"Inverness\",\"Iris\",\"I' Rugoso\",\"Isabirra\",\"I' Serbo\",\"Island Brebis\",\"Island Bries\",\"Isle of Man Cracked Peppercorn\",\"Isle of Man Mature Cheddar\",\"Isle of Man Mild Cheddar\",\"Isle of Man Mild Coloured Cheddar\",\"Isle of Mull\",\"Istara Chistou\",\"Istara Kaikou\",

\"Jalapeno Cheddar\",\"Jarlsberg\",\"Jermi Tortes\",\"Jibneh Arabieh\",\"Jindi Brie\",\"Jubilee Blue\",\"Julianna\",\"Juustoleipa\",

\"Kabritt\",\"Kadchgall\",\"Kaltbach Emmentaler AOP\",\"Kaltbach Le Gruyere AOP\",\"Kanafeh\",\"Kanterkaas\",\"Kapiti Kikorangi\",\"Kase Mit Schweizer Truffeln\",\"Kashar\",\"Kashkaval\",\"Kashta\",\"Kasseri\",\"Keens Cheddar\",\"Kefalotyri\",\"Kefir Blue\",\"Kefir Italian Pasta Cheese\",\"Kefir Peppercorn Cheese\",\"Kefir Salad\",\"Kefir Tomato-Garlic\",\"Kefir Wine Companion\",\"Keltic Gold\",\"Kenne\",\"Kennebec Highlands Caerphilly\",\"Kernhem\",\"Kervella Affine\",\"King Island Cape Wickham Brie\",\"King River Gold\",\"Kinsman Ridge\",\"Kiri\",\"Kirkham's Lancashire\",\"Klosterkaese\",\"Knockdrinna Gold\",\"Knockdrinna Meadow\",\"Kolan Extra Mature\",\"Konig Ludwig Beercheese\",\"Konig Ludwig King's\",\"Kris Lloyd - Artisan Blend\",\"Kugelkase\",\"Kummin\",

\"Labneh\",\"La Bonaparte\",\"La Casatella\",\"Lacey Grey\",\"LaClare Farms Chandoka\",\"LaClare Farms Cheddar\",\"LaClare Farms Chevre\",\"LaClare Farms Evalon\",\"LaClare Farms Evalon with Cummin\",\"LaClare Farms Evalon with Fenugreek\",\"LaClare Farms Fondry Jack\",\"LaClare Farms Martone\",\"LaClare Farms Raw Goats Milk Cheddar\",\"LaClare Ziege Zacke Blue\",\"La Couronne - Fort Aged Comte\",\"Lacy Swiss\",\"Lady Jane\",\"La Fleurie\",\"Laguiole\",\"Lairobell\",\"Lajta\",\"Lake District Extra Mature Cheddar\",\"Lake District Mature Cheddar\",\"Lamb Chopper\",\"L'Amuse Brabander Goat Gouda\",\"L'Amuse Signature Gouda\",\"Lanark Blue\",\"Landaff\",\"Langres\",\"La Peral\",\"Lappi\",\"La Pyramide\",\"Largo\",\"La Rumeur\",\"Laruns\",\"La Sauvagine\",\"La Sauvagine Reserve\",\"La Serena\",\"La Taupiniere\",\"Latteria Navel\",\"Latteria San Biagio\",\"La Tur\",\"Laura Chenel's Cabecou\",\"Laura Chenel Taupiniere\",\"Laura Chenel Tome\",\"La Vache Qui Rit\",\"L'Aveyronnais\",\"Lavistown\",\"Leafield\",\"Lebbene\",\"Le Brebiou\",\"Le Brin\",\"Le Cendrillon\",\"Le Chevrot\",\"L'Ecir de l'Aubrac\",\"Le Conquerant Camembert\",\"Le Conquerant Demi Pont L'eveque\",\"Le Double Joie\",\"Le Duc Vacherin\",\"Leerdammer\",\"Le Fium Orbo\",\"Legacy\",\"Legato\",\"Le Lacandou\",\"Le Marquis Chevre\",\"Lemon Fetish\",\"Lemon Myrtle Chevre\",\"Le Moutier\",\"L'Empereur\",\"Leonora\",\"Le Reflet de Portneuf\",\"Le Roule\",\"Les Calendos\",\"Le St-Raymond\",\"L'Etoile de St-Raymond\",\"Le Wavreumont\",\"Leyden\",\"Liburnski Sir\",\"Liliputas\",\"Lil Moo\",\"Limburger\",\"Lincoln Log\",\"Lincolnshire Poacher\",\"Lindale\",\"Lindy Hop\",\"Lingot des Causses\",\"Lingot Saint Bousquet d'Orb\",\"Liptauer\",\"Little Black Bomber\",\"Little Bloom on the Prairie\",\"Little Colonel\",\"Little Dragon\",\"Little Napoleon\",\"Little Qualicum Raclette\",\"Little Rydings\",\"Little Ypsi\",\"Livarot\",\"Llanboidy\",\"Llanglofan Farmhouse\",\"Loch Arthur Farmhouse\",

\"Loddiswell Avondale\",\"Loma Alta\",\"Longhorn\",\"Lord of the Hundreds\",\"Lo Sburrato\",\"Lo Speziato\",\"Lost Lake\",\"Lou Bergier\",\"Lou Palou\",\"Lou Pevre\",\"Lunetta\",\"Lyburn Garlic and Nettle\",\"Lyburn Gold\",\"Lyburn Lightly Oak Smoked\",\"Lyburn's Winchester\",

\"Maasdam\",\"Macadamia Nut Cheese\",\"Macconais\",\"Madrona\",\"Maffra Aged Rinded Cheddar\",\"Maffra Cheshire\",\"Maffra Dargo Walnut\",\"Maffra Mature Cheddar\",\"Maffra Peppercorn Cheddar\",\"Maffra Red Leicester\",\"Maffra Sage Derby\",\"Maffra Wensleydale\",\"Maggie's Round\",\"Magna\",\"Mahoe Aged Gouda\",\"Mahon\",\"Maisie's Kebbuck\",\"Majorero\",\"Malvern\",\"Mamirolle\",\"Manchego\",\"Mandolin\",\"Mango Rebel\",\"Manon\",\"Manouri\",\"Manteca\",\"Manur\",\"Marble Cheddar\",\"Marbled Cheeses\",\"Marco Polo\",\"Maredsous\",\"Margotin\",\"Maribo\",\"Marin French Triple Creme\",\"Marisa\",\"Maroilles\",\"Martha's Heat\",\"Mascares\",\"Mascarpone\",\"Mascarpone\",\"Mascarpone Torta\",\"Mastorazio\",\"Matocq\",\"Mature Wensleydale\",\"May Hill Green\",\"Maytag Blue\",\"McLaren\",\"Medallion\",\"Meira\",\"Melange\",\"Melange Brie\",\"Melinda Mae\",\"Melville\",\"Menage\",\"Menallack Farmhouse\",\"Menonita\",\"Meredith Ashed Pyramids\",\"Meredith Blue\",\"Meredith Chevre Ash\",\"Meredith Chevre Dill\",\"Meredith Chevre Plain\",\"Meredith Goat Cheese in Extra Virgin Olive Oil\",\"Mersey Valley Original Vintage\",\"Meteorite\",\"Metronome\",\"Mettowee\",\"Meyer Vintage Gouda\",\"MezzaLuna Fontina\",\"Mezzo Secco\",\"Midnight Blue\",\"Midnight Moon\",\"Miette\",\"Mi-Ewe\",\"Mihalic Peynir\",\"Milawa Affine\",\"Milawa Aged Blue\",\"Milawa Blue\",\"Milawa Brie\",\"Milawa Goats Tomme\",\"Milawa White\",\"Milleens\",\"Millstone\",\"Mimolette\",\"Minas cheese\",\"Mine-Gabhar\",\"Minuet\",\"Mirabo Brie with Walnut\",\"Miss Muffet\",\"Mladi Trapist\",\"Mobay\",\"Molbo\",\"Mona\",\"Monastery Cheeses\",\"Mondseer\",\"Monet\",\"Montagnolo\",\"Montasio\",\"Montasio Mezzano\",\"Montasio Vecchio\",\"Montchevre Goat Cheese Log\",

\"Mont D'or Lyonnais\",\"Monte Enebro\",\"Monteo\",\"Monterey Jack\",\"Montgomery's Cheddar\",\"Mont Saint-Francis\",\"Montsalvat\",\"Mont St-Benoit\",\"Moody Blue\",\"Moonglo\",\"Moonlight Chaource\",\"Moose\",\"Morangie Brie\",\"Morbier\",\"Morbier Cru de Montagne\",\"Morcella\",\"Morgan\",\"Morimoto Soba Ale Cheddar\",\"Moringhello\",\"Morlacco\",\"Moses Sleeper\",\"Mossfield Organic\",\"Mothais a la Feuille\",\"Mouco Camembert\",\"MouCo Camembert\",\"Mountaineer\",\"Mountain Goat\",\"Mountain Herbs Rebel\",\"Mountain Rebel\",\"Mozzarella\",\"Mozzarella\",\"Mozzarella di Bufala\",\"Mozzarellissima\",\"Ms. Natural\",\"Mt. Mazama Cheddar\",\"Mt Scott\",\"Mt Tam\",\"Muddlewell\",\"Muenster\",\"Muffato\",\"Mun-chee\",\"Munster\",\"Muranda Blue\",\"Murazzano DOP\",\"Murol\",\"Mycella\",\"Myzithra\",

\"Naboulsi\",\"Nantais\",\"Natural Chevre\",\"Natural Smoked Van Gogh Gouda\",\"Nettle Meadow Kunik\",\"Nettles Gone Wild\",\"Neufchatel\",\"Neufchatel\",\"New Moon\",\"Nicasio Reserve\",\"Nicasio Square\",\"Niolo\",\"Nocciolino\",\"Nocciolo\",\"Nocturne\",\"Nokkelost\",\"Northumberland\",\"Noyan\",\"Nut Rebel\",

\"Oak Smoked Cheddar\",\"Oak Smoked Wensleydale\",\"Oasis\",\"Oaxaca\",\"Ocooch Mountain\",\"Odysseus Marinated Feta\",\"Off Kilter\",\"Ogleshield\",\"Okanagan Double Cream Camembert\",\"Old Burford\",\"Old Drovers Road\",\"Olde York\",\"Old Ford\",\"Old Goat\",\"Old Harry\",\"Old Kentucky Tomme\",\"Old Winchester\",\"Olivet au Foin\",\"Olivet Bleu\",\"Olivet Cendre\",\"Olomoucke Tvaruzky\",\"Oltermanni\",\"Oma\",\"Onion & Chives Cheddar\",\"Operetta\",\"Opus 42\",\"Oregon Blue Cheese\",\"Oregonzola\",\"Organic Beer-Brined Moochego\",\"Organic Carrot\",\"Organic Cheddar\",\"Organic Chili\",\"Organic Creamy Emmenthal\",\"Organic Elderflower\",\"Organic Farm\",\"Organic Feta\",\"Organic Fitness\",\"Organic Flower Meadow\",\"Organic Gouda\",\"Organic Mango\",\"Organic MooVache\",\"Organic Mountain\",\"Organic Mountain Climber\",\"Organic Pepper\",\"Organic Walnut\",\"Organic Wild Garlic\",\"Original Havarti\",\"Original Illertaler\",\"Orkney Extra Mature Cheddar\",\"Orkney Mature Cheddar\",\"Orkney Medium Coloured Cheddar\",\"Orla\",\"Oro Itlaiano\",\"Oschtjepka\",\"Oscypek\",\"Ossau Fermier\",\"Oxford Blue\",

\"Pacific Rock\",\"Pack Square\",\"Paesanella Bocconcin\",\"Paesanella Buffalo Mozzarella\",\"Paesanella Buffalo Ricotta\",\"Paesanella Burrata\",\"Paesanella Caciotta\",\"Paesanella Caciotta with Rocket & Chilli\",\"Paesanella Cherry Bocconcin\",\"Paesanella Dry Ricotta\",\"Paesanella Fresco\",\"Paesanella Fresh Ricotta\",\"Paglierino\",\"Paillot de Chevre\",\"Palet de Babligny\",\"Pallone di Gravina\",\"Paneer\",\"Panela\",\"Paniolo\",\"Pannerone\",\"Panquehue\",\"Pant ys Gawn\",\"Paprika Rebel\",\"Parmesan\",\"Parrano\",\"Pas de l'Escalette\",\"Paski sir\",\"Passendale\",\"Pasteurized Processed\",\"Pastoral\",\"Pate de Fromage\",\"Patefine Fort\",\"Pave d'Affinois\",\"Pave d'Auge\",\"Pave de Chirac\",\"Pawlet\",\"Peau Rouge\",\"Pecorino\",\"Pecorino a Latte Crudo\",\"Pecorino allo Zafferano\",\"Pecorino al Pepe\",\"Pecorino al Tartufo\",\"Pecorino Barba Del Passatore\",\"Pecorino Boccondilatte\",\"Pecorino Camomilla\",\"Pecorino Canapa\",\"Pecorino Con Caglio Vegetale\",\"Pecorino dei Malatesta al Sangiovese\",\"Pecorino Dei Malatesta Sotto Cenere\",\"Pecorino dei Monaci\",\"Pecorino di Sogliano\",\"Pecorino di Talamello\",\"Pecorino di Vigna\",\"Pecorino Erica\",\"Pecorino Fiordaliso\",\"Pecorino Foglie Noci\",\"Pecorino Gelsomino\",\"Pecorino Ginepro\",\"Pecorino Gran Riserva Del Passatore\",\"Pecorino in Walnut Leaves\",\"Pecorino Mallo di Noce\",\"Pecorino nel fieno\",\"Pecorino Nel Granaio\",\"Pecorino Nero\",\"Pecorino Ortica\",\"Pecorino Papavero\",\"Pecorino pepato\",\"Pecorino Pera\",\"Pecorino Querciaiolo\",\"Pecorino Romagnolo\",\"Pecorino Romano\",\"Peekskill Pyramid\",\"Pelardon des Cevennes\",\"Pelardon des Corbieres\",\"Pembrokeshire Extra Mature Cheddar\",\"Pembrokeshire Mature Cheddar\",\"Penamellera\",\"Penbryn\",\"Pencarreg\",\"Pepato\",\"PepBert\",\"Peppercorn Gouda\",\"Pepper Jack\",\"Pepper Rebel\",\"Perail de Brebis\",\"Perlagrigia Sotto Cenere\",\"Perroche\",\"Petida\",\"Petite Swiss\",\"Petit Pardou\",\"Petit-Suisse\",\"Phoebe\",\"Pianoforte\",\"Piave\",\"Piave Fresco\",\"Piave Mezzano\",\"Piave Vecchio\",\"Piave Vecchio Selezione Oro\",\"Picobello\",\"Picodon de Chevre\",

\"Picolo\",\"Picos de Europa\",\"Pied-de-vent\",\"Pierce Pt\",\"Pigouille\",\"Pimento\",\"Pinconning\",\"Piora\",\"Piper's Pyramide\",\"Pistol Point Cheddar\",\"Pithtiviers au Foin\",\"Pizy\",\"Pleasant Creek\",\"Pleasant Ridge Reserve\",\"Plymouth Cheese\",\"Podhalanski\",\"Point Reyes Bay Blue\",\"Point Reyes Original Blue\",\"Point Reyes Toma\",\"Poivre d'Ane\",\"Pokolbin\",\"Pompeii\",\"Pont l'Eveque\",\"Port Nicholson\",\"Port-Salut\",\"Postel\",\"Pouligny-Saint-Pierre\",\"Pourly\",\"Prairie Breeze Cheddar\",\"Prairie Rose\",\"Prairie Tomme\",\"Prastost\",\"President Brie\",\"President Camembert\",\"President Fat Free Feta\",\"President Fresh Goat Cheese\",\"President Light Brie\",\"President Madrigal\",\"Prima Donna\",\"Prima Donna fino\",\"Prima Donna forte\",\"Prima Donna leggero\",\"Prima Donna maturo\",\"Primo Fresco\",\"Prince-Jean\",\"Prix de Diane\",\"Processed Cheddar\",\"Processed Smoked Gouda\",\"Promontory\",\"Provel\",\"Providence\",\"Provoleta\",\"Provolone\",\"Provolone del Monaco\",\"Provolone Mandarino Gran Riserva\",\"Provolone Valpadana\",\"PsycheDillic\",\"P'tit Basque\",\"P'tit Berrichon\",\"Pule\",\"Purple Haze\",\"Purple's a Must\",\"Pyengana Cheddar\",\"Pyramide\",

\"Quadrello di Bufala\",\"Quark\",\"Quartirolo Lombardo\",\"Quatre-Vents\",\"Queijo do Pico\",\"Queijo do serro\",\"Quercy Petit\",\"Queso Blanco\",\"Queso Blanco con Frutas - Pina y Mango\",\"Queso de Afuega'l pitu\",\"Queso del Montsec\",\"Queso del Tietar\",\"Queso de Mano\",\"Queso de Murcia\",\"Queso Fresco\",\"Queso Iberico\",\"Queso Jalapeno\",\"Queso Media Luna\",\"Queso Para Frier\",

\"Rabacal\",\"Ragstone\",\"Ragusano\",\"Raschera\",\"Raw Brie Style Cashew Cheese\",\"Raw Milk Feta\",\"Raw Milk Goat Feta\",\"Reblochon\",\"Red Alder\",\"Red Buddy\",\"Red Cloud\",\"Red Dragon Truckle\",\"Red Hawk\",\"Re di Pecora Erborinato al Te Nero\",\"Red Leicester\",\"Red Windsor\",\"Red Wine Rebel\",\"Redwood Hill Goat Cheddar\",\"Regal Blend\",\"Regal de la Dombes\",\"Reggianito\",\"ReginaBlu\",\"Remedou\",\"Requeson\",\"Reverie\",\"Reypenaer\",\"Reypenaer V.S.O.P.\",\"Reypenaer XO Reserve\",\"Rheba\",\"Richelieu\",\"Ricotta\",\"Ricotta di Bufala\",\"Ricotta di Pecora\",\"Ricotta Salata\",\"Ridder\",\"Ridgeline\",\"Rigotte\",\"Ringwell\",\"Roaring Forties Blue\",\"Roasted Garlic Cheddar\",\"Rocamadour\",\"Roccia del Piave\",\"Rochebaron\",\"Rofumo\",\"Rollot\",\"Romaniae Terrae Pecorino allo Zafferano\",\"Romano\",\"Romans Part Dieu\",\"Roncal\",\"Rondo\",\"Roquefort\",\"Roque River Blue - Special Reserve\",\"Rosemary Medium Asiago\",\"Rosso\",\"Rosso de lago\",\"Roth Raclette\",\"Rotwein Bargler Extra-Wurzig\",\"Rougette Bavarian Red\",\"Rougette Grill Meister\",\"Roule\",\"Rouleau De Beaulieu\",\"Roumy\",\"Royalp Tilsit\",\"Royal Rebel\",\"Rubens\",\"Rubi\",\"Rupert\",\"Rustico Red Pepper\",\"Rustinu\",

\"Saaland Pfarr\",\"Saanenkaese\",\"Saanen Silk\",\"Saga\",\"Sage Derby\",\"Saint Agur\",\"Saint Albray\",\"Saint-Andre\",\"Sainte Maure\",\"Saint Felicien\",\"Saint-Honore\",\"Saint-Marcellin\",\"Saint-Nectaire\",\"Saint-Paulin\",\"Saint Rose\",\"Salemville Amish Blue\",\"Salemville Amish Gorgonzola\",\"Salemville Smokehaus Blue\",\"Salers\",\"Salsa Asiago\",\"Saltbush Chevre\",\"Samso\",\"San Andreas\",\"Sancerre\",\"Sandy Creek\",\"San Geronimo\",\"Sao Jorge\",\"Saporito\",\"Sap Sago\",\"Sardo\",\"Sarro de Cabra\",\"Sartori Classic Cheese Asiago\",\"Sartori Classic Cheese Fontina\",\"Sartori Classic Cheese Parmesan\",\"Sartori Classic Cheese Romano\",\"Sartori Classic MontAmore\",\"Sartori Limited Edition Cannella BellaVitano\",\"Sartori Limited Edition Cognac Bellavitano\",\"Sartori Limited Edition Extra-Aged Goat\",\"Sartori Limited Edition Family Heirloom BellaVitano\",\"Sartori Limited Edition Family Heirloom Parmesan\",\"Sartori Limited Edition Pastorale Blend\",\"Sartori Reserve Balsamic Bellavitano\",\"Sartori Reserve Basil & Olive Oil Asiago\",\"Sartori Reserve BellaVitano Gold\",\"Sartori Reserve Black Pepper Bellavitano\",\"Sartori Reserve Chai Bellavitano\",\"Sartori Reserve Cheese Mediterranean Fontina\",\"Sartori Reserve Dolcina Gorgonzola\",\"Sartori Reserve Espresso Bellavitano\",\"Sartori Reserve Extra-Aged Asiago\",\"Sartori Reserve Extra Aged Fontina\",\"Sartori Reserve Merlot Bellavitano\",\"Sartori Reserve Raspberry BellaVitano\",\"Sartori Reserve Rosemary & Olive Oil Asiago\",\"Sartori Reserve SarVecchio Parmesan\",\"Sbrinz\",\"Sbronzo\",\"Scallion Onion Cheddar\",\"Scamorza\",\"Schloss\",\"Scotch Bonnet Cheddar\",\"Sea Change\",\"SeaHive\",\"Seascape\",\"Seastack\",\"Seator's Orkney\",\"Selles sur Cher\",\"Selva\",\"Serat\",\"Seriously Strong Cheddar\",\"Serra da Estrela\",\"Sgt. Pepper\",\"Shaker Blue\",\"Shanklish\",\"Sharon Hollow Garlic and Chive\",\"Sharp Cheddar\",\"Sharpham\",\"Sharpham Elmhirst\",\"Sharpham Rustic\",\"Sharpham Rustic Chive & Garlic\",\"Sharpham Savour\",\"Sheep Gouda\",\"Shelburne Cheddar\",\"Shepherdista Crush\",\"Shepherd's Crook\",\"Shepherd's Hope\",\"Shepsog\",\"Ships Wheel Brie\",\"Shredded Bliss\",\"Shropshire Blue\",\"Shtayburne Farm Cheddar\",\"Shtayburne Farm Monterey Jack\",\"Sicilian Blend\",\"Siltcoos\",\"Sirene\",\"Sleightlett\",\"Slices Of Bliss\",\"Smoked Fior Di Latte\",\"Smoked Gouda\",

\"Smoked Sulguni\",\"Smokey Jalapeno\",\"Smokey Mountain Round\",\"Smokey Oregon Blue\",\"Smokey Touvelle\",\"Snow Camp\",\"Snowdrop\",\"Sofia\",\"Somerset Brie\",\"Sonnet\",\"Sonoma Jack\",\"Sosha\",\"Sottocenere al Tartufo\",\"Soumaintrain\",\"Sourire Lozerien\",\"Spenwood\",\"Speziato\",\"Squaquerone di Bufala\",\"Sraffordshire Organic\",\"Stawley\",\"Stella Asiago\",\"Stella Black Pepper Romano\",\"Stella Blue\",\"Stella Feta\",\"Stella Fontina\",\"Stella Fontinella\",\"Stella Goat\",\"Stella Gorgonzola\",\"Stella Italian Sharp\",\"Stella Kasseri\",\"Stella Mediterranean Parmesan\",\"Stella Parmesan\",\"Stella Parmesan & Romano Blend\",\"Stella Reduced Fat Blue\",\"Stella Smoked Blue\",\"Stella Swiss\",\"Sternschnuppe\",\"St-Fidele Swiss\",\"St Gall\",\"Stichelton\",\"Stickney Hill Chevre\",\"Stilton\",\"Stinking Bishop\",\"St Jude\",\"St. Killian\",\"St. Mang Original Allgauer Limburger\",\"Stoney Cross\",\"St Pat\",\"Stracchinata\",\"Strathdon Blue\",\"Strawberry Moon\",\"Striegistaler Zwerge Camembert\",\"String\",\"St Tola Ash Log\",\"St Tola Cranberry\",\"St Tola Crottin\",\"St Tola Divine\",\"St Tola Greek Style\",\"St Tola Hard Cheese\",\"St Tola Log\",\"Suffolk Punch\",\"Sulguni\",\"Sun Dried Tomato and Basil Cashew Cheese\",\"Sunlight\",\"Sunset Bay\",\"Sussex Slipcote\",\"Sveciaost\",\"Swag\",\"Swaledale\",\"Sweet Style Swiss\",\"Swiss\",

\"Table Rock\",\"Takelma\",\"Tala\",\"Taleggio\",\"Tamie\",\"Tango\",\"Tapas\",\"Tarago River Jensen's Red\",\"Tarentaise\",\"Tartufo Riserva\",\"Tasmania Highland Chevre Log\",\"Tasty Lancashire\",\"Tavoliere\",\"TeaHive\",\"Tegan\",\"Teifi\",\"Telemea\",\"Teneri\",\"Tete de Moine\",\"Tetilla\",\"Texas Goat Cheese\",\"Tezacki Iz Maslinove Komine\",\"Tezacki Iz Mosta\",\"Tezacki Sir\",\"Tezacki Sir Extra Mature\",\"The City Goat\",\"The Manchester\",\"Thomasville Tomme\",\"Tibet\",\"Ticklemore\",\"Tieton Halloumi\",\"Tillamook Cheddar\",\"Tillamook Smoked Black Pepper White Cheddar\",\"Tilly Whim\",\"Timboon Brie\",\"Toma\",\"Toma Blu Alle Erbe\",\"Toma di campo\",\"Toma di vacca alle vinacce\",\"Toma Piemontese\",\"Tomme\",\"Tomme Brulee\",\"Tomme de Chevre\",\"Tomme de Romans\",\"Tomme de Savoie\",\"Tomme des Chouans\",\"Tommes\",\"Torta del Casar\",\"Toscanello\",\"Touree de L'Aubier\",\"Tourmalet\",\"TouVelle Original\",\"Tozzetto\",\"Traditional Haloumi\",\"Trappe de la Coudre\",\"Trappiste de Bricquebec\",\"Trappiste d'Igny\",\"Tregonwell\",\"Trelawny\",\"Triple Creme Brie\",\"Tronchon\",\"Trou du Cru\",\"Truffello\",\"Trufflestack\",\"Truffle Tremor\",\"Tuada\",\"Tunworth\",\"Tupi\",\"Turunmaa\",\"Tuscan Blend\",\"Twig Farm Crawford\",\"Twig Farm Goat Tomme\",\"Twig Farm Mixed Drum\",\"Twig Farm Square Cheese\",\"Twig Farm Washed Rind Wheel\",\"Txiki\",\"Tymsboro\",\"Tyn Grug\",\"Tyning\",

\"Ubriaco\",\"Ubriaco alla Birra\",\"Ubriaco all'Amarone\",\"Ubriaco al Prosecco\",\"Ubriaco di Nero D'avola\",\"Ubriaco di Raboso\",\"Ubriaco di Zibibbo\",\"Ubriaco Rosso Piave\",\"Ulloa\",\"Up In Smoke\",\"Urda\",

\"Vacherin\",\"Vacherin Fribourgeois\",\"Vache Sante\",\"Valbreso Feta\",\"Valencay\",\"Valentine\",\"Vampire Slayer\",\"Van Gogh Edam\",\"Vaquero Blue\",\"Vasterbottenost\",\"Veigadarte\",\"Venaco\",\"Vendomois\",\"Veneto\",\"Vento d'Estate\",\"Venus\",\"Vera\",\"Vermont Ayr\",\"Vermont Herdsman\",\"Vesuvius\",\"Victoria\",\"Vieux Corse\",\"Vigneron\",\"Vignotte\",\"Vintage Van Gogh Gouda\",\"Vulscombe\",

\"Wabash Cannonball\",\"Wagon Wheel\",\"Waimata Farmhouse Blue\",\"Wakatipu White\",\"Waldo Smog\",\"Wall Street Gold\",\"Walnut Cheddar\",\"Wasabi Disc\",\"Wasatch Mountain cheese\",\"Washed Rind Cheese\",\"Waterloo\",\"Waupoos Lizzie\",\"Weichkaese\",\"Wellesley\",\"Wellington\",\"Wensleydale\",\"Wensleydale with Cranberries\",\"West Country Farmhouse Mature Cheddar\",\"Westfield Farm Smoked Capri\",\"Weston Wheel\",\"West West Blue\",\"Weybridge\",\"White Stilton with Mango & Ginger\",\"Whitestone Farmhouse\",\"Wicklow Blue\",\"Wigmore\",\"Wilde Weide\",\"Wild Garlic Rebel\",\"Willoughby\",\"Wimer Winter\",\"Windrush Cheeses\",\"Winnimere\",\"Woodside Alpine\",\"Woodside Cabecou\",\"Woodside Capricorn\",\"Woodside Charleston\",\"Woodside Chevre\",\"Wookey Hole Cave Aged Cheddar\",\"Woolly Rind\",\"Wrangeback Sweden\",\"Wyfe of Bath\",

\"Xynotyro\",

\"Yarra Valley Ashed Pyramid\",\"Yarra Valley Black Savourine\",\"Yarra Valley Bulls Eyes\",\"Yarra Valley Cardi\",\"Yarra Valley Fresh Pyramid\",\"Yarra Valley Gentle Goat\",\"Yarra Valley Juno\",\"Yarra Valley Le Jack\",\"Yarra Valley Persian Feta\",\"Yarra Valley Saffy\",\"Yarra Valley Vintage Savourine\",\"Yarra Valley White Savourine\",\"Yarra Valley Yering\",\"Yeo Lake\",\"Yorkshire Blue\",

\"Za'atar Burrata\",\"Zamorano\",\"Zanetti Grana Padano\",\"Zanetti Parmigiano Reggiano\",\"Zartschmelzend, Kraftig Wurziger Rahm-Hartkase\",\"Zelu Koloria\",\"Zigljen Iz Extra Mature\",\"Zigljen Iz Mosta\",\"Zimbro\",\"Zwitser\"



]`);


var userText = prompt("Enter some text");

var betterText = userText.trim().split(" ").map(word => {
 let maxWordEditDistance = maxDist;
 maxWordEditDistance *= -Math.max(2 - 0.4 * word.length,0) + 1;
 let possiblePuns = cheeseNames.filter(name => getEditDistance(name, word) < maxWordEditDistance);
 
 if(possiblePuns.length > 0) {
  let pun = possiblePuns[Math.floor(Math.random() * possiblePuns.length)];
  return pun;
 } else {
  return word;
 }

}).join(" ");

alert(betterText);

/*
Copyright (c) 2011 Andrei Mackenzie
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
*/

// Compute the edit distance between the two given strings
function getEditDistance(a, b){
  if(a.length == 0) return b.length; 
  if(b.length == 0) return a.length; 
  a = a.toLowerCase();
  b = b.toLowerCase();
  var matrix = [];

  // increment along the first column of each row
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i <= b.length; i++){
    matrix[i] = [i];
  }

  // increment each column in the first row
  var j;
  for(j = 0; j <= a.length; j++){
    matrix[0][j] = j;
  }

  // Fill in the rest of the matrix
  for(i = 1; i <= b.length; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= a.length; j++){
      if(b.charAt(i-1) == a.charAt(j-1)){
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1];
      } else {
        matrix[i][j] = Math.min(matrix[i-1][j-1] + 1, // substitution
                                Math.min(matrix[i][j-1] + 1, // insertion
                                         matrix[i-1][j] + 1)); // deletion
      }
    }
  }

  return matrix[b.length][a.length];
};
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it converts too many words. For example, can you guess what input sentence your code converted into "Danby Grana Toma Iris and Dante Bra Dante"? It probably shouldn't convert words such as "a", "to", etc... I'd also keep the verbs unchanged if possible.

Comment: @Eran Thank you for the useful suggestions. I totally agree with "it converts too many words". So, I improved the short word handling. If you have any further suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: @Stefnotch One thing you (myself) could improve is turning "brief" into "brie-f", instead of simply turning it into "brie". (Partial word pun detection)

Answer (score 1):

Let's combine Cheese and Mars

## Cheese + Mars

[image]

## Cheers

[image]

---

<sup>Note: Not an editing guru</sup>

Comment: Whew! Rusty and dusty cheese.

Comment: Optimus comes from cosmos, so he must know more than me about Mars.. Maybe humans are maybe up to a cheesy discovery by 2022...+1 for giving us the heads up! Hope you like my [cheesy riddle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese/316605#316605), as much I enjoyed your ... cheesy insight!

Answer (score 1):

Inspiration from @coder-croc and Credit from @Travis J

---

Cheese Overflow:

[image: CheeseOverflow]

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that read through three pages of cheesy things and still having an appetite for cheese: there is more (randomized) cheese than you would ever want to eat that can be found at   http://www.cheeseipsum.co.uk/

> I love cheese, especially cheeseburger cauliflower cheese. Edam brie macaroni cheese cheesy feet smelly cheese cottage cheese danish fontina macaroni cheese. Cheesecake edam cottage cheese fromage frais halloumi boursin cheddar cheese and wine. Camembert de normandie manchego cheese strings who moved my cheese chalk and cheese melted cheese roquefort mozzarella. Port-salut cheese and wine bocconcini babybel red leicester cheese triangles caerphilly fromage. Cream cheese smelly cheese boursin feta cottage cheese red leicester caerphilly halloumi. Cauliflower cheese ricotta melted cheese red leicester blue castello danish fontina cut the cheese the big cheese. Cow fromage frais cheese strings parmesan camembert de normandie swiss brie fromage frais. Manchego boursin dolcelatte the big cheese the big cheese red leicester.
>
> Mascarpone cheesecake cheese slices. Brie stinking bishop cheddar goat fromage cottage cheese brie say cheese. The big cheese manchego cheese and wine hard cheese fromage frais stinking bishop cheddar cauliflower cheese. Cheeseburger lancashire lancashire cow boursin monterey jack cauliflower cheese pepper jack. Caerphilly pepper jack dolcelatte emmental red leicester jarlsberg blue castello red leicester. Smelly cheese port-salut fondue danish fontina the big che

---

I am using this or the https://baconipsum.com/ to spice up layouting tasks or when I need some cheesy texts to fill test-documents. No affiliation otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

During a software design workshop in the Swiss mountains, our American friends were surprised to learn what melted cheese (Raclette) can be used for....

[[image: Video thumbnail]

Watch their enlightening conversation on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEAPR9NY-LE&t=8s)

Answer (score 0):

Cloned from @Kodos Johnson but it goes a little bit faster...

```js
var showAlert = true;
$('#cheese').on('mouseenter',function(e){
    $(this).animate({
        'left': getRandomInt(0, $(window).width() - $(this).width()),
        'top': getRandomInt(0, $(window).height() - $(this).height())
    }, 200);
    showAlert = true;
});

$('#cheese').on('click', function(e) {
  if (showAlert) {
    alert("Got the cheese!");
    showAlert = false;
  }
  
});
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}
```

```css
html {
  cursor: grab;
}
#cheese {
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:88px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="cheese" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nsAx.png"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

In light of the [*latest* achievement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/), and referring to this mention of [chuck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/244062)-e-[cheese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese), my two cents for the Stack Overflow version!!

[image]

<sub>Disclaimer: [Actual Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_E._Cheese%27s), image source: Google, Wikipedia</sub>

Answer (score -1):

First I visited [RhymeZone](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?typeofrhyme=perfect&Word=cheese). Second I wrote this:

> Freeze tease,
>   Squeeze that sneeze,
>   Breeze don't wheeze,
>   Geez, cheese is the keys.

I won't hold anyone personally responsible if I don't win.

Answer (score -3):

Smoked cheese goes well with whiskey!