# Have the e-mails for the "Who cut the Cheese" contest been sent out yet?

Tags: support, email, swag

Evey other time I received swag, I had to confirm shipping information beforehand. Each time someone would send a helpful e-mail out, but I have yet to see one. In the [contest post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316515/182566) it said, "Winners will be notified via email within 10 days of the contest closing." I have checked a few times now and have not seen any messages from Stack Overflow employees, except for a handful of *very* suspicious messages in my spam folder saying things like **We need your confirmation asap!** I don't have a virtual machine handy at the moment and am hesitant to open any of them as there is no message preview. The senders are "Nancy" and "Lucy" with no other information.

Are those e-mails that might have come from Stack Exchange employees, or has the [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/182566) simply not past yet? (aka, are you guys just behind schedule sending them out?) I'm guessing terms like "winner" or "free" would be quick to be sorted into spam, so it is entirely possible they are the correct ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're in the process of collecting them now, I just approved the invoice to order a *few* more boards than we actually seem to need (just in case one gets lost or something, my boss seemed oddly-excited that we're getting some so I'm being careful).

I think Ops is currently working on getting those sent out, I'm not sure you can expect them today, but it should be relatively soon.

Comment: Will we be getting other Swag like T-shirt *(SO one, it's 10th anniversary after all ;) )* and stickers with the shipment too?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Ever since I found out code review had rubber ducks I fell in love with them and wanted one so badly. But even if I had the choice to get a duck or the cheesboard, there will only ever be around 30 cheeseboards. They are *special.* Although I'd certainly love a duck too :)